# Generate antsy permutations

Tags: code-golf, permutations

### Introduction

I defined the class of antsy permutations in [an earlier challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97217/antsy-permutations).
As a reminder, a permutation **p** of the numbers from **0** to **r-1** is antsy, if for every entry **p[i]** except the first, there is some earlier entry **p[i-k]** such that **p[i] == p[i-k] ± 1**.
As a fun fact, I also stated that for **r ≥ 1**, there are exactly **2<sup>r-1</sup>** antsy permutations of length **r**.
This means that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the antsy permutations of length **r** and the binary vectors of length **r-1**.
In this challenge, your task is to implement such a correspondence.

### The task

Your task is to write a program or function that takes in a binary vector of length **1 ≤ n ≤ 99**, and outputs an antsy permutation of length **n + 1**.
The permutation can be either 0-based of 1-based (but this must be consistent), and the input and output can be in any reasonable format.
Furthermore, different inputs must always give different outputs; other than that, you are free to return whichever antsy permutation you want.

The lowest byte count wins.

### Example

The (0-based) antsy permutations of length 4 are

```
0 1 2 3
1 0 2 3
1 2 0 3
1 2 3 0
2 1 0 3
2 1 3 0
2 3 1 0
3 2 1 0
```

and your program should return one of them for each of the eight bit vectors of length 3:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Comment: Can the program take the integer representation of each binary vector instead?

Comment: @mbomb007 No, because the leading zeros are significant. `0 1` and `0 0 1` should give outputs of different lengths.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḟẋLṭ+
0;ç/
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bif4bqLTOG5rSsKMDvDpy8&input=&args=MSwgMSwgMCwgMCwgMSwgMCwgMQ) or [generate all permutations of length 4](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bif4bqLTOG5rSsKMDvDpy8KMuG4tuG5lzPDh-KCrEc&input=).

#### How it works

```
0;ç/   Main link. Argument: B (bit array)

0;     Prepend a 0 to B.
  ç/   Reduce [0] + B by the helper link.


ḟẋLṭ+  Helper link. Left argument: A (array or 0). Right argument: b (bit)

 ẋ     Repeat A b times, yielding A or [].
ḟ      Filter false; remove the elements of A or [] from A.
  L    Get the length of the resulting array.
       This yield len(A) if b = 0 and 0 if b = 1.
    +  Add b to all elements of A.
   ṭ   Tack; append the result to the left to the result to the right.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>62</s> 60 bytes

```python
x=0,
for n in input():x=[t-n+1for t in x]+[n*len(x)]
print x
```

*Thanks to @xnor for golfing off 2 bytes!*

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/YHMXhV).

Comment: Do you need the comma in `x=0,`?

Comment: `0,` is a tuple. Without the comma, mapping over **x** would fail.

Comment: I think you can flip `n` to do `[n*len(x)]` and change the map to a list comp.

Comment: @xnor Indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 45 bytes

```
a=>[h=l=0,...a.map(c=>c?--l:++h)].map(e=>e-l)
```

This turned out to be similar to @ETHproductions' method, except I had started by directly calculating the first element and then using the binary vector to determine whether each digit is a new high or a new low. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @ETHproductions. Saved 2 bytes by starting with zero and adjusting afterwards. My previous method turned out to be similar to @Dennis's method, but took 54 bytes:

```
a=>a.reduce((r,b)=>[...r.map(e=>b+e),r.length*!b],[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 54 bytes

```python
lambda l:[i-i*x+sum(l[i:])for i,x in enumerate([1]+l)]
```

Uses the following procedure:

1. Prepend a 1 to the list.
2. For each 0 entry, write its position in the 0-indexed list.
3. For each entry, write the number of 1's to its right, not counting itself.
4. Add the results of steps 2 and 3 entrywise.

For example, `l=[1,0,1,0]` gives `f(l) == [2,1,3,0,4]`

```
List with prepended 1         1 1 0 1 0

0-indexed position for 0's        2   4
Number of 1's to right        2 1 1 0 0
Sum of above two              2 1 3 0 4
```

Prepending a 0 would also give the same result. The `enumerate` is clunky, I'll see if it can done better recursively.

Comment: Clever technique! It's fascinating how different techniques are best in each language. I tried porting this to JS, but it ended up at 57 due to the lack of `sum` and slicing syntax.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```
v=>[...v,l=0].map(x=>x?l++:h--,h=v.length).reverse()
```

Test it out:

```js
f=v=>[...v,l=0].map(x=>x?l++:h--,h=v.length).reverse()
g=v=>console.log(f((v.match(/[01]/g)||[]).map(x=>+x)))
```

```html
<input oninput="g(this.value)" value="010">
```

#### Explanation

This takes advantage of the fact that when an antsy permutation is reversed, each item is either 1 more than the maximum of the previous low entries, or 1 less than the minimum of the previous high entries. By denoting a higher item as a `0` and a lower item as a `1`, we can create an exact one-to-one correspondance between the antsy permutations of length **n** and the binary vectors of length **n - 1**.

The best I could do with Dennis' technique is <s>57</s> 51 bytes:

```
v=>v.reduce((x,n)=>[...x.map(i=>i+n),!n*++j],[j=0])
v=>v.map(n=>x=[...x.map(i=>i+n),!n*++j],x=[j=0])&&x
```

xnor's solution is 56 (saved 1 byte thanks to @Neil):

```
l=>[1,...l].map((x,i)=>i*!x+eval(l.slice(i).join`+`||0))
```

Comment: `i-i*x` could be `i*!x`.

Comment: @Neil Ah yes, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 33 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give vector as string without spaces on STDIN:

```
antsy.pl <<< 110
```

`antsy.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s%^|.%y/0//+($&?++$a:$b--).$"%eg
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 40 bytes

```haskell
foldl(\r a->map(+0^a)r++[a*length r])[0]
```

[Dennis's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98231/20260) golfs wonderfully in Haskell with `map` and `fold`. It's shorter than my attempts to port my [direct entrywise construction:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98246/20260)

```haskell
f l=[i*0^x+sum(drop i l)|(i,x)<-zip[0..]$0:l]
f l=[a+c-b*c|(a,c,b)<-zip3(scanr(+)0l)[0..]$0:l]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 127 bytes

```
@set s=%*
@set/an=h=l=%s: =+%
@for %%b in (%*)do @call:%%b
:0
@echo %n%
@set/an=h+=1
@exit/b
:1
@echo %n%
@set/an=l-=1
```

Takes input as command-line parameters, output is line-separated. (It's possible to input as space-separated on STDIN for no extra cost.)