# Output the missing integer

Tags: code-golf, string, number, sequence, integer

You will be given a string. It will contain 9 unique integers from 0-9. You must return the missing integer. The string will look like this:

```
123456789
 > 0

134567890
 > 2

867953120
 > 4
```

Comment: @riker That seems to be about finding a number missing in a sequence. This seems to be about finding a digit missing from a set.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem this is definitely a subset of that challenge though. It's not a superset, but most answers from the challenge can be trivially copied over.

Comment: @Riker I wouldn't think it's a duplicate, given that the linked challenge has a strictly incrementing sequence (of potentially multi-digit numbers), whereas here it's in arbitrary order.

Comment: Hi Josh! Since no one else has mentioned it so far, I'll direct you to the [Sandbox](http://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can post future challenge ideas and get meaningful feedback before posting to main. That would have helped iron out any details (like STDIN/STDOUT) and resolved the duplicate dilemma before you received downvotes here.

Comment: It's such a shame that 9-x%9 works for any digit except 0. Maybe someone more clever than me will find a way to make it work.

Comment: Several answers take an integer as function input. Is that allowed?

Comment: I can't technically 'return' an integer in SInclair ZX80 or ZX81 BASIC, but would it be okay to store the missing integer in a variable and printing that once I have returned from a sub-routine that will determine the missing variable?

Comment: Can I print the number twice?

Comment: Can I take input as a newline-separated string?

Answer (score 43):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

<sup>+beauty thanks to @Sarge Borsch</sup>

```python
`99066**2`.strip
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z9gaWlgZqalZZSgV1xSlFnwv6AoM69EIU0jM6@gtERDU/O/uoWZuaWpsaGRgToA)

`99066**2` is just a shorter way to generate a string that contains 0~9

Comment: 32043 can be changed to a more beautiful number. 99066 is center-symmetric (doesn't change if rotated 180 degrees around center) or maybe 97779 (palindrome, two distinct digits)

Comment: If the OP allows to print the number twice, `764**4` can save two bytes.

Comment: @Titus `764**4` is missing `5`,`8` and `9`

Comment: Typo ... I meant `763**4` = `338920744561`

Answer (score 27):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 22 bytes

```python
lambda s:-int(s,16)%15
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JY5LCsJAEETX5hS9kShEmJ6e/gVyEnUR0YCgUTK5f0zG5aPqUTV0l@XVv2/3HnJ7eo7zITcoxz3yMj/ynKGDc52EjTwq1g3UFFwtSeQNDJMKOYcNJLkpY4gbRCH2YH9HNBk6xVJjJccYLBXAIBYTeXFYAqpTSXRdRbLVuVbV8Jkgw3OEcqqtdt9p/QrDIR@XHw)

An arithmetic solution. Interprets the input string as hex, negates it, and takes the result modulo 15.

Comment: Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @KarlKastor, modulo 15 in base 16 works analogically to modulo 9 in base 10. Modulo base-1 is constant when taking sum of digits, just because 10 ≡ 1 (mod base-1). Sum of all possible digits is constant, so the missing digit is the difference of this constant and the input number (modulo base-1).

Answer (score 19):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

#### Derived function

```apl
⎕D∘~
```

`⎕D` **D**igits

`∘` (ties a left argument to the following dyadic function to create a monadic function)

`~` except [the argument]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@5/2qG3Co76pLo86ZtT9/5@moG5oZGxiamZuYanOBeJBOQZgnoWZuaWpsaGRgToA)

---

#### Function train

```apl
⎕D~⊢
```

`⎕D` **D**igits

`~` except

`⊢` the right argument

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@5/2qG3Co76pLnWPuhb9/5@moG5oZGxiamZuYanOBeJBOQZgnoWZuaWpsaGRgToA)

---

#### Explicit program

```apl
⎕D~⍞
```

`⎕D` **D**igits

`~` except

`⍞` character input

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#e9TRnvb/Ud9Ul7pHvfP@P@po/5/GZWhkbGJqZm5hyQVkQ5kGQLaFmbmlqbGhkQEA)

Answer (score 13):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```hs
(477-).sum.map fromEnum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mq2Fibq6rqVdcmquXm1igkFaUn@uaV5r7PzcxM0/BViEzryS1KDG5REFFoTgjv1xBTyHtv6GRsYmpmbmFJQA) Usage: `(477-).sum.map fromEnum $ "123456890"`. 477 is the sum of the character codes of the digits 1 to 9, excluding 0. This anonymous function computes 477 minus the sum of all digit character codes to find the missing one.

Turning the char digits to ints is one byte longer:

```hs
(45-).sum.map(read.pure)
foldl(\a b->a-read[b])45
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mm5afk5KjEZOokKRrl6hblJqYEp0Uq2li@j83MTNPwVYhM68ktSgxuURBRaE4I79cQU8h7b@hkbGJqZm5hQEA)

Answer (score 12):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>48</s> <s>38</s> 36 + 3 = 39 bytes

*10 bytes saved thanks to DJMcMayhem!*

```
((([]())[]{}){()()({}[()])}{}[{{}}])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hoREdq6GpGR1bXatZraEJhNW10RqasZq1QLq6urY2VvP/fwtDI2MTAzNzy/@6yQA)

### Explanation

The sum of all the digits in Ascii is 525.  This program sums up the input and subtracts it from 525 to get the missing digit.

```
((([]())[]{}){()()({}[()])}{}      )
```

Will push 525.  This takes advantage of the fact that we know there will be 9 elements of input to begin with.  This means that `[]` evaluates to 9 which allows us to get to large numbers like 525 quickly.

Next we have the bit:

```
                             [{{}}]
```

which will sum up the inputs and subtract it from the total.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @ГригорийПерельман Explanation added!

Comment: If you move the `negative(sum(input()))` to the end, you can abuse the stack-height nilad to push 525 easier. `(([][][]()()()){()()({}[()])}{}[{{}}])` should save you 10 bytes

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyM6tjq6ujYWSEfHalZraGpU10ZraMZq1lbX1mr@/29hZm5pamxoZPBfNxkA "Brain-Flak – Try It Online") by subtracting 477 instead

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ØDḟ
```

Simply filters (`ḟ`) the input string from **“0123456789”** (`ØD`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394hsvDHfP///@vZGFmbmlqbGhkoAQA)

Comment: I like the way that all the golfing languages (and even some non-golfing languages) are using the same algorithm, but Jelly manages to have the shortest names for the builtins it uses, and the least boilerplate for reversing the arguments to `ḟ`.

Comment: @ais523 APL is letter by letter the same (except that it would be an APL snippet rather than a function/program): `Ø`=`⎕`, `D`=`D`, `ḟ`=`~`, as in `⎕D~'867953120'`.

Comment: Me, while scrolling through the answers: "I'm predicting 3 characters in Jelly." Bingo. :^D

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 26

*Edit* 1 byte save thx @Neil, with a much more smarter trick

Xoring all the values from 1 to 9 gives 1. Xor 1 one more time and the result is 0. So, if any single value is missing, the result will be the missing value.

```
s=>eval([1,...s].join`^`)
```

**Test**

```js
f=s=>eval([1,...s].join`^`)

function go() {

  var i=I.value;
  O.textContent = f(i)
}  

go()
```

```html
<input oninput='go()' value='012987653' id=I>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: ``s=>eval([1,...s].join`^`)`` saves a byte.

Comment: @Neil ... and it's much more interesting too

Comment: I feel this tip came suspiciously short after [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114134/29637) :D anyway nice golf +1.

Comment: @Christoph Well it sounded as if you wanted to spread the word...

Comment: @Neil absolutly :) Nice to see that it helped!

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, 14

Sums the ascii codes and subtracts from 48*9+45

```
->s{477-s.sum}
```

Use like this

```
f=->s{477-s.sum}

puts f["123456789"]
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>27 21</s> 19 bytes

-6 Thanks to Basic Sunset
-2 Thanks to Martin Ender

```
.
$*_5$*
+`_1|1_

1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6/HpaIVb6qixaWdEG9YYxjPxWX4/7@hkbGpmbmFpQEA)

Replace every digit with that many `_`s and 5 `1`s:

```
.
$*_5$*
```

Remove all of the `_`s and a `1` for each:

```
+`_1|1_
```

Count the number of `1`s left:

```
1
```

Comment: The first line of the second answer can be just `.`.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using deduplication instead of replacement: [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6/CZWBoZGxiamZuYcnlkqDHpZigp/L/v4WZuaWpsaGRAQA)

Comment: Oh well, and here was I just getting the second answer down to the old byte count of the first answer... `^` `5` `^.` `$*9¶` `.` `$*_` ``+`_¶_`` `¶` `_`

Comment: @Neil I got it to one less than the original.

Comment: (Huh, that looks suspiciously similar to my answer, the only difference is that you switched from `_` to `1` to save a byte.)

Comment: @Neil It is. I forgot to up the amount of credit I gave you, my bad.

Comment: Thanks! (But I'm still impressed by the extra byte saving.)

Comment: @Neil I only knew of that because [Martin Ender](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender) commented on my last Retina answer to tell me about it.

Comment: [Here's](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6/HpaJlxBXHZWKqosWlnWBoxMWl9/@/oZGxqZm5haUBAA) a worse answer using a similar approach, but perhaps someone can see an opportunity I missed.

Answer (score 7):

## Brainfuck, <strike>17</strike> 15 bytes

```
-[-[->-<],]>++.
```

[Try it out here](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=LVstWy0-LTxdLF0-Kysu).
*This solution works on standard Brainfuck (8-bit cells) only, as it relies on wrapping.*

It's a rare day when Brainfuck can actually compete, but this challenge just happened to line up with the BF spec pretty well!

Instead of straight-up breaking down this answer, I'd like to step through the iterations I took, because I think it would be more understandable (and more interesting).
Note: this solution is inspired largely by [Wheat Wizard's Brain-Flak answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114060/output-the-missing-integer/114063#114063).

### Explanation

### Step 1, 26 bytes

In his answer, Wheat Wizard pointed out that the sum of the ASCII values from 0-9 sum to 525. And since standard Brainfuck only has a notion of [0,255], this makes the value 525 % 256 = **13**. That is to say, subtracting the ASCII values of the input from 13 nets you the missing digit.

The first version of this program was:
 1. Put 13 in the first cell
 2. Take inputs into the second cell
 3. Subtract the second cell from the first cell
 4. Jump to 2 if there are inputs remaining
 5. Print the first cell

And here's the code for the simple solution:

```
+++++++++++++ #Set the first cell to 13  
>,            #Take inputs into the second cell  
[[<->-],]     #Subtract the second cell from the first cell and repeat until inputs are over  
<.            #Print the first cell
```

### Step 2, 19 bytes

As pointed out in his answer, since we know the input will be exactly length 9, we can use that value as a constant, and eliminate that long string of +'s right at the beginning.
It also doesn't matter at what point we add 13 (thanks, commutative property!), so we'll mix it in with the subtraction and printing steps.

```
,        #Take input to enter the loop
[[->-<], #Subtract the first cell from the second cell 
>+<]     #Add 1 for each input; totaling 9
>++++    #Add the missing 4 to make 13
.        #And print
```

This was my original answer to this problem, but we can do better.

### Step 3, 17 bytes

Interestingly enough, the previous answer works even if we begin with a + instead of a ,

```
+[[->-<],>+<]>++++.
```

Brainfuck required *something* in a cell in order to begin a loop. We naively added that extra 4 in the end, when it could have gone in other places.

```
-[[->-<],>+<]>++.
```

With some *totally intentional* (read: trial and error) loop trickery, starting off the program with a - leads to two interesting results:

1. One gets added to the second cell (saving 1 byte at the end).
2. The loops runs one extra time, totaling 10 instead of 9 (saving another 1 byte).

1 + 10 + 2 = 13, and we end up with the original answer.

Looking back on it, this is probably an excessive write-up for such a simple Brainfuck program.

### Step 4, 15 bytes

After thinking about this solution a bit more, I was able to cut off 2 bytes.

I wanted to clarify something about the previous step:
The minus to enter the loop *effectively* adds 1, but what it's actually doing is subtracting 255 from the second cell (resulting in 1).

It's obvious in retrospect, but subtracting 1 from the first cell is the same as adding 1 to the second cell (because everything in the first cell gets subtracted from the second cell.)

```
-[-[->-<],]>++.
```

I was able to remove the ">+<" by adding a "-" at the beginning of the first loop. It has to go there, and not where the ">+<" was, because the program will loop infinitely otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
45¹SO-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@29iemhnsL/u//8WZuaWpsaGRgYA)

```
45     # Push 45
  ¹    # push input
   S   # Split
    O  # Sum
     - # Subtract (45 - sum)
```

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>31</s> <s>29</s> <s>28</s> 22 bytes

```
s=>(15-`0x${s}`%15)%15
```

Port of @xnor's Python answer, except that JavaScript only has a remainder operator rather than a modulo operator, so I can't do it in a single step. Edit: Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Arnauld.

Comment: `s=>[...s].map(c=>r-=c,r=45)|r` ;-)

Comment: You are too much in love with `reduce`. +1 anyway

Comment: @Arnauld I don't see that working when `s[0]!='0'`, but there's already an answer that uses `eval`.

Comment: Could you do `s=>(15-\`0x${s}\`%15)%15`?

Comment: @Arnauld Bah, and I'd already done that for the Batch port too...

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
477-Tr@ToCharacterCode@#&
```

Pure function taking a string as input and returning an integer.
Mathematica has long command names and is reluctant to convert between strings and integers, which makes it particularly bad at this challenge. The best I could find was the algorithm from [Level River St's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114091/56178), which does a computation based on the total of the ASCII codes of the input string; in Mathematica, this uses only one long command name.

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 22 bytes

```matlab
@(x)setdiff('0':'9',x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gUaFZnFqSkpmWpqFuoG6lbqmuU6H5PzGvWEPd0NjE1MzcwtJAXfM/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 27

```
<?=trim(32043**2,$argv[1]);
```

uses the trick from [Rod's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114070/29637) to generate a string containing all digits then removes all digits except for the missing one.

---

PHP, 41

```
for($b=1;$i<9;$b^=$argv[1][$i++]);echo$b;
```

This one uses *xor* because I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: Nice I have not think about trim. Alternatives values `32043,32286,33144,35172,35337,35757,35853,37176,37905,38772,39147,39336,40545,42744,43902,44016,45567,45624,46587,48852,49314,49353,50706,53976,54918,55446,55524,55581,55626,56532,57321,58413,58455,58554,59403,60984,61575,61866,62679,62961,63051,63129,65634,65637,66105,66276,67677,68763,68781,69513,71433,72621,75759,76047,76182,77346,78072,78453,80361,80445,81222,81945,83919,84648,85353,85743,85803,86073,87639,88623,89079,89145,89355,89523,90144,90153,90198,91248,91605,92214,94695,95154,96702,97779,98055,98802,99066`

Answer (score 5):

### Bash + coreutils, 19 bytes

I found a <s>shorter</s> bash solution, that uses an interesting checksum approach:

```sh
sum -s|dc -e524?--P
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19cmqugW1yTkqygm2pqZGKvqxvw/7@FmbmlqbGhkQEA)**

**Explanation:**

The `sum` command prints a checksum and a block count. I don't know many details, but using the option `-s` (System V algorithm) will make the checksum equal to the ASCII sum of each input character code. As such, the checksum remains constant when the order of the same input characters changes.

Given `867953120` as test case (last example), here is how the script works:

- `sum -s` outputs `473 1`. If no integer was missing, the checksum would have been 525.
- `dc -e524?` pushes 524 and then the pipe input. The stack is: `1 473 524`. The idea is to subtract the checksum from 525, but since sum outputs 1 as well, I need to work with it.
- `--P`. After applying the two subtractions (524-(473-1)), the stack is: `52`. With 'P' I print the character with that ASCII code: `4`, the missing digit.

Answer (score 4):

## Fortran 95, <s>146</s> 128 bytes

```
function m(s)
character(len=10)::s,t
t='0123456789'
do j=1,10
k=0
do i=1,9
if(s(i:i)==t(j:j))k=1
end do
if(k==0)m=j-1
end do
end
```

Not very short, I'm afraid.

**Ungolfed:**

```
integer function m(s)
    implicit none

    character(len=9)::s
    character(len=10)::t
    integer:: i, j, k

    t='0123456789'
    do j=1,10
        k=0
        do i=1,9
            if (s(i:i) == t(j:j)) k=1
        end do
        if (k==0) m=j-1
    end do

end function m
```

Answer (score 4):

## Google Sheets, <s>39</s> 33 bytes

> Input is entered into cell **`A1`**.

**Code:**

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(4&2^29,"[^"&A1&"]")
```

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to Steve Kass.*

**Previous Code:**

```
=REGEXEXTRACT("0123456789","[^"&A1&"]")
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The number 2^29 has all the digits but 4, so 33 bytes: =REGEXEXTRACT(4&2^29,"[^"&A4&"]")

Comment: @SteveKass Nice. `=REGEXEXTRACT(0&49^9,"[^"&A1&"]")` is also a valid solution, given similar logic. Updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash (+utilities), <del>22</del>, 19 bytes

- Use `seq` instead of brace expansion, -3 bytes (Thx @Riley !)

```bash
seq 0 9|tr -d \\n$1
```

**Test**

```bash
$seq 0 9|tr -d \\n123456789
0
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@cWqhgoGBZU1KkoJuiEBOTp2L4//9/CzNzS1NjQyODr3n5usmJyRmpAA)

Comment: If you moved the space before the `$1` it would be more obvious...

Comment: @Neil, yep, that's a nice idea ! Thx !

Comment: You could use `seq` instead of `echo`:  [`seq 0 9|tr -d \\n$1`](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@cWqhgoGBZU1KkoJuiEBOTp2L4//9/C3MTS1NjQyMDAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>36</s> 30 bytes

```bash
(fold -1;seq 0 9)|sort|uniq -u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rck5DoMwFEXRPqt4RYqkQPKAJ7EVGic2AinyFzh03rvToPzu6N5XrGtf6EDEViCVHo11PkBeEPDWBaOlElD/xlcqlmaNLMOyLMfyrDAh0S2/V8I9omHuj4U@CYOcat4hEJ6t0vFtZ9l2DGdPVHL/AQ)

<s>Posting to get golfing tips over this.</s>

Thanks @DigitalTrauma, big fan ;)

`fold -1` writes one char of input per line

`seq 0 9` writes 0..9 one per line after this.

Those lines are fed to `sort` and filtered by `uniq -u` displaying only not duplicated lines.

Comment: Without changing the approach, [a couple of things to make this shorter](https://tio.run/##Rck5DoMwFEXRPqt4RYqkQPKAJ7EVGic2AinyFzh03rvToPzu6N5XrGtf6EDEViCVHo11PkBeEPDWBaOlElD/xlcqlmaNLMOyLMfyrDAh0S2/V8I9omHuj4U@CYOcat4hEJ6t0vFtZ9l2DGdPVHL/AQ): 1) have `fold` take input directly from STDIN instead of the herestring, and 2) have the `(fold|seq) output pipe directly to sort, instead of the process substitution

Comment: One of my first posts, I was an addict for some time...

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 30 bytes

```powershell
param($n)0..9|?{$n-notmatch$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSp2mgp2dZY1@tkqebl1@Sm1iSnKESX/v//391CzNzS1NjQyMDdQA)

Takes input `$n`, constructs a range `0..9` (i.e., `0, 1, 2 ... 9`), then uses a `Where-Object` clause (the `|?{...}`) to pull out the number that does regex `-notmatch`. That's left on the pipeline, output is implicit.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 5 bytes

```
A,sq-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@@@oU1yo@/@/hZm5pamxoZEBAA)

```
A,     e# The range from 0 to 9: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
  s    e# Cast to a string: "0123456789"
   q   e# The input
    -  e# Remove all characters from the range that are in the input
       e# Implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 36 bytes

Includes +1 for `-r`

```
s/$/0123456789/
:
s/(.)(.*)\1/\2/
t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@1@sr6JvYGhkbGJqZm5hqc9lxVWsr6GnqaGnpRljqB9jpM9V8v@/hZm5pamxoZHBv/yCksz8vOL/ukUA)

```
s/$/0123456789/ # Append 0123456789
:               # Start loop
s/(.)(.*)\1/\2/ # remove a duplicate character
t               # loop if something changed
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
žhISK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X4ZnsPf//4bGJqZm5haWBgA)

**Explanation**

```
žh     # from the string "0123456789"
    K  # remove
  IS   # each digit of the input
```

Comment: I like it because you can say it out loud. '"žhISK", he cried, as he waved his wand over the top-hat and a small white rabbit appeared in a puff of smoke'.

Comment: `SK` can now be `м` to save a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 5 bytes

```
ẹ:Ị↔x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9w106rh7u7HrVNqfj/X8nCzNzS1NjQyEDpfxQA)

Arguably should be shorter (I'm still confused as to why the `ẹ` is necessary), but this is the best I could do.

### Explanation

```
ẹ:Ị↔x
ẹ      Split the input into a list of characters
 :Ị    Pair that list with the string "0123456789"
   ↔x  Remove all elements of the list from the string
```

Comment: `x` implementation is old and pretty buggy, which is why you need `ẹ`.

Comment: You can actually make an argument that something like `¬∋ℕ` should work in only 3 characters – that's what I tried first – but there's multiple reasons why it doesn't, and I don't think there's any plausible way to change Brachylog so that it would.

Comment: Having `¬∋ℕ` work like that is not even possible in Prolog, unless specifically programming what you mean by not `not in`. `¬` in Brachylog is equivalent to `\+` in Prolog, and its meaning is that of "not provable under the closed-world assumption", rather than "give me choice points for everything that does not verify this" (which is almost always an infinite number of things)

Comment: The only way to do it in Prolog would be to "labelize" the `ℕ` in advance, but that would mean tinkering with Brachylog's evaluation order based on the content of the predicates. That's only one of the problems it has, though; there are a ton of others.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
¬x n45
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@39oTYVCnonp//9KhkYmpmbmFpYGSgA)

#### Explanation:

```
¬x n45
   n45     // 45-
¬          //    Split the input into an array "123" → ["1","2","3"]
 x         //    Return the sum of all the items ["1","2","3"] → 6
           // 45 - 6 = output
```

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge 98, <s>14</s> 12 bytes

I saved 1 byte by moving the program onto 1 line and 1 byte by doing some better math

```
~+;@.%a--7;#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@v07Z20FNN1NU1t1b@/9/CzNzS1NjQyAAA)

#### Explanation

The sum of the ASCII values range from 477 to 468 depending on which number is missing. By subtracting this from 7, we get the range -470 to -461. By modding this number by 10, we get the range 0 - 9, which we can then print.

```
~+;       ;#    Sums the ASCII values of all characters to stdIn
~          #    The # doesn't skip over the ~ because it's on the end of a line
~               Once EOF is hit, the ~ reverses the IP's direction
          ;#    Jump the ; that was used before
       --7      Subtract the sum from 7 (really just 0 - (sum - 7))
     %a         Mod it by 10
   @.           Print and exit
```

The reason I use the ASCII values instead of taking integer input is because the `&` command in Try it Online [halts on EOF](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#VY7BasMwEETv@oqBQkhoMG1Km@QSUnLyqYfmB2R1bQlkyUi7Dr701107SQs97uzw3owP/eJR4VAclTpbl5FtFP@FLrnAYEvI0iLW0N4jSFtRynDh@nGhE16jkltxAas9Z9QxUU8Jy3P5ASNT4ngiTAiGRuuCMK2Km61LsUm6xcXN@Mh3rw4DWxeaQqmyxhAFxurQ0N3DcQJ9r6/XP8K8dQ7fP09liV57oTyP/1sLE1Miw37AcrvZoyKjJdNvJ3faUF4V47jDG7bY4xUveMYGTz8) (Even though it should reverse the IP). The `~` works correctly, though.

#### [Old Program](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XLqvT5nKwU8801dLV1fn/38LM3NLU2NDIAAA), 14 bytes

```
#v~+
@>'i5*--,
```

The sum of the ASCII values of all 10 digits is 525. By subtracting the sum of the given digits from 525, we get the ASCII value of the missing character.

```
#v~+         Sums the ASCII values of all characters on stdIn
             Moves to the next line when this is done
 >'i5*       Pushes 525 (105 * 5)
      --     Subtracts the sum from 525
@       ,    Prints and exits
```

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, 47 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(- 45(reduce'+ s :key'digit-char-p)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(lambda (s) (- 45 (reduce '+ s :key 'digit-char-p)))
```

Explaination:

```
(reduce '+ s :key 'digit-char-p)
```

This loops through the chars in `s`, converts them to digits, and adds them. Digit-char-p, conveniently, return the number of the char as its "true" value, so it can be used as a test or a conversion.

```
(- 45 ...)
```

Subtract from 45 gives back the digit that was missing from the input.

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 18 Bytes

```
5v&;52/ni?@.>!&oW+
```

Expanded

```
    5 v
    & ;
5 2 / n i ? @ .
> ! & o W + . .
    . .
    . .
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=NXYmOzUyL25pP0AuPiEmb1cr&input=ODc2NTkxMzIw&speed=20)

Uses the same sort of method as this [brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114063/31347) answer.

Create the value -525 on the stack by pushing 5, 2, concatenate, push 5, concatenate and negate.
Then repeatably get input and add until end of input is hit.
Remove the last input, negate(make positive) the last add result, output the character and halt.

The reason for working from -525 up is that the character output is hit for each input iteration.  Since the value is negative, nothing is output until the loop is exited and the negative value is made positive.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 37 bytes

```
<?=45-array_sum(str_split($argv[1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
Cdi?B%-B%p
```

[Try the dc version online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@@@ckmnvpKrrpFrw/7@hkbGBqYm5mQUA)

This uses the fact that the sum of the digits from 0 to 9 is 45, which is 1 more than a multiple of 11.

The program works by viewing the input as a base 12 number, finding its remainder when divided by 11, and subtracting that from 12 (to find the missing digit).  The only catch is that if 0 or 1 is the missing digit, this would give an answer of 11 or 12, respectively, so I mod out by 11 one additional time at the end to take care of those cases.

---

This yields a short bash solution also:

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```bash
dc -eCdi?B%-B%p
```

[Try the bash version online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SrKCb6pySae@kquukWvD/v5GBmaGlqbmFCQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 5 bytes

```
477-/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NysTcXFf/f5q6hpKhkbGJqZm5haWStZIhlGkAZFuYmVuaGhsaGShp/gcA)

Subtracts the ASCII character codes of the input string from 477.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
kd⊍
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kd%E2%8A%8D&inputs=867953120&header=&footer=)

Imagine not having set operations.

### Explained

```
kd⊍
kd    # "0123456789"
  ⊍   # set(↑) ^ set(input)
```

Comment: [Fig lol no set operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253450/107299)

Answer (score 3):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 5 bytes

```
+0/+/-_?}*
```

Input and output are integers. [Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIrMC8rLy1fP30qIiwiWzEzNDU2Nzg5MF0iLDBd)

#### Explanation

Here's a rough diagram of the program's parse tree:

```
    +
    -
  0   _
 +     }
/ /   ? *
```

It calculates the set difference between the list of numbers 0 through 9 and the list of digits in the input (example input 134567890):

```
  /         5
  /+/       5+5 = 10
 0/+/       range(10) = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
       ?    input number = 134567890
         *  10
       ?}*  to-base(134567890, 10) = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
      _?}*  no-op
 0/+/-_?}*  diff([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]) = [2]
+0/+/-_?}*  sum([2]) = 2
```

---

If input as a list of digits is acceptable, here's a **3-byte** solution:

```
+0*-_?
```

It's the same idea, just skips the base-conversion step.

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 3.292 bytes

```
Fxcd
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJGeGNkIiwiMTM0NTY3ODkwIl0=)

```
Fxcd
Fx   # Remove all elements of the input
  cd # From the string "0123456789"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 5 Bytes

```
-jkUT
```

[try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-jUT&input=867953120&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=123456789%0A134567890%0A867953120&debug=0)

#### explanation

```
-jkUT
    T   # 10
   U    # The unary range of ten: [0,1,..,9]
 jk     # join that on the empty string
-       # set minus
```

"-jUT" also kinda works but produces newlines for every int.

Comment: The interpreter at the provided link throws errors, this one works: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XzcrOzTk/38LM3NLU2NDIwMA "Pyth – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 28 bytes

```
{(_/"")|ord _|sum|chr 525-_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#y03MzFOo5uIsKC3O0FAyNDI2MTW3sDRQ0lSo@V@tEa@vpKRZk1@UohBfU1yaW5OcUaRgamSqG1/7v/a/AUi1GVA1AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), <s>36</s> 31 bytes

```c
f(long*s){s=9-(*s+s[1]%16)%15;}
```

Takes a string as input and returns an int. As written, this work only on little-endian architectures.

The lack of a `return` statement is undefined behavior, but this works with tcc and gcc.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-tcc#@5@mkZOfl65VrFldbGupq6FVrF0cbRiramimqWpoal37PzOvRCE3MTNPQ5OrmouzoAjIT9Pg4uRUUk2JyUNgJR2gWJqGkqGRsYmpmbmFpZImTAQqYAAXsTAztzQ1NjRCiJgYGRuYWRiamitpcnFqWnPV/gcA)

#### Alternate version, 33 bytes, no UB

```c
f(long*s){*s=57-(*s+s[1]%16)%15;}
```

Takes a string pointer as input and overwrites the string with the result (allowed by default).

While this is perfectly valid C, it will *not* work with compilers such as gcc, which store strings in read-only memory sections.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-tcc#@5@mkZOfl65VrFmtVWxraq6roVWsXRxtGKtqaKapamhqXfs/M69EITcxM09Dk6uaizM5I7FIQavYmouz2FbJ0MjYxNTM3MJSCchP0yjWBFIFpSXFEBZIAVTeAJcCCzNzS1NjQyOcCkyMjA3MLAxNzbEpqP0PAA)

Comment: I like the use of longs to compress the information.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 12 bytes

```perl
$_=-hex()%15
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lY3I7VCQ1PVEMgzNDI2MTUzt7DkMoQyDLgszMwtTY0NjQz@5ReUZObnFf/XLfivmwMA)

Explanation:

Interprets input as hex string, negates it, and calculates modulo 15 (based on xnor's Python answer).

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
Num_j_&-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@@9XmhufFa@mq/f/P5ypoG5oZGxiamZuYanOhSwKFTRAEbUwM7c0NTY0MlAHAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 31 bytes

```
Fn.new{|x|"0123456789".trim(x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaiRsnA0MjYxNTM3MJSSa@kKDNXo0Kz9n9wZXFJaq5eeVFmSaoGSJNecmJOjoaSIVSpgZKm5n8A)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{|x|                      // New anonymous function with parameter x
          "0123456789"          // Declare all the numbers
                      .trim(x)  // Trim out everything included in x
                              } // The remaining number is the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org), 28 bytes

```
#(- 477(apply +(map int %)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

-1B from tsh

```
s=>9-('0x9'+s)%15
```

```js
F=
s=>9-('0x9'+s)%15
;
console.log(F('135792048'))
```

Comment: use `9-('0x9'+s)%15` save 1 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell) (POSIX shell with POSIX utility ), <s>50</s> <s>47</s> 27 bytes

```sh
$((1${1%0*}-1$1?9-9$1%9:0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdA7DsIwDADQnVN4SKUWKVKcND86cBGWqg0qSyORbIizBwZqk@nJjm3Z61y2ds9PqKnUZS4JHjugNqN1PkTAHxQE56M1qBVoinEWNcuwRpZlOZZnBfU3Vx0kUYyy9I8qqJa6UD/eSBlvow5ugjWf4PtKqiAliOMCE6Rly3Brou9RvLBT57dEgdcoo8AuXtQwtDXvqX0A)

The code above evaluates to a string of digit.

### Alternative

```sh
$((1${1#*0}-1$1?9-9$1%9:0))
```

### How it works

- `${1%0*}`. If $1 has 0, then remove digits from right up to 0; else unchanged.
- `${1#*0}`. Similar but from left.
- Why `1$1` and `9$9`? Numbers begining from 0 is octal; but it would be syntax error if $1 has 8 and 9. They are for workarounding.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 28 bytes

```
=SUM(45,-MID(A2,ROW(1:9),1))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 22 bytes

```julia
~x=(w='0':'9')[w.∉x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CVqPcVt1A3UrdUl0zulzvUUdnRez/3MQCjTodhWguJUMjYxNTM3MLSyUgG8o0ALItzMwtTY0NjYDsWE0FvRo7hYKizLySnLz/AA)

Comment: you can remove the parens around `a[.!occursin.(a,x)]` and `[` and `;]` around `'0':'9'` to save 5 bytes.

Comment: You can also save another two by defining the variable inline: `~x=(w='0':'9')[.!occursin.(w,x)][1]`

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CVqPcVt1A3UrdUl0zulzvUUdnRez/3MQCjTodhWguJUMjYxNTM3MLSyUgG8o0ALItzMwtTY0NjYDsWE0FvRo7hYKizLySnLz/AA) using ∉ and printing a single element array

Comment: Thanks, amelies. I've used your solution and changed this answer to a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

20 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
s/./+$&/g;$_=45-eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAtyPlfrK@nr62ipp9urRJva2Kqm1qWmPP/v4GhkbGJmbmFJQA)
Note that the input needs to be supplied *without* final newline (with `echo -n` for instance).

---

Some other (longer) approaches (all with `-p` flag):

```perl
$\=45;$\-=$_ for/./g}{

$_=9876543210=~s/[$_]//gr

for$@(0..9){$\=$@if!/$@/}}{
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, <s>83</s> <s>76</s> 52 bytes

```
@set/pn=
@cmd/cset/a(641670-0x%n:~,4%-0x%n:~4%)%%15
```

Takes input on STDIN. Uses @xnor's hex modulo 15 trick, except that a) Batch only has 32-bit integers, so I have to split the string into two b) Batch only does remainder, not modulo, so I have to subtrat the values from a large multiple of 15 first.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 43 Bytes

```
for(;strpos(_.$argv[1],48+$i++););echo$i-1;
```

## PHP, 50 Bytes

```
<?=join(preg_grep("#[{$argv[1]}]#",range(0,9),1));
```

Comment: save 1 byte: `for(;strpos(_.$argv[1],48+$i++););echo$i-1;`

Comment: @Christoph I have the feeling that you forget the chr function

Comment: I have the feeling you should learn your tools ;) `If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character` see [strpos on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Comment: @Christoph you are right

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 25 bytes

```
;{~instr(A,!a$)|a=a+1\_Xa
```

Explanation

```
;       Get the input as A$
{       Start an infinite DO loop
~instr  Test if A$ has an occurrence of a% cast to string       
(A,!a$) a starts out as 0. !..$ casts to string.
|a=a+1  If we did find an instance, tets for the next a
\_Xa    Else, quit, printing our missing number.
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 44 bytes

```
j;f(char*s){for(j=477;*s;)j-=*s++;return j;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@59lnaaRnJFYpFWsWZ2WX6SRZWtibm6tVWytmaVrq1WsrW1dlFpSWpSnkGVd@z8zr0QhNzEzT0OTq5qLs6AIyE/TUFJNicmDYCUdBSDf0MjYxNTM3MJSSRPCh3INoHwLM3NLU2NDIyBf05qr9j8A)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 53 bytes

There allready was a array_sum and regex solution, wanted to provide another:

```
print_r(array_diff(range(0,9),str_split($argvs[1])));
```

A few bytes more, but as bonus it will provide *all* missing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 6 bytes

```
4Y2jX-
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=4Y2jX-&inputs=012346789&version=19.8.0)

**Explanation**

```
4Y2     % Pre-defined literal for '0123456789'
j       % Grab input as a string
X-      % Compute the set difference between the two, yields the characters in 
        % '0123456789' that are missing in the input
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 26 bytes

```
v=>45-eval([...v].join`+`)
```

I'm not a big fan of eval, but it does the job.
The sum of all digits 0-9 is 45.  45 minus the sum of the passed-in digits is the value of the missing digit.

**Test**

```js
f=v=>45-eval([...v].join`+`)


function test() {

  var i=I.value;
  O.textContent = f(i)
}  

test()
```

```html
<input oninput='test()' value='012987654' id=I>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 9 bytes

```
477-_.sum
```

To use it, assign it to a variable:

```
val f:(String=>Int)=477-_.sum
```

`_` is syntactix sugar for the arguments of a function, so this expands to `x  => 477 - x.sum`, which will subtract the sum of the ascii codes of the input from 477.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
((i.10)-."."0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@6@hkalnaKCpq6ekp2Sg@f8/Kl9B3dDI2MTUzNzCUp0LQwoqY4ApZWFmbmlqbGhkoA4A)

J is always surprisingly inadequate for golfing :(

```
(                )  NB. Monadic fork: (f g h) x = (f x) g (h x)
  (i.10)            NB. Array of integers from 0 to 9
            "."0    NB. Digits of string (". = evaluate, "0 = each atom)
         -.         NB. Except
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by shortening `(i.10)"_` to `(i.10)`

Comment: @TIkkanz thanks! I never remember the left verb of a fork can be a noun :(

Answer (score 1):

## Pure bash, 28

```
a=1234567890
echo ${a//[$1]}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#Rc47DsIwEATQPqeYwm0Urx3/hDhJRGEli6CJJewOcXZDEbJbPc1MsffyQuPa1lwZzx1k7Ox8iAl0QCP6kJwlo2HOTFoyIiuaRU7kRUEURemCrQz4XeWGcYT6f9fz9RzpgddHgXrnaVoU3T59Kzv3Lw).

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 18 bytes

```
{$0=/0/?9-$0%9:0}1
```

[AWK live editor](https://awk.js.org/?gist=d8233952b193627759af0d1dccd5fdb4)

Explanation: If 0 exists in the input, return 9 - modulo 9 of the input, otherwise return 0. Implicit print.

Answer (score 1):

### TXR Lisp, 28 bytes:

This is 28 bytes. It reads a line of digits and yields a string of the missing ones as the result value;

```
(diff"0123456789"(get-line))
```

This uses the `awk` macro to do read every line of input and print the missing digits. It only adds one byte  to the length:

```
(awk((mf(diff"0123456789"))))
```

At the system prompt:

```
$ txr -P '(diff"0123456789"(get-line))'
135249
0678

$ txr -e '(awk((mf(diff"0123456789"))))'
123456789
0
234567890
1
012357698
4
13579
02468
^D
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP, <s>50</s> 39 Bytes**

<s>`function x($y){echo(45-array_sum(str_split($y)));}`</s>

[Jörg Hülsermann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59107/j%C3%B6rg-h%C3%BClsermann)'s answer prompted me to try the CLI method, Thanks.

```
echo 45-array_sum(str_split($argv[1]));
```

Test it at the command line with:

```
php -r 'echo 45-array_sum(str_split($argv[1]))."\n";' /'12346789'
```

Test it (The old version) [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd51a4c04ca9261acda396c8c8ba1107e6f6de6b) if you'd like.

[Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)'s answer put me in the right direction and I got help from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232531/1195835)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>14</s> 8 bytes

```
?⅀ȍ$-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f/lFrw4leFd3//y3MzC1NjQ2NDAA)
*-6 bytes thanks to @A̲̲*

### Answer History

#### 14 bytes

```
`0123456789`᠀-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/wcDQyNjE1MzcwjLh4YIG3f//lQyhfAMlAA)

Comment: You could have got this to [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##y05N///f/lFrw4leFd3//y3MzC1NjQ2NDAA); 8 bytes because this uses unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), <del>13</del> 7 bytes

```
'0'9.St
```

### Explanation

```
'0'9.   % Define the range of string 0 to 9
     S  % Swap so that instructions are in the right order
        % a[0], "0...9" -> "0...9", a[0]
      t % Trim out everything in 0...9 that appears in a[0]
        % The result is the remaining number
```

### W, 8 bytes

```
CJ525S-C
```

### Explanation

```
C         % Convert every character to its code point form
 J        % Sum the list
  525S-   % Minus 525 from the value
       C  % Convert to character form
          % Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

### TI BASIC, 23 bytes

```
45-sum(seq(expr(sub(Ans,I,1)),I,1,9
```

Turns the input string in Ans into a list containg the digits and then sums the list so that the number can be derived from subtracting the sum from 45. The byte count is affected by the 2 byte tokens expr(, sub(, and Str1. A full program could prompt for Str1 for 5 additional bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
žhsм
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L6M4gt7/v83NDI2MTUzt7AEAA)

```
žhsм  # full program
   м  # remove all characters of...
  s   # implicit input...
   м  # from...
žh    # "0123456789"
      # implicit output
```

`s` can also be `I` or `¹` and `h` can be `m` with no change in functionality.

Comment: The APL answer wasn't #1... [Dennis' jelly answer was](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114075/78850)

Comment: oof ok guess i didn't look far enough :/

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, 16 bytes

```
477SSm8[a+A{]x-n
```

[Try it online!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=477SSm8%5Ba%2BA%7B%5Dx-n&stdin=123467890)

### Explanation

```
<implicit input>     - Push STDIN to stack
477SSm               - Push 477 (the sum of all digits' ASCII codes) to the bottom
      8[    ]        - Loop 9 times:
        a+A          -   Put loop counter in register, add the top two digits, then take it back out.
           {         -   Decrement the loop counter
             x-      - Remove the loop counter, then subtract the sum of all digits from 477
               n     - Output the result as a number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 28 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 28 bytes.

- Filename (Unprintables are escaped): `\011.t.w0.i.-.+.m\001.-.c.t.a\055.-.n`
- Content: empty.

[Try it online! (with pxem.posixism)](https://tio.run/##1Vr/U9vGEv9df8VxGEuykS0ZQwD5SCmBJlOCO5C@9r2YMEI6Yw22pJFkG2O7/3q6dyfZkm0cSJNMXydF57vdvc/u7e59dayo89n2e4HbpYqqSBGNkUb7Zr9nRfdI12s1kz4Efhij85Ob4/NzcmLGo4CiOxrbvtdGR1WHDqpev9tFtaOiUSzyVhDYszxnuTWR9dvxh7cEF5SUTgtmAlmTWhizT/lwKgraFKcofr949@fN1Yc3pKbrO2nlb82rd3@e//fmpHl5eXrygRimbUUU4cL45@Ortzf/Ob28ete8OCyPphi5njJSuZY@CvzIfTDZj/LPpkkjy54x/m8lH@31u1ZMUdRhXH4QQ2noh04UdN3YtLquFSHtDsmFsVHGhZ/wVCYy@8rmxe/n5yfv35DDfD8K69wxo47bjjkQBzH6pILaHR8VNlXeu6Hyn7HvI7/rgOpujIxEGh1YXYQ3UNvqRhRPJmO0inYKvcaNhiYbUdxxQllq9z07dn0PWbdgRqUX3anjIHS9GGEahn6IDIQR1HIBiq6a0zkLjFekhDTettWx21bc2367TUNCMFbHbT@0abvbjzqKagINUYA6puEEPl3XoyihVk3ghPYG0VX49EMPwce0u35EExbo0yYJOaO2N/7CCKtpdxgcA1QeR/1bBaNKqYC3MQZIJq/4@AldlxCvmvU4dfxu1wp1YptJl2CYmVY9a3SbIh/zbxTToFxmXc9@HhFetOLUWvynOWsnujmdi8waYywhlGWBn1kuKWNfN7rtWt69YnOmBKpNyE5tMlEOGsQuFu0GMXZUxvXz6S/vLhgd7QXxiGD@wTPxBPMPXuoPodQamDdyP1bAXFFs2ffb@BCr@erIfaTz6hBiV2F/IkodXtWzwFN1jkk4mSRtohjgsLCJmC0QtewOiuzQhejx2@Jn6Pdj8AtpcxNVpJBaju91R@C@VtTjacKKUaMhf2geX73PeC18rcCNra7iZY2k7O02iFcseg1yoKuvFa@8U1MPvQXr2j0nz9aCIkKKBybeUcHGrLCXFl4lhXraVN@FQspzMOvQ0Gvw3SAHe@Kzn6ECLkPPshn6wYyvJvgMYyf5vsoPLAwADa1uMk5BSAdizKZStlVJCywMXxf0Q6WgQwjjlIDLFLrPjVfQVbVYFCKJ48dMILh7wgLx9knEEf9bwNxmMPgswLItIs7mHTGiuZi/qpWqyuvSCMDdOS5GPU1jo43wlt3y8HYOorlgBKG4QF3goXN68SYPfd7nqh6nEvcnScUS87uf0Jvmhzfvj08um29PL09zXji8z3vhH7/K85Fx7zw/pDcO0AdW3BFh5dEoZrEigroAhsUWTtDN2iDrjbPwKhabOCFMIAWBSFQZbqPKA/w/2kYQOJVHjCYIMxjGUbGGzSzvJopGXmw9IJG4g9C/C61eQpPk/8TIaf@aZq6GDy6yUEmMMWd8iIU6f1U/fRw@jB6vC9VxRiLkSdZsgLZdru2dSMO6dnBdBvfgWeWj64g8AoXra1I0Zz@AXSQWwcYcquUhlCQbVlWpMCdTzdRVComxU1zQcQAdC5u0JIxYxlFcMutCM0z3CHR0NU0dg48JotSKM3zutZlpdGiXskl/Vet0Vpr1AeLxEiw/DwvcQIke57jUI30dHqDVDHUtqBUkc621DOBlbN7LsHk9sq5X5uG9Rp4lVai@a@ZqvV6JwJBk6qaZsh@R@n4Z@EDglgEpINPGxhWAiMYqa/R6R7qZq1qAsCgOpjWebpQWbrW8FlaB4ikoAn6@/RuOgJsfgaz153xg2GS23iAAGavZjmaR9XhNEqo5J1siMXa@ZlMRjOeLWJ8izo5cuo5gwMzlmGChvaT1zXKommZu0OYqkyWVUUYjtoBMFrEtXLk5hKUBbA2oHVMHnTbPgHHBQ9PVVSJ90VW@VjKCBO7BSqZPn3KkrEawmMh3G90Rw/xGQG5hArt/FordZRTaD4NR32@kTlcsJoXG7v4XDbNWbhaf6wX9GHl@DKWY3tEwB3Gaja6nsCBnkNZr9f2FsFruy42e7G61i2dNu6TXs23EQA5Khl5W5lhf6JwLnWfmthUTd3RXcgbPDXX7ZVNMLs08K8FCr@sSbPSy/r9hah88J7WLVQosSxpseooeqzXYGpfLeZsMyRPrk0x13ljuEuilVhIN18Jv4/melad5mC9d2OstU9K8otmddMZL@rcB8JeNVRLClw0Sa4@DJfdQWRzl3H4WoiFLVw5tw1bT4XtRIF3IWIvS@HKC73PVUhyoa201/OJ8ttooX1YVoaGzNg6e5bJPOG0CAHpYmYBWKPrwDRUltQVNH27JhrKoRiNXUYNR/grtVxHVnjYRqS3Z6OH2eQYafU8DjVYZ6OjfYaDRMw30@D0N9HhLluxDyL/DQI/PNJCVz7srKOKXZcsOtQLygzaUvSVorPcNwo8lV0/0yhz4NWHUXzPLO9xouXMcc/nMRRyH6KsOP4wlkeUvWXnB@xZdo/yjbK79Q6Dalzb1iwwNtoNeqFvczX9D/Tb@oX6lHzUQhRcCHRhkXT4Z1L4LcA5sYJRAfG5HVzhEjzT0NccduJHre@uWR4CUDGpHA@M1WyQNatWBoR7yolEd1Navlbb@r6209Q@stDW30tYaK81Ps9PctbF4Xnzhw44uDGkU@J7jeneoYvFV7Xc5N@bH5X/8Ko7L0R31aMhuQtmFz@z6RpyQa3Lbs3o0f8PIL4bAImIi4nrwGYlPCfx8N3N8KqUCJOkQ8XLPdZwuRcWilFwRbEXsltbY3CxVp6Ce5DtIO0Ye0mLUN5A2gKo4RNpJhHSjtlPf3Xu1f4Dkjy2vdC1D211IA1SBgjW8Z9SwryH1PRDJ75xw0oALyvxSYitqtTxBMbxnFIAZthEyt1Q1N@lU7ZYkw3@ZCVxcMpkYqGVuw0SxNqAErfh1rTyVmW3tDrXvYeDBFWwaRVbI7iAQu49AbbdLJbYHIzqDTIkupRfWqSlgOJRS5WP77Lqk8u0aMZC4JX6KlJ4mpHSJlPGzP1QQ67PJM6VjcH0vph6/y2PwkBWldyxZKUKAwa5jmJfggiFMuGLcEFo3cgjNxi4ZgKhaKVVXn1HkLxeqgl8Rxp65ZrqnHcsmw2aidDBUKdVyrkhqiRWGmMUEbHIXI4IZKR8QyU74mQGRPSIQDcDLUxg/JpBWHwMIGnZaIC0uo3hMJ6ikXFDV/rXhlMwXLfELL9uEnamIYxOeVOeEqXESg6TUmnF9nT9UWeabk7LF51L7qruhBaLpYkXKMz8HWiBIk4U5yxY5R4KcIUtrtJeer7C0rKP0hFrJ7eESeEn4EYBiQdB2PavbHUkiOiRJ/bzJ/NqhYQUFD7RnV/ijGzfqVRi1DxGVtDzkWuIOHSErpKgd@j3enmvu@Y7bdsFfLHQLHbFZ78O7JmuBf504DqLDavXOjTv924rt96q/vNU@BBY9s4aP1KvmxEmbwJKrYSe4Jyd6RZLOLo7fn7K738Rp5ZZuGJW4MtQrbkWrlCu9lq4bULKh0mrpu7tQ9mQYsavm75cnp0SWP2dji8vDk6GNNJtPxrnIEzxPNnPmVURKEnXJqxSGV7wcUpSCkr6rOr785eb98Z/8HdZkwttren1f1Q5UVcWMXTy4IZgNF9I8Y8KTAOSAQdw3JqvCH0H0T0TsT1jwapRl40@oVIVUK36gUgF@cPnpQxGG7yMDzx@H9Vk1DPF1sQiV4VLlHIRTR9pFPUcgUDkZVNpkogQRsPgoAL@lsduj24Ed9LcH0aPpQHpWs3rVJ0@mtVSx2HK7YI56jasoG25L0mpG/VV9f2evvi@x2aelVFrj/da0pRaqLaMqT5IBkcdWmT1OmLLFnMhelgnzCkbi7Rt7dDfzirkDqDgZIFksymqo67PJH4BQR1ZTYEknPeuhS72vHXQRmwSnDs4rRVgSLH4BCAhu@CWWj0gWTx@al1fsIcb5GUnvUTGkMdVssudP1U/cGQtV9jasSYihJs@euGR0fsbJ@FoXaLmagnQlnbjr35lk1rAi@dUh@ZGLM5H2BGfz7AoV3CzpVDScn2UrBWTM09RWn702KdTEOzn4AiTttXi1IDTYaKbihb0AlZHIbSPcam35wJ/qM05kD@M2yM12yuXv7Ah/WNIWPGMSdZAWfX5V042d@sHe/t8)

### With comments

```
XX.z
# push 9; heap=pop
.a\011.tXX.z
# while empty || pop!=0; do
.a.wXX.z
  # push 48; push getchar
  .a0.iXX.z
  # push abs(pop-pop); if size>=2; then push pop+pop; fi
  .a.-.+XX.z
  # push heap; push 1; push abs(pop-pop)
  .a.m\001.-XX.z
  # dup; heap=pop
  .a.c.tXX.z
# done
.a.aXX.z
# push 48; push abs(pop-pop); printf "%d", pop
.a\055.-.n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.3](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.3), 129 bytes

```
func main:
lda 0
sta $1
in ""
conv ~arr:char
pop $a
push "0123456789"
.lbl a
push $a
ldelem $1
sub
inc $1
push $1
push 9
sub
brtrue a
print
ret
end
```

**Commented and ungolfed:**

```
func main:
    ; Initialize $1 to 0
    lda 0
    sta $1

    ; Get the input, convert it to an array of <char>s, then store it in $a
    in ""
    conv ~arr:char
    pop $a

    push "0123456789"
    .lbl loop
        ; Get the <char> in $a at index $1
        push $a
        ldelem $1

        ; Remove it from the <str> currently on the stack and push the updated <str>
        sub

        ; Increment $1 and stop looping if $1 == 9
        inc $1
        push $1
        push 9
        sub
        brtrue loop

    ; The string will now only contain the remaining digit.  Print it
    print
    ret
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Mascarpone](https://github.com/catseye/Mascarpone), <s>82</s> 53 bytes

```
[9876543210]$v[v'$>,<]v*'#<^v'.>1#########^0123456789
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y00sTk4sKsjPS/3/P9rSwtzM1MTYyNAgVqUsukxdxU7HJrZMS13ZJq5MXc/OUBkG4gwMjYxNTM3MLSz//4czAQ)

#### Explanation

```
[9876543210]$      // push the string '[9876543210' (we can ignore the '[')
v                  // push the current interpreter
 [      ]v*        // define an operation (under the current interpreter)
  v'$>,<           // "bind a symbol from stdin to 'Pop ToS'"
           '#<^    // bind this operation to '#' and install it to the environment
v'.>1              // push an interpreter that defaults to "Output ToS"
     #########     // bind 9 symbols from stdin to "Pop ToS"
              ^    // install this interpreter to the environment
0123456789         // one of these will output ToS, the rest will only pop
                   // the symbols to output are on the stack from line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```factor
[ "0123456789"swap ∖ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQma@QnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXmpeZnJ@SqmDNxaVkaGRsYmpmbmGppKCgqKBrp2AAFIMKGcDEjLiULMzMLU2NDY3gYiZc/6MVlAwQ@ovLEwsUHnVMU4gFShQUZeaVKMQqJOfnFuQXpyqUFGU6/AcA)

Set difference (`∖`) with `"0123456789"`.

Answer (score 1):

### x86‑64 assembly machine code, 17 B

#### input

- address of string buffer in 64‑bit register `rsi`
- string buffer consists of exactly 9 ASCII-encoded Western-Arabic digits

#### code listing

```
  1                      missing_integer:
  2 00000000 6A09           push 9          ; rsp ≔ rsp − 8  rsp↑ ≔ 9
  3 00000002 59             pop rcx         ; rcx ≔ rsp↑     rsp ≔ rsp + 8
  4 00000003 31C0           xor eax, eax    ; eax ≔ 0
  5 00000005 BADD010000     mov edx, 477    ; edx ≔ 477
  6                      .digit_sum:
  7 0000000A AC             lodsb           ;  al ≔ rsi↑     rsi ≔ rsi + 1
  8 0000000B 29C2           sub edx, eax    ; edx ≔ edx − eax
  9 0000000D E2FB           loop .digit_sum ; ecx ≔ ecx − 1   ZF ≔ ecx = 0
 10                                         ; if ¬ZF then goto digit_sum
 11 0000000F 92             xchg eax, edx   ; shorter than `mov eax, edx`
 12 00000010 C3             ret
```

#### output

- the “missing” integer in `ax`

Comment: `mov dl, 477%256`

Comment: @l4m2 I don’t understand. The algorithm relies on the value `477`, not `221`.

Comment: You only need `dl`, or if you want to return whole `eax`, `movzx eax, dl` is only 2 bytes more, `mov` saves 3 bytes

Comment: @l4m2 I’m sorry, I don’t see it. Could you submit a full/complete answer/solution?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256651/76323 Later found `xor` shorter

Comment: Was `push 9/pop rcx/mov dl,221/lodsb/sub edx,eax/loop $-3/movzx eax,dl/ret`

Comment: @l4m2 I now see what you’re doing. That’s neat.

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -R, 15 bytes

```
explode|477-add
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@1oiAnPyW1xsTcXDcxJeU/139DI2MTUzNzC0suQyjDgMvCzNzS1NjQyOBffkFJZn5e8X/dIAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2.5 bytes (5 nibbles)

```
`r-_$
```

```
`r-_$
`r      # get the first integer found in
        # the string of
  - $   # remove the command-line arg 
   _    # from the string in STDIN
        # (but if there is no STDIN,
        # from all printable ASCII)
```

Input string is provided as a command-line argument.
If STDIN is empty, [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) assigns a default value of 'the list of printable ascii characters in a more useful order".
The first (and only) integer present in this list after the input string is removed should be the missing digit from the input string.

[image]

(Note that since [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) will check to see if there's anything in STDIN, in the screenshot above I've pressed 'ctrl-D' to terminate STDIN with no input)

Answer (score 1):

## x86‑64 assembly machine code, 13 B

```
f:      use64
6A09    push 9
59      pop rcx
6A01    push 1
5A      pop rdx
a:
AC      lodsb
30C2    xor dl, al
E2FB    loop a
92      xchg eax, edx
C3      ret
```

read string from `[rsi]` and return `rax`

Comment: Just to clarify: In contrast [to my previous (longer) solution](/a/253638/94076) this function returns the ordinal value of the respective ASCII character. I understood _You must return the missing integer._ that necessarily an integer value was expected.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt Then change `push 1` into `push 49`

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

```
10,`^~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmvZGFmbmlqbGhkoPTf0EAnIa7u/38A)

There's a shorter, 4-byte solution if input can be taken in the form of an array of integers:

```
10,^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfbaFgpmCuYKlgqmCsYKhgpGAQ@9/QQCfu/38A)

## Explanation

```
10,`^~

10,     # create an array of integers from 0-9
   `    # convert it into a string
    ^   # setwise difference
      ~ # dump array onto the stack
```

The 4-byter just removes the need for a string because it takes input as an array and the difference doesn't include any `[` characters, removing the need for the `~`

Answer (score 0):

## Lambdabot Haskell, 14 bytes

```
(['0'..'9']\\)
```

After realizing I could just make a list with the String "0123456789" instead of the integers [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], the step for converting the string to integers could be skipped.

Type is now String -> String (takes a string and returns a string with the correct number). Call like:

```
(['0'..'9']\\)"149263708"         -- Outputs "5"
```

### Previous:

```
([0..9]\\).map digitToInt
```

Uses set difference, unlike the other Haskell answer, type String -> Int

Call like

```
([0..9]\\).map digitToInt$"123467890"  -- Outputs 5
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 25 bytes

```
->x{'0123456789'.tr x,''}
```

Not terribly competitive, I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 5 bytes

5 bytes seems to be the number for all golfing languages that aren't Jelly.

```
,tDCa
```

Takes input as a command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@69T4uKc@P//f0sLczNTA2MjQwA)

#### Explanation

```
,t     Range(10)
  DC   From each element, delete all characters...
    a  ...that are in 1st cmdline arg
       Concatenate and print (implicit)
```

The result is actually a list like `["";"";"";"";4;"";"";"";"";""]` (which is what you get if you put `RP` at the front of the code). Lists by default are concatenated together before printing, so all you will see is `4`.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 31 bytes

```c
f(x){return x?f(x/10)-x%10:45;}
```

Strictly speaking, f(x) returns the sum of the missing digits. This lets me knock off a digit, get the sum of the missing digits, then add it back on.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-clang#@5@mUaFZXZRaUlqUp1BhD@TpGxpo6laoGhpYmZha1/5XzsxLzilNSbUpLknJzNfLsOPKzCtRyE3MzNPQrObiLCgCctM0lFRTYvKUdNI0LMzMLU2NDY0MNDWtuTih5hpYc9X@BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 14 bytes

```
@(a)477-a*~~a'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkahpYm6um6hVV5eo/j8xr1hD3cDQ2MTUzNzCUl3zPwA)

Developed independently but the same as some other answers.

```
a'          transpose of array `a`
~~a'        convert all elements of a' to 1
a*~~a'      matrix multiplication of `a` with a column vector of 1s
            that is equivalent to sum(a)
477-a*~~a'  subtract from [477=sum('0123456789')-48]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>61</s> 54 bytes

```
long d(int n){return(15-Long.valueOf(n+"",16)%15)%15;}
```

Based on [*@Neil*'s JavaScript (ES6) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114077/52210) (just like JavaScript, Java uses remainder for negative-modulo. Original port is from [*@xnor*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114113/52210))

**Old answer (61 bytes):**

```
String c(int n){return"0123456789".replaceAll("["+n+"]","");}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#jY4xC8IwEIV3f8VxICSoxaitipO74uAoDjFJJXCmpU0Fkf72GqEoChaHW@699/E1imRZwvbeAyi99FbB3hfWnUEx6zw4fi@MrwqHYzGZzuJkvlhiVJicpDJrIoYHHLgBHnGIyFf1G0NZgOhPCBPxaBP@0VVSZXYpC0scioT3Rfy8sA@AvDpRALSca2Y1XKR1LLVOUqt3OILkT2mA/a305hJllY/yEHlyTLGXLOerjlZbGne2Fsl8GU/FpKvVJr9i/ZeQ/ktIfwvVvbppHg)

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 36 bytes

```
#=0123456789
arg n
say verify(#,n)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 39 bytes

```
i=[%1%]
Send % RegExReplace(99066**2,i)
```

Again, the inherent confusion between the input variable `1` and the actual number 1 causes confusion in AHK functions. At least it only cost 3 bytes this time.

`99066**2` = `99066^2` = `9814072356` (a trick I copied from [Rod's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114070/38183))

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 21 bytes

```
z=>45-z.Sum(v=>v-'0')
```

The expression `v-'0'` takes the char value such as `'3'` and subtracts the char value for `'0'`, leaving the value 3, essentially converting the character 3 into the integer 3.

45 is the sum of all the numbers 0 through 9.  45 - the sum of the passed-in integers yields the missing integer.

Sample code

```
public static void Main()
{
    Func<string, int> X = z=>45-z.Sum(v=>v-'0');
    
    Console.WriteLine(X("123456789"));
    Console.WriteLine(X("134567890"));
    Console.WriteLine(X("867953120"));
}
```

Test Here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/yanR5S

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 64 bytes

```
Azv~a
##'Bzv~b
`^v##'Czv~c
*f|`^-##'Dzv~d
Z~'~e `^-##'
ZZZZZZZ~S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/chip#@@9YVVaXyKWsrO4EZCRxJcSVAdnOQHYyl1ZaTUKcLpDrAuSmcEXVqdelKkBEuKIgoC74/39zE0MLUyMDSzMA)

Chip is a 2D language that operates on individual bits in a byte stream. Each byte of input is broken down into its component bits for computation, then stitched back together for output.

This solution uses a rather simple algorithm, that is only a minor twist on that used by many of the other solutions:

1. Start with a value of `0x2`:

   ```
    0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 =  45 (0x2D)
                    ~45 = -46 (0xD2)    *
             -46 & 0x0F =   2  (0x2)
   ```

   <sup>* I only do half of two's complement negation; I skip the increment at the end for a reason. I'll get back to this.</sup>
2. Add each code point in the string, masked with `0x0F`, ignoring carries.
3. After the ninth addition, the current value will be equal to -1 minus the missing digit, masked with `0x0F`:

   Let's say we were missing the digit '4':

   ```
                 -1 - 4 =  -5  (0xB)
                  ~(-5) =   4  (0x4)    *
   ```

   <sup>* Again, we only do half of negation. This instance cancels out the offset introduced by the previous negation.</sup>
4. Prefix the value with `0x3`, giving the codepoint for the missing digit:

   ```
             0x30 | 0x4 =  52 (0x34)
   ```

What portions of the code do each bit? Well, they're a bit mixed together, but I'll try to cover the highlights:

- The `#` elements do the addition described in step 2.
- The `z` elements near the adders carry over the current value to the next cycle so that we can have a running sum.
- The `Z` elements keep track of which digit of the input we are on, handling the condition in step 3. They also provide the signal used to initialize the adders to `0x2`, as described in step 1.
- The `S` element suppresses all output until the `Z` elements disable it on the final digit. (If you are looking at the TIO, try deleting this element to see all the intermediate values. Also, adding the flag `-v` will print the actual code points to stderr.)
- The letters `A` through `D` are reading the 4 low bits of the input, and `a` through `d` write those same bits of the output.
- The letters `e` and `f` provide the value `0x30` to the output as described in step 4.

Answer (score 0):

## D, 24 bytes

```
writeln(477-readln.sum);
```

Just add up all characters in the given string (*not* terminated by a newline).
The sum is `s = 48 * 9 + (0 + 1 + 2 + ... + 9 - x) = 477 - x`, therefore, `x = 477 - s`.

The calls make use of [optional parentheses](https://dlang.org/spec/function.html#optional-parenthesis) (-4 bytes), and `.sum` invocation uses [uniform function call syntax](https://dlang.org/spec/function.html#pseudo-member) (-1 more byte).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/d#y8wtyC8qUSguSdFLzEnPL8osycjVAfGAODPfmqssPzNFITcxM09Ds/p/OVA6NSdPw8TcXLcoNTElJ0@vuDRX0/p/7X9DSyMDYwsTM1MA)

Answer (score 0):

### Q, 24 bytes

```
{1#iasc"0123456789"in x}
```

Gets a boolean vector between the expectation and input, then sorts the indices of the expectation by that boolean vector in ascending order, first value always being the missing element since boolean for it is set to 0 and we know that value=index in this case.

Answer (score 0):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/), 8 [bytes](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

```
ɲdFḶṡạĖ⁻
```

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=%C9%B2dF%E1%B8%B6%E1%B9%A1%E1%BA%A1%C4%96%E2%81%BB&input=%22098765432%22&run=false)

---

### How it works

```
ɲdFḶṡạĖ⁻
         # Input implicitly pushed onto the stack.
ɲd       # Pushes the string "0123456789" onto the stack.

  FḶṡạĖ⁻ # Loops nine times removing digits from the string "0123456789" producing the missing number.
  F      # Pushes the string "F" onto the stack.
   Ḷ     # Consumes the string "F" and converts to a base 98 number producing 9 then loops the following that many times.
    ṡ    # Swaps the string "0123456789" with the input on the stack.
     ạ   # Gets the ith element from the input and pushes it onto the top of the stack.
      Ė  # Grabs the string "0123456789" at the bottom of the stack and puts it at the top.
       ⁻ # Removes the element pulled out of the input from the string.
         # Implicit end of the loop.

         # Implicit push to the screen, outputting the missing digit.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 106 bytes:

```
(filter-not(λ(x)(member x(string->list(number->string n))))
(for/list((i(range 48 58)))(integer->char i)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f n)
  (filter-not
   (λ(x)
     (member x
             (string->list
              (number->string n))))
   (for/list((i(range 48 58)))(integer->char i))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 867953120)
```

Output:

```
'(#\4)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
ɳą←ą\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5OYjrY/aJhxpjfn/X8nQ0tjCyMzUxFwJAA)

Takes input as a string (with quotes)

```
ɳ          push "0123456789"
 ą         convert to array of characters
  ←ą       get input string; convert to array of characters
    \      set difference; implicit print
```

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
Ś9△-~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6CzLR9M269b9/29oaWBhZGZqYg4A)

Takes input without quotes

```
Ś        implicit input; sum of digits
 9△      45 (9th triangle number)
   -     subtract
    ~    negate; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kDḍ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhZLs10e7uhdUpyUXAwVWbBaycLM3NLU2NDIQAkiBAA)

##### Explanation

```python
kDḍ  # Implicit input
  ḍ  # Symmetric set difference
kD   # with the string "0123456789"
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 43 bytes

```rust
|s:&str|s.bytes().fold(477,|s,b|s-b as i32)
```

This is the same strategy as in [Level River St's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114060/output-the-missing-integer/114091#114091).

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMGWtDyF3MTMPA1NhWouzpzUEoU0BdulpSVpuhY3tWuKrdSKS4pqivWSKktSizU09dLyc1I0TMzNdWqKdZJqinWTFBKLFTKNjTShWjo4rbk4C4oy80py8hQ1lKprlXQU0jSULAyNjM1NTM0slTQ1sSowNLIAyxvgVmBMSIGJsbmppYEFWEEtxD0LFkBoAA)