# Shortest Code to Find the Smallest Missing Positive Integer

Tags: code-golf, array, algorithm

### Description

Given an unsorted array of integers, find the smallest positive integer that does not appear in the array. Your task is to write the shortest code possible to solve this problem.

### Input

A non-empty or empty array of integers, where the integers may be negative, zero, or positive.

### Output

The smallest positive integer that does not appear in the array.

### Test cases

Input: `[1, 2, 3]`
Output: 4

Input: `[3, 4, -1, 1]`
Output: 2

Input: `[7, 8, 9, 11, 12]`
Output: 1

Input: `[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10]`
Output: 4

Input: `[]`
Output: 1

Input: `[-1, -4, -7]`
Output: 1

Scoring criteria: Your score is the number of bytes in your code, as counted by the bytecount tool. The code with the smallest number of bytes wins. In the case of a tie, the earlier submission wins.

```js
var QUESTION_ID=258335,OVERRIDE_USER=117038;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: You say the input must be non-empty yet one test case is a empty list

Comment: Ooops, thanks, the array can be non-empty, but.. lemme edit it

Comment: Why even say "non-empty or empty". That's just a array lol

Comment: I am literally so confused rn XD, I hope the wording is fine enough,

Comment: Can the array be assumed not to contain duplicates?

Comment: @UnrelatedString duplicates are allowed

Comment: [very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/114060/107299). im quite sure theres a dupe somewhere

Comment: sorry but its not at all related, its asking for missing integer from 1-9 in an answer, while I am asking for smallest missing positive integer in an array.

Comment: I mean 'not at all related' as these are not clearly close to be called duplicate

Comment: @AiraThunberg i didnt mean that the related one was a dupe. we like to link to related challenges in comments

Comment: In my opinion, this question is neither a dupe of [Minimum excluded number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/minimum-excluded-number) nor [Output the missing number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114060/output-the-missing-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1) because they are both looking at only fixed ranges (0-9 and 0-20).

Comment: @chunes do you suggest me to cast a reopen vote?

Comment: @chunes yes, while they are fixed ranges, most answers can be trivially ported back and forth. that is our requirement for dupes

Comment: Suggested new test case : [3,2,1]. My answer worked for all the test cases but failed when dealing with this particular case. Also in my (quite new) opinion, this problem is a bit different from [Minimum excluded number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/minimum-excluded-number), because i had a bug regarding negative numbers when trying to port my previous answer, and it was fun to solve :)

Comment: Where is the *bytecount* tool documented in the question? I tried https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=bytecount and various Google searches, e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=codegolf+stackexchange+bytecount+tool&hl=en , but there wasn't anything useful or official.

Comment: @pts done, i added it

Comment: Suggested test case: `[1, 4, 3, 2] -> 5`. This foils solutions using an incorrect recurrence relation.

Answer (score 12):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-1`, 4 bytes

```
ŇPᵖf
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpKuoVLsgqWlJWm6FsuPtgc83DotbUlxUnIxVGzBzZRoQx0FIx0F41iuaGMdBRMdBV2ggCGQZ66jYKGjYAnkgASMgCK6pkBZkAqgQl0jiEoDoBzEAB0FoDRQk6EBUClItSFUtXksxDIA)

The flag `-1` set the interpreter to `FirstValue` mode, which prints the first possible result.

```
Ň        Non-deterministically choose an natural number
 P       that is positive
  ᵖ      and such that
   f     the input doesn't contain this number
```

---

### [Nekomata v0.1.0.0](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata/tree/v0.1.0.0) + `-1`, 6 bytes

```
ℕPᵖ{-Z
```

This is the original answer in an old version of Nekomata. Some symbols are changed in newer versions.

```
ℕ        Non-deterministically choose an natural number
 P       that is positive
  ᵖ{     and such that
    -Z   it minus the input doesn't contain any zero
```

Comment: Cool language! Glad to see someone's made a backtracking stack language

Comment: How does this code guarantee that you get the smallest such number?

Comment: @DanStaley [Non-determinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_programming) doesn't mean that the choice is random, but means that there are multiple possible values. The interpreter chooses the correct value via backtracking. The first value for `ℕ` is always the smallest one.

Answer (score 8):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>3</s> 2 bytes (4 nibbles)

```
/-,~
```

I somehow didn't expect that `fold`-ing over an infinite list, starting from infinity (the right-hand end) would work, but it does.

```
/-,~    # full function
/-,~$$  # (with implicit arguments shown):
 -      # remove
    $   #   elements of the input list 
        # from
  ,~    #   the infinite list of positive integers
/       # now fold over this infinite list from the right
     $  # each time returning the left-hand argument
  -     # (so, finally, returning the first (left-most) element)
```

[image]

Comment: nibbles is written in Haskell, which is pretty good about lazy lists

Comment: I really like that trick of folding over the list and returning the implicit argument as a way of getting the first item of a list lol, seems like it might come in handy somewhere else as well

Answer (score 7):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 21 bytes

```bash
seq inf|grep -xvm1 $1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwXJD24TkxJKEpaUlaboWW4tTCxUy89Jq0otSCxR0K8pyDRVUDCFyC6DUakMuIy5jLjMuQy4TiBAA)

- `seq inf`: list of all positive integers
- `grep`: filter those for

  - `$1`: any of the lines in the input
  - `-v`: inverted match (i.e., it must not match any of the input items)
  - `-x`: match whole lines, not substrings
  - `-m1`: output only the first matching line

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
ℕ₁≜¬∈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/eobcOjpqaHuzprH26d8P9Ry9RHTY2POuccWvOoo@P//@hoQx0FIx0F41gdhWhjHQUTHYV4oIghiGuuo2Cho2AJ5IFEjEBC8aZAeZAaoNJ4I4haA6AkxAwdBaA0UJehAUgtWL0hVL15bCwA)

*-1 stealing [Fatalize's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/252022/1) to the dupe target--note that my <s>accepted</s> reverted golf suggestion fails on the empty list. Whoops*

Reversed I/O.

```
ℕ₁       The output is a positive integer.
  ≜      Try every value for it until one
   ¬∈    isn't in the input.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [flax](https://github.com/PyGamer0/flax), 7 bytes

```
∵µḟκ→A∴
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLSexYsGCpaUlaboWGx91bD209eGO-ed2PWqb5PioY8uS4qTkYqjshmilaEMdXSAy0tE1jlWKhYoDAA)

[image]

### Explained

```
∵µḟκ→A∴
∵        ⊳ min of
   κ→A∴  ⊳ range(1, abs(max(input)) + 2)
  ḟ      ⊳ set diff with input
```

Comment: The test case says that if all numbers  in index are negative then output must be 1, whilst your code gives error when all elements are negative

Comment: +1 Nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.reduce(m=>m+a.includes(m),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZBBDoIwEEX3nmKWbZwCLRh0ARcxXTSlGAylBsTr1yKuSEyJs528/9/MXb3UpMfu8WSDa4xvK6@qWiWjaWZtiK1qe1RJN@h@bsxELEVOvXbD5HqT9O5GWnLlCAIhlxAbSiFNoThs@ByhQGAhhssdvNjyJcIZ4RLwJULICM@3PDuF9sUgiDCxmmQhaT0LIaxDBc/kD//44ZF@/u0v5V98/hHlu//v3w)

Comment: This is really clever! I had a hard time understanding why it works, but now it's ok :) You could also post nearly the same solution to this problem : https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/minimum-excluded-number (and beat all of its previous JS answers)

Comment: @Fhuvi Thank you! Posted. :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
1ḟ1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w4Y75hsr/D7drRv7/H22oo2Cko2Acq6MQbayjYKKjoAsUMQRxzXUULHQULIE8kIgRSEjXFCgPUgNUqmsEUWsAlISYoaMAlAbqMjQAqQWrN4SqN48FAA)

```
  1#    Find the first integer
1       starting from 1
 ḟ      which is not empty with elements of the list filtered out.
```

Answer (score 4):

## x86-64 machine code, 13 bytes

```
31 C0 FF C0 89 F1 57 F2 AF 5F 74 F6 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVJNj5swED3jXzFLlcosQwQkadqk6WXPvfRUKZuD15jgKjEIOy0R4q@XHRMlWiGN5@PNe@PBsmmSo5TjKOwZOPwKOSs3QVe3oESH3rB2E2gjJzc4139BSV@wmgXNxVbQFuS1qjEKrBS2oHTd3LJ/FLS@5lgUQrRlqnOqNRC@hNBr46Dk3j4LBH@aaDsw9om0TpdCwXfrCl3Pqx@MWSeclmBde5EOnLKOhNSNw2ynZrHP8gP134t2f4Ad9KxfYJ9hjothQNYvkeIlJhlmU7zCfo1f8RtmlMmnVJZjn6wwIdQCk9xjU5wYcIVrzNIJlWI/ncROAA9e@3jYMj/MWWjDI9azoKRFcnFxNXx2sHmMbiMWUDVoWoKXPJxp4CHSPtycluHmJqJtBbduT6jpLildFJ52vkpeHBPFBwI700QQ0hfDk/YcYq8PE8sdE72a0CcGFrBH8tX8FLLS9PNkXajNBPCKnVdEuFJY1NDf4TBL898kdN1xfjFWH40qQFaifY7KaN/FMUkO8K/SJwX86sdNu5eFJ30wcLrs25U24edB6Kg4jON/WZ7E0Y7J@cuSDL3GHeHV6R0)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes the address of an array of 32-bit integers in RDI and its length in ESI, and returns a 32-bit integer in EAX.

In assembly:

```
f:  xor eax, eax    # Set EAX to 0.
r:  inc eax         # Increase EAX by 1.
    mov ecx, esi    # Set ECX to the length.
    push rdi        # Save the value of RDI onto the stack.
    repne scasd     # Compare EAX and the value at address RDI,
                    #  advancing the pointer and counting down ECX,
                    #  and repeat as long as the result is unequal and ECX≠0.
    pop rdi         # Restore the value of RDI from the stack.
    je r            # Jump back if the last comparison result was equal.
    ret             # Return.
```

Comment: My first thought was a (potentially huge) bitset, using `bts` to construct it, and `not`+`bsf` to scan it for missing numbers.  (Or init to all-ones, `btr` construct from the array, `bsf` to find the first uncleared bit.)  That would have O(N) run time instead of O(N^2), but would require more code.  I'm curious how much more.  `rep scasd` gets the linear search done very compactly.

Comment: 32-bit mode could save a byte here, allowing 1-byte `inc eax`.  (The calling convention wouldn't be one of the standard C conventions for 32-bit mode, but that's [allowed for asm / machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020/30206).)  push/pop instead of 2-byte `mov` is break-even in 32-bit mode, or a win vs. 3-byte `mov r64, r64` in 64-bit mode, so that's good whether you use `push`/`pop` to save/restore here or to copy a register, e.g. if you took in dummy=EDI, len=ESI, and pointer=RDX).  I don't see any savings.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,i=1:i in a and f(a,i+1)or i
```

A recursive function that accepts the list and returns the first missing positive integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BCsIwEEX3nuLvmuAEmlapFupFxEWkBgOalpqNlJ49Tow1iyHz5r9hxne4D76O0XYP87z2BoZcp1sH58GN72EFo62WwwQXLddwe4U0FhvwO2tCRagvlNuasCMopnpFDeFAODJJtFqx2nMuZVlRVXZKDuR9BB6zqcs1//f0z2uYyPYLx8n5IGwxp@MWdCfMVqS/XAoZPw)**

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
-#Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1c58P//aF1THQVdEyA2BmIjIDbUUTDQUQCSQA5QDChtDuQaxAIA)

This challenge is extremely well-suited for Pyth. Let's go through it step by step:

- `#`: This is the filter function. The predicate function that is used as the filter is `-TQ`, where `T` is the variable representing the values being filtered over. No explicit input is given. When no input is given, `#` outputs the first positive integer for which the predicate function gives a truthy output.
- `-`: This is subtraction function. It is called on `T`, a positive integer, and `Q`, the input list for the program. When `-` is called with an integer followed by a list, it returns a singleton list containing the integer, if the integer is absent from the list, or else an empty list.

Here's an equivalent Python program to the above Pyth program, to hopefully make it clearer what's going on.

```python
import ast
Q = ast.literal_eval(input())
T = 1
while True:
    subtract_in = [T]
    subtract_out = [elem for elem in subtract_in if elem not in Q]
    if subtract_out:
        print(T)
        break
    T += 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7RCoMgFIbvfYpzWaxGrY3BYA8ReBcRNoxkpmLHjT19OxaMduBX/@8/HnUfHK2plkVNznoEMSOr4R73o1YovdCdfAmdKOMCJmnKOKUle49KS@A@yBsDqjn06MUDO2Uob3j7T23AiKWWEwzWw3qg1v01NWzYWIxRvY0gup@yvRbLeWUw4ekP9F6K5@o4HOiPy9LklwzyM6kinUhlBkUGtJIhRvGVbNF@AQ)

Comment: you seem to be rather good at pyth :P

Comment: @mathcat Gee, I wonder why that might be

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal),  <s>6  5</s>  4 bytes

```
?F)ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI/RinhuYUiLCIiLCJbMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsN10iXQ==)

*-2 thanks to @lyxal*

##### Explanation

```python
?F)ṅ  # Implicit input
  )ṅ  # First integer where:
?F    #  Remove elements from the input which are in this number
      #  (i.e. is the number not in the input)
```

Comment: `c` automatically swaps arguments if one is a list and one is a number/string, so the `$` isn't needed

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI/RinhuYUiLCIiLCJbMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsN10iXQ==) for 4 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 10 bytes

```haskell
he<df[1..]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ0W0km5yQYFS7E3VzNyC_KIShcLSxJzMtMzUFIWAotSc0pRULqhEAFeabczS0pI0XYtVGak2KWnRhnp6sRCBnbmJmXm2mfkqxRk2aTZQjXpFqYkpEPkFN7WidU11FHRNgNgYiI2A2FBHwUBHAUgCOUAxoLQ5kGsANRIA)

My first hgl answer. Returns the first element of the "set" difference of the input from the positive integers.

Potential useful additions (or that I couldn't find):

- a two or three byte alias for `[1..]`
- find the first item in the list matching a predicate (`(hd<)<fl`)
- find the first positive integer matching a predicate (a special-cased combination of the above two; like Jelly's `#`)
- (I didn't use it in the code itself, but in the footer), `read` Maybe there's some fancy equivalent in `P.Parse`, but I couldn't find it

I'd like to set up an instance of [hoogle](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle) for hgl - it would make searching for things easier.

Comment: I only saw this a year late, but I'm very glad to see someone using hgl! The `nN` is the alias for `[1..]` you were looking for, it was added in October 2021.  Finding the first element of a list matching a predicate is `g1`, however that was added after this answer was written albeit indpendently. The other things don't exist at the moment.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 31 bytes

Unlike [pxeger's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258341/86147), no external programs, just pure shell constructs.

```sh
<<<${${${:-{1..1$#}}:|argv}[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cm6mhqfHfxsZGpRoErXSrDfX0DFWUa2utahKL0stqow1ja/9rcnEBVYKwgqGCkYIxmGWkoGuooAvkKRj@BwA)

```sh
       ${:-{1..1$#}}             # List from 1 to a number bigger than the length of the list.
                                 # It's shorter to prepend a "1" than to add 1.
     ${             :|argv}      # :| set difference with the list
<<<${                      [1]}  # print the first result
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 31 bytes

```r
\(x,y=seq(c(1,x)))y[!y%in%x][1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhb7YzQqdCpti1MLNZI1DHUqNDU1K6MVK1Uz81QrYqMNYyGqbqanaRhaGWsqKCuYcKUBVRrrmOjoGuoYaoKEjMBC5joWOpY6hkBBI7CoIVhU19TKWMdUx1zH0EAToR1ZgaGOLtAsc4gQxLoFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 27 bytes

```r
\(x){while(T%in%x)T=T+1;+T}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuha7YzQqNKvLMzJzUjVCVDPzVCs0Q2xDtA2ttUNqISpupqdpGFoZayooK5hwpWkkaxjrmOjoGuoYaoKEjMBC5joWOpY6hkBBI7CoIVhU19TKWMdUx1zH0EAToR1ZgaGOLtAsc4gQxLoFCyA0AA)

Naive approach. For a clever one (and currently longer) see [@Dominic van Essen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258369/55372).

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
f a=filter(`notElem`a)[1..]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h0TYtM6cktUgjIS@/xDUnNTchUTPaUE8vVlHR4H9uYmaebUFRZl6JSpoKSNQ49j8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 6 bytes

```
ṀŻ‘ḟ³Ṃ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzoajux81zHi4Y/6hzQ93Nv3//z9a11BHQdcEiM1jAQ)

#### Explanation

```
ṀŻ‘ḟ³Ṃ  #                  | [-1, 0, 1, 4]
Ṁ       # Maximum          | 4
 Ż      # Range from 0     | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  ‘     # Increment        | [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   ḟ    # Filter out items |
    ³   # In the input     | [2, 3, 5]
     Ṃ  # Minimum          | 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -ap, 20 bytes

```perl
1while++$i~~@F;$_=$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@wPCMzJ1VbWyWzrs7BzVol3lYl8/9/XVMFXRMFXWMFXSMFXUMFAwVDBSMFYwVTBXMFQ4N/@QUlmfl5xf91EwsA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@øX}f1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QPhYfWYx&input=Wy01LCAtNCwgLTMsIC0yLCAtMSwgMCwgMSwgMiwgMywgNSwgNywgMTBd)

```
@øX}f
@  }f  # first positive integer where the following is false:
 øX    # the array contains the integer
```

Comment: [Ninjaed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258358/58974)!

Comment: [The output should never be 0](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QPhYfWY&input=WzEsMiwzXQ) - it says positive integer, not non-negative.

Comment: @TheThonnu Oops will fix, now it's exactly the same as Shaggy's lol

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), <s>70</s> 65 bytes

```
j=join(x,0)
l=[isgn(i-j)^2.minfori=[1...j.max+1]]
f(x)=l[l>0].min
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h0e9etscpj)

-5 bytes thanks to [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow).

Comment: [65 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ts1jtgqnup)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 14 bytes

```
{(~^x?)(1+)/1}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxtj7FuwjAQQHd/xVXqAKqNc3aiQDx07tSlG6JqFJzEIsQ0NlUQKt9eG5DSgc137/klrovz7PI5vs5n+DLn+EuIL87P69NlKGoAGNWX3anZV12aTo3qpIb5JjprBAFSpZtwlJACQ0Al4pTDElaAYRYK44JlwIIggYmoJXC9ChnkgMmt8JTcVbyqeZwIJ633B1dwXtmtbmxXL5wvq50eq7bsG72o7J5/H7XzxvaOi2wpZcZdawcfdixeYt6y2vRb5lvN3L7sukj2xjnTN+xgnfHmRzPTe93ogZCPgKEqnXaEvPWHoy9gjRQEBbkh70d/3aQTkxRSGh5FAScuJp5TWFJYBRwVMTk4OSwLhVgJMSZutSTYt89SCDhkMHn4A4+LeC/m//EfdIGGxw==)

Sets up a while-reduce, seeded with `1`, that proceeds to the next iteration (adding one) if the current value is already present in the original input.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 22 bytes

```powershell
for(;++$i-in$args){}$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBRS8MwFIWfm19xH4JrWAJrp0yRQWDoq@J8E5Eab11HXWaSolD72@stTYe@Jec73wnkaL/Q@R3WtTLWYc/LdduX1qXX8zmvVHXghXv3ou141XeM6ZQlUqc6zSTkEpZCwrmI0ZLOEhSRjOJ8ilcSLiVcUTqQXAw4InVB/cEhVeWjuyA@bksgTHa2@PvKPz@L/mpMBfzArXU3hdmpu9c9mgAtS3hAHzaFRwkcv4@U4husgb8QcuibOtDtjJegpyJLnu63m8YH@zHOPGvaSbaNMej94J52FH5CXKHGYxwYKtMYqL2tDjCTMyo8TO@dnI7Rt/a/)

Takes the input array using splatting, returns an integer

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```
~x=argmax(!in(x),1:1+max(0,x...))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjcV6ypsE4vScxMrNBQz8zQqNHUMrQy1QVwDnQo9PT1NTajCHQ6JxcWpRSUKddGGOgpGOgrGsQq2tgomXAhxYx0FEx0FXaC0IVjOCEnOXEfBQkfBEigFkjYCyxsiyeuaAnWCdAMN0TWCmGIAVAmxSkcBKA00wtAAw1JMkwyhJplDpCDuh3kYAA)

Returns the first index of range [1,max+1] that isn't in the input. To accommodate the empty list, the input is padded with `0`.

- -3 bytes thanks to MarcMush: replace `findfirst` with `argmax`
- -2 bytes thanks to MarcMush: replace`0∪x...` with `0,x...`

Comment: -1 byte: `max(0,x...)`

Comment: here too, `argmax` can save some bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 26 bytes

```julia
>(x,i=1)=i∈x ? x>i+1 : i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc0xDsIwDIXhnVO8EYQj1WlRAcmBeyCGDgxGTJRKmTr3nFwkuA1DpK7@7N/P4aUdx5TCNpIK70S/0xRxQQy6Z5yhaRSEzbXr@8f7g/HGBE@o7xBBU8xrQkNwxryYL6wlHAkno5n94ly4O9jlfG0R53Olss38imBsCa5WT9cl/pfaTOkH)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞IKн
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8T@8Le///jzbUUTDSUTCOBQA)

*-1 thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

##### Explanation

```python
∞IKн  # Implicit input
∞     # Push the infinite list [1, 2, 3, ...]
 IK   # Remove the elements of the input
   н  # First item
```

Old:

```python
∞å0k>  # Implicit input
∞      # For each number in the infinite list [1, 2, 3, ...]
 å     # Is it in the input?
  0k   # Get the index of the first 0 (0-indexed)
    >  # And increment it to make it 1-indexed
```

Comment: 4 bytes: [`∞IKн`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8T@8Le///jzbUUTDSUTCOBQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
Ｉ⌊⁻…·¹⊕Ｌθθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYq7CoAwEMB@peMV6iC6OToJCuIqDqUetdCe2Nfvn7okEGIuHc2tPfMaHWUYdcqwOHKhhN8lwUTGl@QqbposQqvEVyIGpIwnzEg2X/BIKZX4KQfmfe@U6JVovrk9Dm6qfwE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Now a port of @GammaFunction's jq answer.

```
   …·       Inclusive range from
     ¹      Literal integer `1` to
        θ   Input list
       Ｌ    Take the length
      ⊕     Incremented
  ⁻             Set difference with
         θ  Input list
 ⌊          Take the minimum
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Would have been 6 bytes if the input had been guaranteed to be a nonempty list of positive integers:

```
Ｉ⌊⁻⊕θθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzczLzO3NBdElxZreOYlF6XmpuaVpKZoFGrqKBRqAoH1///R0YY6CkY6CsY6CqY6ChY6CobGsbH/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ   Input list
   ⊕    Vectorised increment
  ⁻     Set difference with
     θ  Input list
 ⌊      Take the minimum
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@øX}f1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QPhYfWYx&input=Wy01LCAtNCwgLTMsIC0yLCAtMSwgMCwgMSwgMiwgMywgNSwgNywgMTBd)

```
@øX}f1     :Implicit input of array U
@          :Function taking an integer X as argument
 øX        :  Does U contain X
   }       :End function
    f1     :Get the first integer >=1 that returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 61 bytes

```
=@LET(a,A1#,b,SEQUENCE(MAX(a,-a)+1),SORTBY(b,XMATCH(b,a),-1))
```

Input is spilled array `A1#`.

Comment: 48 byte solution that assumes values are input individually into the cells in column A but you could save a byte by replacing `,A:A,0)` with just `,A#,0)` if you *did* assume that: `=MIN(IFERROR(""&MATCH(ROW(A:A),A:A,0),ROW(A:A)))`. Don't change `ROW(A:A)` to `ROW(A#)`, though. That would only work if the size of the input is larger than the first integer that was missing and that's not the case for `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @EngineerToast Great stuff! You should post that! I guess we can make it 44 bytes, viz `=MIN(IFNA(""&MATCH(ROW(A:A),A:A,),ROW(A:A)))`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 26 bytes

```
$[a][min--@1..+1max a++1a]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?qjFp9c)

```
$[a][              ; a function taking an argument a
    min            ; the minimum element of
    --             ; the set difference of
    @              ; the array of
    1..            ; the range from one to
    +1             ; one plus
    max            ; the maximum element of
    a++1           ; a with 1 appended (for empty input)
    a              ; and a -- the second argument to set difference
]                  ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```javascript
a=>(g=i=>a.includes(++i)?g(i):i)``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3LCsIwEEX3fsUsEzopTapUhdQPEaGhL0ZCIlb9/TilriTrc@65d/dxS/@kx0uFOIxpssnZVsyWbOtKCr1/D@MiioLkZRYkzyS7LvUxLNGPpY@zmMRVIxiE@ibl7o/UCHsExYLO0AbhiHBiuAomY6gDr9cCh5TZShW72yECY47oKjPN1fSv1jBMXw)

Port of Jonathan Allan's Python answer.

*-1 thanks to @Shaggy*

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY3LCsIwEEX3fsUsEzopTapUhdQPEaGhL0ZCIlb9/TilriTrc@65d/dxS/@kx0uFOIxpssnZVsyWbOtKCr1/D@MiioLkZRYkzyS7LvUxLNGPpY@zmMRVIxiE@ibl7o/UCHsExYLO0AbhiHBiuAomY6gDr9cCh5TZShW72yECY47oKjPN1fSv1jBMXw)

Comment: @Shaggy thanks, updated

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
`@Gm}@
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%60%40Gm%7D%40&inputs=%5B-1%2C+-4%2C+-7%5D&version=22.7.4)! Or [verify all test cases](https://matl.io/?code=%60%0A%60%40Gm%7D%40%0A%5DDZxT&inputs=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B3%2C+4%2C+-1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+11%2C+12%5D%0A%5B-5%2C+-4%2C+-3%2C+-2%2C+-1%2C+0%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+5%2C+7%2C+10%5D%0A%5B%5D%0A%5B-1%2C+-4%2C+-7%5D&version=22.7.4).

#### Explanation

```
`      % Do...while
  @    %   Push interation index, 1-based
  G    %   Push input
  m    %   Ismember. Gives true or false
}      % Finally (i.e. execeute when exiting the loop)
  @    %   Push iteration index
       % End (implicit). A new iteration is run if top of the stack is true
       % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) NumPy, 31 bytes

```python
lambda a:min({1,*a+(a>0)}-{*a})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BDoIwEEX3nuLvbHUwFDSoCVxEXYxRIomUptYFIZwdBxG7mzfvTera8GhsOpT5eXhyfb0x@FhXVnWGVrxWXMS6j7oV93qoatf4APuuXQvwC9YtysYj3F8BlYVaQN7JEBJCeqFpTAlbQiTUzCgj7AkHISNNZhztxBtdSaJkamIRpnsEWUtp4tn/d@bXZUL08Qudr2xQ5bIbP9cjL9CVyroNe8@tGqHW/VIPHw)

Expects a numpy array.

### How?

Returns 1 if that's not in a and otherwise the smallest successor of a positive number in a that's not in a.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 38 bytes

```python
lambda a:[*{*range(len(a)+2)}-{*a}][1]
```

Uses set differences to get the missing number after removing negative numbers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BDoIwEEX3nuLvbLUktGhQErgIsiixVRIsBLoxhLPjVMRZzbz5bzL92z87lyw2vy2tftV3DZ2Vh9F4Nmj3MKw1jml@VJxHAdaw3YAajYNGY1EXMa9KWS0BezP6sGE7UJVSQAkklVjHROAkEBGVG0oFLgJXIoGqDUdnyoUsKZFanZgC6z0BWpMp4y3/9@TPS4nw7Av7oXGe2f0UnpuRF5gsCz2f93z5AA)

-22 bytes by using `{}` to make set. And no need to check if positive

Comment: Pretty sure this works just fine for 38 bytes: `lambda a:[*{*range(len(a)+2)}-{*a}][1]`

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 46 bytes

```swift
var l={(a:[_])in(1...).first{!a.contains($0)}}
```

The type signature `[_]` tells the compiler to infer the `Array`'s `Element` type via type inference (possible thanks to the `1...` range).

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 17 bytes

```
1
While sum(Ans=L1
Ans+1
End
Ans
```

We first put 1 in Ans for the first pass of the loop. Because we're using the While loop the condition will be checked first before the loop runs and 1 will return if it's not in the list. The condition returns a list with the operation against each element so for example a list {1,2,3 will turn to {1,0,0 then sum to 1 and pass the condition allowing the loop to continue. the loop itself then can track the counter in Ans instead of needing to store to a variable. After the loop finishes we use the implicit final line Disp to display the value in Ans.

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 26 bytes

```
[range(1;length+2)]-.|.[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxCoAwDEV3T5FRMSlNVVQ8SungUCoiguLo3fUXHf97L1mP5/HnvKdY6rTFPV1L7aog5jbeBjhlckxNKHzD1DIJgGL1TAPTiJGBA5EONhcIxX2lhfseMEHjSC3SXOtf9@EF)

| Input: | `.` | `[]` | `[5,1,0,1]` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Need to add 2 because `range` isn't inclusive | `length+2` | `2` | `6` |
| `[]` makes it a list | `[range(1;length+2)]` | `[1]` | `[1,2,3,4,5]` |
| `LIST - LIST` is set difference | `[range(1;length+2)]-.` | `[1]` | `[2,3,4]` |
| Select first element | `[range(1;length+2)]-.|.[0]` | `1` | `2` |

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 66 bytes

```python
lambda l:min(i for i in range(1,abs(max(l or[1]))+2)if i not in l)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BTsMwEEX3nGJ28YhxFKdULZVgwRnYhSxcxS5Gjh05LoKzsKmE4E69DWOS5f_vzZ-v3-kzv8Zw-bYPLz_nbOX--uT1eBw0-MPognBgYwIHLkDS4WSEIn2cxag_hIeYOtUj3rboLDsh5uJ5XJeey6l3wZQ2TiaIButk9CCwnifvcmGzwMOUXMiipNq_necstg1VUCFV8rEiK8y79v8Ycd2-XIdOEbQEm_6m2xDcEUguFKcdwZ7gnkMpWm7klmkxWJTtYjbMlgECxnykGlaLrVZ71y_P_gA)

### [Whython](https://github.com/pxeger/whython), 57 bytes

```python
lambda l:min(i for i in range(1,max(l)+2)if i not in l)?1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1NTsMwEIX3nGJ2mRHjKE6p-iNBL8GudGEUuzVynChxKT1LN5UQ4ky9DWPS5XvfN28uv6fDOR26eP12z28_x-TU8rYKpn1vDIR16yN6cN0AHnyEwcS9Rc2t-cJAjzV5JyB2KcNAG30feM0XwUeb-663ESsqB2sapHLsg0-ZjUjrfvAxYU5l-DiOCecVF1AQF-qlYIf204R_TETT9vXWbDVDzTDbPWxnDE8MSgotacGwZFhJyEUtjZoLzYaIqp7MStg0wCBYjnQlarb13V7spmd_)

Whython's `?` command catches the error of either from either `max` or `min`.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 31 bytes

```haskell
import Data.List
head.([1..]\\)
```

A port of [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258349)'s answer using only the standard library. I quite like the approach using Haskell's lazyness.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
1▐╙)╒\-├Þ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/w0bQJj6bO1Hw0dVKM7qMpcw7P@/8/2lDHSMc4livaWMdER9dQxxDINNex0LHUMQRyjIA8XVMdXaCUsY6uEUiBgQ5Yh46pjrmOoQFQHqTEEKzEPBYA)

**Explanation:**

```python
1▐         # Append a 1 to the (implicit) input-list
  ╙        # Pop and push its maximum
   )       # Increase it by 1
    ╒      # Pop and push a list in the range [1,max+1)
     \     # Swap so the (implicit) input-list is at the top of the stack
      -    # Remove all those values from the ranged list
       ├   # Push its first item (without popping unfortunately)
        Þ  # Only keep the top item of the stack
           # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 19 bytes

```
{first *∉$_,1..*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxBCsIwEAXQq3xKKFomoUnV1kW9SCnBhQFBsaRuSuler@lF4ox1@f9/M8Ml3g7pPiEPaNMcrnF8ovi83sqTNaZY0niekClvBpabLdoT5gDllwzhEdFZgiNUPaGrCDuC5sZKrAkN4chJGieV3vMuhql2qy15XH8QeOYrW4r9efv3dZ@@)

Returns the `first` element of the lazy sequence of positive integers `1 .. *` such that the number is not an element of the input list: `* ∉ $_`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 25 bytes

```
1//.x_/;#~MemberQ~x:>x+1&
```

[Try it online! (verifies all test cases)](https://tio.run/##ZYzBCoJAFEV/5aLgpnHG0cIyk7YtoqJ2ImGh5UILGUEQ/XV7k@1a3nPOe2WqnlmZquKejvlmlELw9irW5rDPyltWn4Y2iNqZtMZjXVQqNnbVu1EBjDC6vM6K2CM2kzAyAM45cGjUn8@pSBJYEFt06CSDy@D1DJ3HMGewiUg9fYYlw4qWJq5G9oK8bii13al1SE4/GEjTlXR0@@3lr/d79OMH) Exact same implementation as [this earlier answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105412/find-the-smallest-number-that-doesnt-divide-n/105426#105426), except testing whether the temporary variable is a member of the input rather than divides the input. (Has the same limitation as that answer, that Mathematica's default recursion limit is 65536.)

Comment: `MemberQ`->`!FreeQ`

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `lists.lazy math.unicode`, 36 bytes

```factor
[ 1 lfrom [ ∌ ] with lfilter car ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc09DoJAEIbhnlN8HgDC8hP8OYCxsTFWhGKDS9y4LLgsMUjoLTylF8EBDd3MkzczBc9tZcbz6XDcb9GIeyt0Lhoo2djGU/zZ/UbchNFCoeT26rVa5tVFoDbC2q42UlvsHKd3ejAECDFghYi2EBFcRjhBQJBgjQ0YUTAbI3NjuJSFcIMp9v83YoqZv5xaajbXyQIh1WzJGH2cZNpjZxhTElWYqkSKz@uNDA9pr0RSWWGQc4NsLHkNb/wC)

- `1 lfrom` the natural numbers
- `[ ∌ ] with lfilter` select the numbers that are not in the input
- `car` get the first one

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) -F, 35 bytes

```php
for(;in_array(++$i,$argn););echo$i;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZHLDoIwEEX3fMUsWJTQCgUMGjTu/AnTEMKzhtAG3Pjz1uGxIwbiLGeSM@fO6Eaby0032rKzvu7gCs9BdWlR5qooydRzElOpniSyS7O@z97EdW1Jl5GTlHmjbJkYz8tVN6i2PLSqJhV5cAoBhVDAVjkOeB5E1ooQUogoMARxsYMQrAkxhROFMwJGSCA2CHxNYEc0GC1QhgWzjY@sORwFHOMS7oufKbYPsOnAF4dY/EkIJ12@@xdmf@6P0i@J2wy7fwE)

I did something a bit unusual here, as command-line arguments give a string, and question says we are provided an array, is to decode the string off the byte count. If you think this is wrong I will include it in the count

Answer (score 0):

## [Java 8 (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 53 bytes

Solution using inline stream :

```java
l->l.stream().sorted().reduce(1,(a,b)->a<b|b<1?a:b+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZI7T8MwEIBn@itutIVtNSmoPEIQI1KZOiKGS@JGDs5DtlOpgv72cCFB6ko8Wff47vPJFR5Rtp1uquJz6PrMmhxyi97DG5oGvlYroGOaoN0Bcw07CsF8KAoHVhFB9cFYtTM@JK9UWmqXguWPv5XnCeEDBmLvwMLTYGVqlQ9OY8248q0LuqCL00WfaxYJhiLjMsUk@86S6BkfsuuIDxNvlpx5x9YUUJMq2wdnmvL9A9CVnpPm1f7kg65V2wfVUS7Yhll1KfziHJ68Qj@a01iIBWw4J/H/9m4E3AiQhIgW9W8F3Am4p/YRES9iyFsyGC1IRsaTzZpo07MEUJrGROtF8GVG0Wy0XbrU@G@h8086Dz8)

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 160 bytes

This `function` requires a processor compliant to at least ISO standard 7185 “Standard Pascal”, level 1.
Note, in Pascal it is not possible to specify “empty arrays”, therefore the fifth test case is not applicable.

```pascal
function f(x:array[m..n:integer]of integer):integer;var s:set of integer;i:integer;begin s:=[];for i:=m to n do s:=s+[x[i]];i:=1;while i in s do i:=i+1;f:=i end
```

Ungolfed (Extended Pascal, ISO standard 10206, level 1):

```pascal
type
    natural = 1..maxInt;
    integerWithoutMaxint = -maxInt..pred(maxInt);

function naturalSupremum(
        { This is a “conformant-array parameter”. It permits us writing a
          generic routine without specifying the array’s size in advance. }
        sample: array[indexMinimum..indexMaximum: integer] of integerWithoutMaxint
        { The `array` may not contain the value `maxInt`, hence the restriction
          to `integerWithoutMaxint`. Otherwise the `result := result + 1;` will
          overflow if all values in the interval [1, maxInt] are present. }
    ): natural;
var
    range: set of integer value [];
    i: type of indexMinimum;
    result: natural value 1;
begin
    { transform ordered list to “unordered” `set` -------------------- }
    for i := indexMinimum to indexMaximum do
    begin
        range := range + [sample[i]];
    end;
    
    { analyze step: find first `natural` not part of set ------------- }
    while result in range do
    begin
        result := result + 1;
    end;
    
    { In Pascal there must be exactly _one_ assignment to the
      implicit result variable bearing the same name as the function. }
    naturalSupremum := result
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 REPL, 52 bytes

```python
next(i for i in range(1,max(_+[0])+2) if i not in _)
```

Returns the first integer in the range `[1, (maximum of input and 0) + 2)`, that is not present in the input.

Replacing `max(_+[0])+2` with `10**9` saves 7 bytes, but assumes the input it short enough.

Using the REPL so we can take the input as variable `_`.

Comment: This looks like it's intended to take input as a variable. You should check out our [allowed input methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).  You could make this a function by adding `lambda x:` to the front,

Comment: @WheatWizard According to https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8580/117110 I can take input as "the value of the last expression". Can I replace `x` with `_` and be done?

Comment: That only works int the repl, which is fine, but it's not an answer in Python 3, it's an answer in Python 3 repl.  So you can replace `x` with `_`, but you should modify the header to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 17 bytes

```
{1+⊑/¬(«↕2+≠)∊}
```

[Try it online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=aW4g4oaQIOKfqDEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDfin6kKezEr4oqRL8KsKMKr4oaVMiviiaDwnZWpKeKIivCdlal9aW4=)

#### Explanation

```
{1+⊑/¬(«↕2+≠)∊}
{     (      )∊} 1. Is the input in...
      ( ↕    )    2a. the natural numbers from 0 to...
      (  2+≠)    2b. the length of the input plus 2...
      («     )    2c. left-shifted (to get rid of 0)
{    ¬          } 3. in -> not in
    /             4. Which indices are true
 1+⊑              5. Take the first (add 1 due to 0-indexing)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>58</s> 57 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!*

```c
i;c;f(a,k)int*a;{for(i=0,c=1;i<k;i=c-a[i]?i+1:!c++);a=c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDNT4MwFL/zVzxZltCtILDp1I6ZHYx3t3jZCMEO9GV8mIEXF/52fJRtIrGXtu/32UrzXcq6RiFFbIR8zzArR6E4xvnBQM/m0nMEzvcCPWmGG/Qfcew8XMnxmInQk6KqB5jJ5GsXwbwod5hbHwvtzyjBt2amDXZRjFkE66fV2rAsi8ERthrQokQoo6Lc@OBBELwug@XL8yoIRAcv8DsitNny2GjYDK7PVyKwDnkEaZQSOQ2TJJdGV3OhfR6IGBv6sNA56BvQL4h6OCUiOdiCtrmKoRO9@VeHQELVGn3Gm0Q6kOQ06uf4YC5giNuMVG0XrmzbRpWmNZFpiBkY9DFKqj7qCA4Hl8MEKia64wmHKQeTUKcPzTjccbgnpEHdPmzekK7RkoXpth42P@dwIJgcHLuv69s4J5tZH7k4TZXZLe82@oc8VeS2Z1X/AA)

Takes as input a pointer to the start of an integer range, and the number if integers in said range.

I almost had 44 bytes with the beautiful-looking recursive `i;f(a,k)int*a;{a=k?i+=(i=f(a,--k))==a[k]:1;}`, but this unfortunately doesn't work on specific unsorted arrays, such as `[1, 4, 3, 2]`. :(

`i=0,c=1` feels clunky and long but I don't see a way to eliminate it.

### Explanation

Abusing K&R C implementation for saving lots of bytes:

- `i;c;` instead of `int i,c;` for some global variables
- `f(a,k)int*a;` instead of `int f(int*a,int k)`
- `c-a[i]` instead of `c!=a[i]`
- `i=...?i+1:!c++` instead of `if(...)i++;else i=0,c++;`
- `a=c;` instead of `return c;`

Comment: @ceilingcat Ty!

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda x:min({1,*range(max(x)+2)}-{0,*x})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NDoIwEITvPMXEE8Vt0gL@JvoiyAEjKIlUAxwwhmfH7qKempn5ZqfPV397uGSqDqfpXjTnS4Fh39QufFuK2sJdy7AphnBQy1iN@m0oGkY19WXXdzggC4DMEmJCkhOyhJAStHcsyw1hS9h5xU7Mll75nBmP6nhmjQ/nGwQf@5Y1OfFpToXeSJd52fnjqTTWUvpN4UukQsiqNSYP8qB6tOCvo3bydns/8mxr14csCQt9XBAqUUpNHw)

A non-recursive approach that works by generating the set of all possible numbers it could be (and 0), removing the ones it can't be, and selecting the smallest remaining number.

Alternatively, `range(1,max(x)+2)` and `{*x}`, but that looks less fun :>

Comment: It looks less fun but wouldn't it be shorter (making sure to replace `max(x)` with `len(x)` to account for the empty list)? Like this is 39 bytes: `lambda x:min({*range(1,len(x)+2)}-{*x})`

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƘƇ~
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU5OCVDNiU4N34mZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lNUItNSUyQyUyMC00JTJDJTIwLTMlMkMlMjAtMiUyQyUyMC0xJTJDJTIwMCUyQyUyMDElMkMlMjAyJTJDJTIwMyUyQyUyMDUlMkMlMjA3JTJDJTIwMTAlNUQmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
ƘƇ~  # Implicit input
Ƙ    # First integer where:
 Ƈ~  #  Not in input
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 39 bytes

```rust
|v:Vec<_>|(1..).find(|i|!v.contains(i))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMGWtDyF3MTMPA1NhWqunNQShTQFW4WlpSVpuhY31WvKrMJSk23i7Wo0DPX0NPXSMvNSNGoyaxTL9JLz80qA2oo1MjU1ocr3W3MVFGXmleTkKWooVVvZ1yrpKKRplKUmK0Yb6igY6yiYxGpq4laja6qjoGsCxECVukZADNRkoKMAJI3AuoHS5kCuAV5DgCosdBQsgeqA-gyN8FtoCLXQHKysFuKNBQsgNAA)

Now the thing with this solution is it returns `Some(n)`; not sure if that's allowed. So here is a solution which returns an integer instead:

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 48 bytes

```rust
|v:Vec<_>|(1..).find(|i|!v.contains(i)).unwrap()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fY9LDoJADED3nKKwmkmGCSAGxN8t3BhjCDLJJDgSGHABnMQNC72Be8_hbWyArSzapul7bfp4FlWp-7dQcI2lIhQaI0s1CNjCq9LCDr9OW0eHNNmcdy1xOadcSHUhrWzNmic3pVEriaSUV-pexDmhk_dZG3khlc6USawm2ncWA0HqNDGPLoMFA_9E6X_GXjKwfQwkbQ8DJYcBZm-wcRxg68wuQSJksEIOPdebP-hOB4MB68Y3-n6sPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 61 bytes

Port of [@Jonathan Allan's Python code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258368/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBSwMxEIXv/RWP0kOCs6XZKrULK3gU9FQ8lR7SNVtT1qxugiBlf/s6ySq4nibzvnkvyfhKN3poj2dTBTxp63CZAS@mxhs3QncnX@C@6/TXfhc6604HWeDZ2YAyTQKfukEwPnhWHq0PIqkYz4qQE9aS/oprwjUhY6amYEO4JWxZjyyfwuyGPdHH9iwf/SseG28gMGa/Wk1d/zLUT8ZGJlnOUknPX9ZtZ3T1KmKH8g7v/N3QOOHni19pcakTlv1cxoR@iJuqhS525mP/4MKBbMGlVDIVy2hZtS7wLr2wUnJP9kpJ03gDO/TDNw)

```
def f(a:Seq[Int],i:Int=1):Int=if(a.contains(i))f(a,i+1)else i
```