# Output your Score!

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, self-referential

**Challenge:**

The concept is simple enough: write a full program to output its own code golf score!

Output should only be the byte count of your program and a trailing  `bytes`.

**BUT WAIT**..... there is one restriction:

- Your source code can not include any of the digits from your byte count
- So if your score is `186 bytes`, your program can not contain the characters `1` , `6` , or `8`

**Example Output:**

```
315 bytes
27 Bytes
49 BYTES
```

**Additional Rules:**

- Unnecessary characters, spaces, and newlines are forbidden in the source code, however trailing spaces and newlines are perfectly acceptable in output
- There should be a single space between the number and `bytes` in the output
- Letters are case insensitive
- No self inspection or reading the source code
- [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed
- this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so

**Shortest code in bytes wins!**

Comment: Does this need the [tag:quine] tag, or may the code self-inspect?

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but what is a `trailing byte` (I'm sorta new ).

Comment: @Dat, given the formatting of the word `bytes` I suspect the intention is that the count should include the bytes it takes to print the text: `bytes`

Comment: Are leading spaces in output acceptable?

Comment: If my code is 1 byte long, should I output `1 bytes` or `1 byte`? (keep in mind there are already 41 answers, although I don't think any are affected)

Comment: @X1M4L Also, I don't recommend code to be able to self-inspect, this would easily make a generalized quine challenge if not for that.

Comment: Can `bytes` be uppercase?

Comment: @JoKing well I didn’t address casing in the rules, but if somehow using capital letters makes your score lower, then by all means I’d love to see what you came up with. I say go for it!

Comment: @X1M4L i can imagine that in some programming languages (mostly very ancient ones) there are no lowercase characters in a character set. In this case however, it's just to make Brainfuck code more compact which seems fair.

Comment: Can the output be surrounded by quotes?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard im sorry but output is limited to numerical byte count, the word `bytes`, and white-space characters

Comment: As rafa11111 asked earlier: Are leading spaces acceptable?

Comment: @StewieGriffin - I you read the question only trailing whitespaces seems to be allowed.

Comment: Can `bytes` be in any case pattern, e.g. `bYtEs`?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye sure

Answer (score 59):

## JavaScript, 19 bytes

Octal was invented to serve two purposes:

- setting file permissions in Linux
- answering this challenge

```js
alert(023+' bytes')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@Yk1pUomCrkJyfV5yfk6qXk58OEdMwMDLWVldIqixJLVbX/P8fAA)

Comment: Does this count as a full program?

Comment: @ericw31415 This is a _browser program_, [as defined in this meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11932/58563).

Comment: +1 because finally clarifying me why octal is not completely useless!

Comment: +1 for *answering this challenge*

Answer (score 39):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 16 bytes

There are many other ways to get `16` but this one is mine

```perl
say afpbytes^PPP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhMa0gqbIktTguICDg//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DA30DAE)

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing In perl you can leave out the quotes on strings if they looks like a literal and don't conflict with a keyword (and is very much deprecated but we don't care in golf), Binary operators `&` `|` `^` and `~` can also be applied to strings and work on them like on a list of ASCII values (if and only if ***both*** sides are strings). For `|` and `^` it works as if the shorte string is extended with `\0`. After that is a simple exercise to find combinations of letters that xor to the desired output,

Answer (score 36):

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 23 characters, 9 bytes

```
54340045141332401057403
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcEBEQAwDAIxSzCeq39lLLmtBIkaJw9ZPZTtAw)

This is a fairly hard challenge in a language that consists entirely of digits, but I managed it…

This is just 9 bytes in 7's encoding. (Strictly speaking, it's 8⅜ bytes (23 × ⅜ − ¼ because the final two trailing 1 bits can be omitted), but for the first time, PPCG's requirement to round up to a whole number of bytes is actually an advantage because it means that the extra trailing 1 bits are necessary and thus not banned by the question.) A reversible hex dump:

```
00000000: b1c0 2530 b6a0 22f8 1f                   ..%0.."..
```

The main challenge of writing this program in 7 was golfing it to under 10 bytes (as writing 7 without using `0` or `1` is pretty hard.) This uses the same structure as the standard "Hello world" program:

```
54340045141332401057403
5434004514133240105      commands 0-5 append literals to data space
                   7     start a new section of data space
                    403  another literal appended to data space
                         {implicit: eval the last section as commands}
                    4    swap 1st and 2nd sections with an empty section between
                     6   reconstruct the commands that would create the 1st section
                      3  output (+ some other effects we don't care about)
```

In other words, we start by creating two sections of the data space; we have two literals, each of which pushes a sequence of commands there. The second section (they're pushed stack-style so first push = last pop) is a fairly arbitrary sequence of commands but is pushed using the command sequence `5434004514133240105` (thus producing the data sequence **`5434664574733246765`**; when discussing 7 in text, I normally use normal font for a command that pushes a literal, and bold for the corresponding resulting literal). The first section is pushed using the command sequence `403`, producing **`463`**. Then the first section is copied back to the program (an implicit behaviour of 7).

The **`463`** is now composed of (bold) commands that do something immediately, rather than (non-bold) commands that just push literals. **`4`** rearranges the sections to get our "string literal" into the first section. Then **`0`** does the operation that 7 is most known for: taking a section of data space, and reconstructing the command sequence that's most likely to have created it. In the case where the original command sequence was all `0`-`5`, this is 100% accurate (unsurprisingly, as those commands purely push data and thus leave obvious evidence of what they did), and so we get our original sequence `5434004514133240105` back. Finally, **`3`** prints it.

So the remaining thing to look at here is the encoding of the string. This has its own domain-specific language:

```
5434004514133240105
5                    change encoding: 6 bits per character
 43                  select character set: digits and common symbols
   40                '9'
     04              space
       51            select character set: uppercase letters
         4133240105  'B' 'Y' 'T' 'E' 'S'
```

(There's no "select character set: lowercase letters" in the "digits and common symbols" character set – you have to go via a different character set first – so I needed to use uppercase to golf this short enough to fit underneath the effective 10-byte limit.)

Answer (score 22):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
８ bytes＋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjE4JTIwYnl0ZXMldUZGMEI_,v=1)

A more interesting 20 byte solution:

```
bytecount.innerText＃
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=Ynl0ZWNvdW50LmlubmVyVGV4dCV1RkYwMw__,v=1)

Comment: OK, that *is* pretty clever.

Comment: Notice that one of the restrictions is "Your source code can not include any of the digits from your byte count" so the first solution is not valid in this case =)

Comment: @Cyclonecode That "8" there isn't a regular ASCII 8 though - it's a full-width 8 character in this unicode version of the code, though really it's the byte 0xD5, which is completely unrelated to any 8s

Answer (score 14):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 53 BYTES

```
+[[<+>->->++>----<<<]>-]>-.--.<<<+.<.<.-----.>+++.<-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fOzraRttOFwi1gRQQ2NjYxNrpApGerq4ekKOtZwOEIBldPaAaIFdX7/9/AA)

Another submission with capitalised `bytes`. Found with the help of the excellent [BF-crunch](https://github.com/primo-ppcg/BF-Crunch) helper by primo.

Answer (score 12):

## PHP, 14 bytes

```
<?=7*2?> bytes
```

Comment: How about putting the `bytes` part outside the `?>`? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7WXNvc3k4hqbIktfj/fwA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing great 3 less bytes :)

Comment: Just fyi, it's probably best that you split up your answer into multiple answers if you cover more than one language.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>25</s> <s>24</s> 18 bytes

```python
print(6*3,'bytes')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew0zLWEc9qbIktVhd8/9/AA)

Comment: But "4" is in "24".  Maybe "33-9"?

Comment: @recursive `3*8` should be fine, though

Comment: @recursive whoops, fixed it :P

Answer (score 10):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╗↑╞ô╝
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=bb18c693bc&i=&a=1)

Unpacked, it looks like this.  Packed source mode makes this kind of trivial and uninteresting.

```
5p     print 5 with no line break
`5l@   print the compressed string " bytes"
```

If you don't want to use packed source mode, `` 6^p`5l@ `` works for 7 bytes.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, because I think that using packed mode, while a clever way of saving bytes, feels like cheating (which it isn't) at worst, and uncreative at best. Rather than go on a downvote spree of all Stax [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5brestricted-source%5d%20Stax%20is%3aa) answers, I'll leave this downvote to cover all such similar answers.

Comment: I certainly agree that it's uncreative.  But I think the fault lies with the concept of `restricted-source`, not the language.  This is actually the most direct way of producing `"5 bytes"` using Stax.

Answer (score 9):

## [PHP older than 7.2](https://secure.php.net/), 13 bytes

Assumes default settings (E_NOTICE warnings disabled) and PHP version older than 7.2.

Needs to be decoded with `xxd -r`

```
00000000: 3c3f 3d7e cecc df9d 868b 9a8c 3b         <?=~........;
```

Or if you prefer Base64

```
PD89fs7M352Gi5qMOw==
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PymxONXMREE3RcHGxkYhwMXCMq3Y3NfY1Mg907TQ17/c1lahRqEgo@D/fwA)

Answer (score 8):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), <s>477</s> 440 BytEs

```
     ^   ^       ^   ^       ^   ^
    ^-  / \     ^-  / \     ^-  / \
   / \ /out\   / \ /out\   / \ /out\
  /out\-----^ /out\-----^ /out\-----^
 ^-----^   / \-----^   / \-----^   / \
 -^   / \ /chr\   / \ /chr\   / \ /chr\
  -^ /chr\-----^ /chr\-----^ /chr\-----^
  /*\-----^   / \-----^   / \-----^   / \
 ^---^   / \ /66 \   / \ /116\   / \ /115\
/8\ / \ /32 \-----  /121\-----  /69 \-----
---/55 \-----       -----       -----
   -----
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7RCsIwDEXf8xV5FkropEX/JRRkDraHoUx98Otr07VVcIFdCD25TXN7fy@XebqaRz8O8xAjikKpTYZMBpGQUWGZEYturydrnIbyaURBY0g7VzM/1RiwElI/LqxxCpX9gjVrm@V3B94XHb4NkvfYEq31P@wY6MRrd@zKknRrO9vYn4sPqci5NpX1x1Ahxg8)

Outputs `440 BytEs` by multiplying 8 by 55.

Comment: Wouldn't that violate the rule against unnecessary whitespace? Or maybe I don't understand?

Comment: @SteveBennett You're right. I've modified it so that the program doesn't have redundant characters (though it can be golfed pretty easily

Comment: [431 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsSszNTNEtTs5IzU39/18BBOKgGCubC8zSVVDQV4hRwMEGqQEJ6eeXlsTgYgMVgWldEIjDxeYCmgkRBGvFxeZSgLEU9JMzimJwsbkQTJhd2Nlc@ibGhjFEWQ3mKMBssbRQgNtoaGiGxDYFhwsY6BsbQQ0Bsg2NDBFsAygbrhRuOjb2//8A "Pyramid Scheme – Try It Online"), Psll code: `(out (_ 431) " ") (out _ "b") (out _ "y") (out _ "t") (out _ "e") (out _ "s")`

Comment: @MarcinKonowalczyk There's a source restriction on this challenge so that you can't use numbers from the score (in your case 4,3 or 1)

Comment: though i managed to modify the format to work

Comment: @JoKing Aaa, yes. I apparently read straight past it. 

Answer (score 8):

## [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), 6 bytes

```
bytes
```

Uses an unprintable character at the beginning to push 6 to the stack. Then when it gets printed at the end, a space is automatically added after the 6 due to it being an integer.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@fLamyJLX4/38A)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 16 bytes

```r
cat(4*4,"bytes")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRMNEy0RHKamyJLVYSfP/fwA)

Comment: Isn't it 17 because of your missing space?

Comment: @PmanAce "Output should only be the byte count of your program and a trailing `bytes`". The program is 16 bytes.

Comment: `cat` by default adds a space between its inputs.

Comment: `object.size` outputs in the correct format (with `bytes` included by default). Annoyingly, the shortest I could find is 17: `object.size(0)-39`. [TIO](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pz8pKzW5RK84sypVw0BT19jy/38A "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @RobinRyder why is `0` 56 bytes? that's the part that confuses me

Comment: @RobinRyder [Hadley's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) says a zero-length vector takes up 40 bytes, so that's 40, 8 bytes for a 64-bit number, and 8 more bytes which come from...somewhere.

Comment: All the byte counts in that reference are off by 8. On my machine, a zero-length is 48 bytes, not 40. Maybe Hadley's results are outdated?

Comment: Apparently, in Hadley's version, a 1-length vector is of length 48, so there must exist a version of R in which this 16-byte code works: `object.size(0)/3`.

Comment: @RobinRyder there must be! The first edition (which I linked) came out in September 2014 so it's a version 3.1.1 or earlier; the 2nd edition removes that particular section altogether.

Answer (score 6):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
[ bytes]Bnn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z9aIamyJLU41ikv7/9/AA)

-3 bytes by `@Cows quack`

Comment: `[ bytes]Bnn` shaves some bytes

Comment: @Cowsquack thanks!

Comment: @cowsquack duckies go MOO, I'd assume :P?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Ducks, what are ducks? :P

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
₂¤“ÿ¡Ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UVPToSWPGuYc3n9o4eH@//8B)

---

```
₂      # [26]        | Pushes 26 (many other alternatives).
 ¤     # [2, 6]      | Split out tail.
  “ÿ¡Ï # ['6 bytes'] | ÿ = "Interpolate top of stack.", ¡Ï = "bytes" (compressed)
```

---

Alternatives for `₂¤` include: `5>`, `₁¤`, `3·`

Comment: Too bad ***[this](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOc022HOw4tPNz//z8A "05AB1E – Try It Online")*** doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

## Bash, 21 bytes

"Read your own source code" is clearly not the winner here, but no one else submitted one, so what the heck.

```bash
echo `wc -c<$0` bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18hoTxZQTfZRsUgQSGpsiS1@P9/AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>100 BYTES</s> 80 bYTES

```
((((((()()()))[]{})))((({}){})(((({}){}))<([]([](([][][])([{}]()({{}}))))[])>)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fAwI0QVBTMzq2uhZIAQWANBBpwFmaNhrRsSAExCCoqRFdXRsL1FVdXQvSAtSqaQek/v//r@sIAA)

Outputs the `bytes` part in reverse title case. Does away with the `(<>)` abuse to pad the stack height and instead reuses those elements to add up to 83 for the final push, as well as contributing to pushing the `80`  part.

Initially, this pushes `3 8 8 32 32` to the main stack while pushing `8 16 32` to the "third" stack (this is used to produce `80`  (`8+16+32,16+32,32`)). Then inside that we push the `bytes` part inside a `< >`. Here we use the stack height (`5`) to get the differences between the elements (`9 5 15 -14`) before finally summing the stack to produce `83` (`S`).

Comment: [I've finally outgolfed this.  There might be room to get me back.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207216/56656)

Comment: I've managed to get "76 bYTES" down to [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fAwY0NYEoOhYENatrNYFcDY3qWhDLRiM6FoQ0oLIa0dW1sRqaGtXVtSB1QE2adiACqP////@6jgA) but I can't get it any further :(. If anyone can manage to remove that last pair of brackets, feel free to post it as your own answer

Answer (score 6):

## PHP + HTML, 16 bytes

```
&#49;&#54; bytes
```

Yes, this is getting pretty close to loophole abuse, but I felt this needed to be posted.  And the use of PHP means that this answer technically *is* written in a Turing-complete programming language.  Of course, any other similar HTML templating language would work just as well.

Live demo (without PHP):

```html
&#49;&#54; bytes
```

Comment: Beat me to it! And the ; can usually be omitted!

Comment: Ahh but then it would be 14/15 bytes

Answer (score 6):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 112 bytes

Just because nobody's done it yet:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCcAwDAPf0hRarZRA8ysk0PFdyyHxQ5zE4e/ps433uluEJACZIigDPZmAhVX3iiPY2ELGQZHrmU2iOlk1L@IH)

Prints " BYTES" in caps, since uppercase letters have shorter binary ASCII codes.  The commands in the program, in my own made up visible notation, are:

```
Push 112
PrintNum
Push 0
Push 0x53
Push 0x45
Push 0x54
Push 0x59
Push 0x42
Push 0x20
Label _
PrintChr
Dup
JumpZ S
Jump _
Label S
End
```

Comment: Ah, didn't notice there was already a Whitespace answer.. [Here is a shorter one (**104 bytes**).](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZNTgRNIcXFygWkQhvAUYDxOJC5QtQInEhekAlkxJ6osUD2Y@/8/AA). Will delete mine again. [Here is the same with added highlighting and explanation.](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/PzpYAQRDOEM4QSSE58cVH1BanBFvaGASGx3C6ccFkooPKMrMK4kH4tT01KJYuEYIjazN2CgebDpMb7ACVG9yRmJRYnIJNt0gFky/mVm8E3F6Ic4G0TC9FpbxkcTqhdkP12sSH0K8myH64W62jHcl3l6Iy@H2GscH49H7/z8A)

Comment: Oh, hmm. I guess the text is short enough that implementing the loop actually hurts more than just repeating the PrintChar.  (And I know, I can always drop the final NNN, but I really like not having errors.)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
main=putStr$"\50\54 bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIRSnG1CDG1EQhqbIktVjp/38A)

---

#### 29 bytes

```hs
main=putStr$pred<$>"3:!czuft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIpaAoNcVGxU7J2Eoxuao0rUTp/38A)

Comment: Unnecessary whitespace is now forbidden, but you can use a `$` instead.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 22 bytes

```matlab
disp([50 50 ' bytes'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JbO4QCPa1EABiNQVkipLUovVYzX//wcA)

Answer (score 5):

## Applescript, 15 bytes

Yes, I’m going there.

```
9+6&”bytes”
```

Comment: But... `Your source code can not include any of the digits from your byte count`

Comment: @nicael Dang, you’re right. One second then...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `”` a multibyte character (3 bytes in Unicode if I remember correctly), so this is more than 11 bytes?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing ...Shoot. You’re right - “ is 2 bytes, upping this to 15.

Comment: does this not still print 11?

Comment: @DestructibleLemon *Sigh*... Edited. Again.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 15 bytes

```
 bytes
*>w`..+
```

This program counts the number of substrings with at least two characters in the string " bytes", and then prints this count and the string itself.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n0shqbIktZhLy648QU9P@/9/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html), 277 bytes

```
for the A.I. system i did, i tried to put in humans
i know i am one of those
i am trying human testing for cyber-enabled virtual brains
a for-profit company rakes in massive loads of cash educating interns,
& then force-feeding things to all the interns until we earn a diploma
```

Outputs `277 bytes`.

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?LY9BbsMwDATvfsWeeorzhx77DFqiaiISZYhUAr8@kdxeSJC7mMWm2uA74/v@c4ed5lwgiBJvY3kTjvCKoztEsfdCaovgofU1dCqoyqhpIKrxcn28naK/f144m88rjZhwbtxWVtryoD6leaeMrZEMJk3LerSaxBFqOUhPNHqwzeBCZvJk5ErRZl4g28GxB7rwos5N7bZ8zTI6WYHXxByn6vuYNntQzlfbfz@6umS8GExNQaP3kWuh93uj@AE)

Poetic is an esolang I made in 2018 for a class project. It's basically brainfuck with word-lengths instead of symbols.

This was a fun program to write, although I'm not entirely sure I've fulfilled the "no unnecessary characters" requirement. If my answer needs to be amended, let me know!

Comment: "& then force-feeding things to all the interns until we earn a diploma". Absolutely wonderful!

Answer (score 4):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```forth
$d . ." bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//q6Qo6CnoKSkkVZakFv//DwA)

Answer (score 4):

## Java 5 or 6, 44 bytes (full program)

```
enum A{A;{System.out.print(0x2C+" bytes");}}
```

No TIO-link, because Java 5/6 is old.. In Java 5/6 it was possible to have an enum with code instead of the mandatory `main`-method, making it shorter for full program challenges.

Also errors with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main\nException in thread "main"` in STDERR after printing to STDOUT, which is fine [according to the meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/should-submissions-be-allowed-to-exit-with-an-error/4781#4781) (but if the challenge would have disallowed additional errors to STDERR, `System.exit(0);` can be added (and the octal numbers has to be updated) to prevent the error.

Suggested by *@OlivierGrégoire* (and [his relevant Java tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140181/52210)).

## Java 8+, 74 bytes (full program)

```
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(0112+" bytes");}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z8zryS1KC0xOVXBt7q4JLEkM1mhLD8zRSE3MTNPI7ikKDMvPTo2UbM6uLK4JDVXL7@0RK8AKFiiYWBoaKStpJBUWZJarKRpXVv7/z8A)

## Java 8+, <s>16</s> 15 bytes (lambda function)

```java
v->0xF+" bytes"
```

-1 byte thanks to *@OliverGégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY0xC4MwEIX3/oqHU6Qo3aUdu9VF6FI6nDEtsTGKOUOl@NvTiMLdcO8@3teSp6xtPkEacg430vZ3ALRlNb5IKpTrCVQ8avuGFPdeN/BpEdMlbhzHxFqihMUZwWeX0/d6TFDPrFwSig0aptpEaGf9WtJFl9h6H09Quotmx6rL@4nzIb5Y2FwKOxmT7s4l/AE)

Comment: Technically not a full program :)

Comment: @O.O.Balance Oops.. somehow read past that, thanks for the correction. There goes my score.. XD

Comment: `v->3*5+"bytes"`?

Comment: @Neil It contains a `5`, so I'm afraid that's not going to work.

Comment: `37*2` contains a `7`, so it is not valid. Your alternative solution is fine though.

Comment: @O.O.Balance Oops.. not sure how I missed that. Removed it.

Comment: `v->0xE+"bytes"` or `v->0xF+" bytes"`. Can't test but should work anyways. Nothing says the score and "bytes" must be separated.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks. As for whether there need to be a space before bytes, as expected when I looked in the challenge edit it stated `" bytes"`, so the space is mandatory. I edited the challenge description to _<code> bytes</code>_ and also added the rule explicitly to make it more clear the space between the number and `bytes` is mandatory. Thanks for the -1 with the hexadecimal number `0xF` though.

Comment: `enum H{H;{System.out.print(<octal or hex>+" bytes");System.exit(0);}}` for both Java 5 and 6.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I know, I know. ;) When I posted the full program I was doubting to answer it as enum thinking about [your tip-answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140181/52210). Do you know any online compiler that still supports it? I prefer to have a link with test code for my answers..

Comment: Then [I posted it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160850/16236)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Oh, I was just done with my edit, lol.. Still looking for an online compiler for Java 5/6, though.. :(

Comment: Now You use 053 to write 43. That's not allowed. Fixed by switching to hexa, for 1 extra byte.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah oops.. >.> Third time I made that mistake, wth.. I'm glad it's weekend now.. sigh. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```c
main(){printf("%d bytes",040);}
```

There is a trailing newline, which is not "unnecessary" since the C standard demands it. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0k1RSGpsiS1WEnHwMRA07qW6/9/AA).

Thanks to [NieDzejkob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55934/niedzejkob) for golfing 1 byte.

Alternative with the same bytecount, thanks to [ErikF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79060/erikf):

```c
main(){printf("%d bytes",' ');}
```

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0k1RSGpsiS1WElHXUFd07qW6/9/AA).

Comment: `, 040` for 32 bytes

Comment: `, 040` is against the (updated) rules but I added a trailing newline instead of the space. Thank you!

Comment: You could also use `,' '` to avoid any numerals at all!

Comment: @ErikF now that is clever. thanks :)

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0k1RSGpsiS1WElHXV5d07r2/38A)

Comment: @Steadybox nice catch. I prefer the printable character solutions though.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 23 bytes

```matlab
printf('%i bytes',9+14)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/oCgzryRNQ101UyGpsiS1WF3HUtvQRPP/fwA)

And this:

```matlab
disp(['','67$f}xiw'-4])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JbO4QCNaXV1H3cxcJa22IrNcXdckVvP/fwA)

Comment: The first answers seems fine, but... how does the second one works? o.O

Comment: @rafa11111 Subtracting `4` from (the ASCII codes of) `'67$f}xiw'` gives the ASCII codes of `'23 bytes'`. Then, concatenating with the empty string `''`  converts ASCII codes to chars

Comment: @Luis Mendo Pretty clever! Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

Full program which implicitly prints to STDOUT.

```apl
'bytes',⍨3×4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b96UmVJarG6zqPeFcaHp5uABP@nAQA)

`,⍨` is appends the string to the result of the multiplication. APL's default display of mixed-type data puts a space between a number and subsequent text.

Comment: I may be wrong, but don't you have a 2 in your byte count and program?  3*4 should be fine though

Comment: @fyrepenguin Heh, right you are, of course. How silly of me.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
'57$f}xiw'4-c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X93UXCWttiKzXN1EN/n/fwA)

This pushes the string '57$f}xiw' and subtracts `4`, to get `13 bytes`. This is converted to characters using `c`.

Comment: `6EV' bytes'h` is 12 (I was just about to post it)

Comment: although it's the same boring approach :P

Answer (score 4):

## Petit Computer BASIC, 11 bytes

```
?9+2,"bytes
```

Using a comma in a print statement will move the cursor over to the next multiple of the current tab size. In SmileBASIC, that is 4 by default, so this would output `11  bytes` (2 spaces) but PTC BASIC used 3 instead, so the output has the correct spacing.

Answer (score 4):

## [FerNANDo](http://esolangs.org/wiki/FerNANDo), 79 bytes

```
3 3
1
2 2
0 1 3 3 1 2 2 3
0 1 3 3 2 1 0 2
0 1 3 0 0 1 0 1
0 3 3 1 0 0 3 1
1 1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0stykvMS8n//99YwZjLkMtIwYjLQMFQAcgDkkAeUBTGNwLSBnB5AwUDMN8QyIeoBokAaS5DEP7/HwA)

Answer (score 4):

### Hexagony, <s>26</s> 22 Bytes

```
B{3'/bs.<t>;ey;:!$@P0/
```

*-4 Bytes @Jo King*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/19BQcFJoVrBWEGdS0FBXyFJoVhBT8GGS6FEwU7BWiFVoVLBmstKQVFBRcFBIUDBQEGfCygPh0A9yGwY8/9/AA)

---

More Readable:

```
   B { 3 '
  / b s . <
 t > ; e y ;
: ! $ @ P 0 /
 . . . . . .
  . . . . .
   . . . .
```

Reuses every semicolon twice similar to
[this answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/165095#165095)

Comment: It even uses one of the semi-colons *4* times!

Answer (score 4):

## Red, 43 bytes

```
print[to-integer 8.6 * length? b: "bytes"b]
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>20</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```bash
echo $[8+9] bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BJdpC2zJWIamyJLX4/38A)

-2 bytes thanks to @manatwork.
-1 byte thanks to @boboquack.

Comment: `echo $[20-2] bytes` for 18 bytes?

Comment: @manatwork woah, I didn't know bash could do math like that

Comment: “The  old  format  $[expression]  is  deprecated  and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash.” — `man bash`. But in meantime we enjoy using it here in PPCG.

Comment: `echo $[5#33] bytes` also works for a score of 18.

Comment: Doesn’t 8+9 work for 17?

Comment: @boboquack Yes, it does. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

### ><>, 13 bytes

```
#o<" bytes"nd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XznfRkkhqbIktVgpL@X/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
x=>0xf+' bytes'
```

Comment: `_=>5*3+' bytes'`

Comment: @Neil Both the code and the byte-count contains a `5` in that case..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Bah, I can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: Submissions are required to be full programs "**write a full program** to output its own code golf score!"

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 32 bytes

```
@@echo %COMSPEC:~-10,-010% bytes
```

`COMSPEC` is usually `%WINDIR%\system32\cmd.exe` so I extract the substring from 10 to 8 characters from the end. Old 16-byte self-referencing version:

```
@echo %~z0 bytes
```

Fortunately the byte count wasn't a multiple of 10.

Comment: @manatwork OK, I hadn't seen that, here's a new version.

Answer (score 3):

### 7Zip - <s>90</s> 14 bytes

Hex dump:

```
00 75 0d 08 c0 00 0d 08 03 00 00 03 04 1d
```

To use:

save into a source file, named anything.

run the compiler from the command line: `7z e [source name]`

Answer (score 3):

## Excel VBA, 10 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the vbe immediate window.

```vb
?2*5"bytes
```

#### Output

```
10 bytes
```

Comment: My Excel shows additional leading space. Is it allowed?

Comment: @pajonk That is the default nature VBA's `Print` and `?` statement when handling number types, and is generally accepted to be valid for PPCG. That said, it may the space may be forcefully removed by converting to a string, and then operating upon that string, such as `?6+7&&" bytes` for 13 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [C++ (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 51 bytes

*Thanks to @ceilingcat!*

```
#import<iostream>
main(){std::cout<<063<<" bytes";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkztyC/qMQmM7@4pCg1MdeOKzcxM09Ds7q4JMXKKjm/tMTGxsDM2MZGSSGpsiS1WMm69v9/AA)

## [C++ (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56 bytes

```cpp
#import<iostream>
main(){std::cout<<(int)'8'<<" bytes";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkztyC/qMQmM7@4pCg1MdeOKzcxM09Ds7q4JMXKKjm/tMTGRiMzr0RT3ULdxkZJIamyJLVYybr2/38A)

**More portable version (60 bytes):**

```cpp
#import<iostream>
int main(){std::cout<<(int)'<'<<" bytes";}
```

`#import` is not standard C++, but should work at least with GCC, Clang, and MSVC.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//9fOTO3IL@oxCYzv7ikKDUx144rM69EITcxM09Ds7q4JMXKKjm/tMTGRgMorKluo25jo6SQVFmSWqxkXfv/PwA)

**Standard compliant version (61 bytes):**

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main(){std::cout<<(int)'='<<" bytes";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//9fOTMvOac0JdUmM7@4pCg1MdeOKzOvRCE3MTNPQ7O6uCTFyio5v7TExkYDKKypbqtuY6OkkFRZklqsZF37/z8A)

Comment: Suggest `063` for `(int)'8'`, `067` for `(int)'<'` and `070` for `(int)'='`

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE with OS 5.2+), 14 bytes

```
toString(9+5)+" BYTES
```

`toString(` is a [two-byte token](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/time-tokens), all other characters used are [one-byte tokens](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens).

`toString(` can be replaced with `eval(` for the same output and score.

Explanation:

- `toString(9+5)` Returns the string `"14"`
- `+" BYTES` Adds the string  `" BYTES"`, to get `"14 BYTES"`
- TI-Basic implicitly returns/prints the last item evaluated, so `13 BYTES` is output.

Comment: What calculator has a `toString(` function?

Comment: @kamoroso94 The TI-84 Plus CE. [Source](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tostring)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jstx](https://github.com/Quantum64/Jstx), 4 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/codepage)

```
♦─]P
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.2/JstxGWT.html?code=4pmm4pSAXVA%3D)

Answer (score 3):

## m4, 15 bytes

As in the m4 POSIX macro processor.

```
eval(8+7) bytes
```

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, <strike>12</strike> 10 bytes

```
i9<C-o><C-a> bytes
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica frontend, 18 bytes (maybe 10?)

```
Row@{2*9," bytes"}
```

Thanks to @ovs

### A naughty way ... as I don't know whether this counts (10)

```
2" bytes"5
```

Well it depends on how you define *space*.

[image]

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), solution w/o frontend (30)

```
Print[ToString[5*6]<>" bytes"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJDokP7gEyEiPNtUyi7WxU1JIqixJLVaK/f8fAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 9 bytes

```
G½ "bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/90F4FpaTKktTi//8B)

### Explanation

Quite simple really

```
G            Push 18
 ½           Halve the result, giving 9
             Push a space character
   "bytes    Push "bytes"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 18 bytes

```
print(9*2,'bytes')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew1LLSEc9qbIktVhd8/9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 17 bytes

```
print 9+8,'bytes'
```

Output: `17 bytes`

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Mono C# Shell)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/repl/), 27 bytes

```cs
Console.Write(3*9+" bytes")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7Wzc3Py9ctzkjNyfn/3zk/rzg/J1UvvCizJFXDWMtSW0khqbIktVhJ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-Mfeature+say`, 14 bytes

Relies on a generated program, so TIO link is to Bash which generates the program from `xxd` output. Uses `-Mfeature+say` instead of `-M5.10.0` although I don't think it matters that much...

```perl
say~"ÎËß"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxBCsIwFATQfU8xdNOFpGiEprHBG3iI5OeXCgVDErFuvHoU7CJvNzMwzqalbJuHiDDGoDvuLlDn4QSlFUNKYpDzM7QfB4xOW4wkJf5Ksu9P2@/a0uGKRPEech/WqSGb68i0PKbmRRBU14HjCnGb2eZn5MPvslrLFw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 90 bYTES

```
((((((<>))))[])[]([]((((([][][]))))([{}]()([]({}{}){}{}<>)))))(([][])[()]((([]{}))({}{})))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fAwxs7DSBIDoWiDSACASiY0EQJKwRXV0bq6EJkqiura7VBBEQDZoQZZrRGpqxYC1AWU2IIk3N////6zoCAA)

It took a while but I got us down to double digits.

I stole a technique of pushing a bunch of zeros in order to abuse `[]` from [JoKing's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160761/56656).  However I have modified it a bit.

Instead of pushing zeros I just push whatever is convenient (which does happen to include zeros). This is ok since JoKing gets rid of them with a loop that doesn't pick up zeros (which is reversing the stack), I use `<>` to switch to the other stack.

Other than that shared trick out answers are quite divergent.

Comment: [88 bYTES](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fAwxs7DSBIDoWiDSACASiY0EQJKwRXV0bq6EJkqiura7VBBEQDZoIhRpg/UBVYCWamv///9d1BAA) is a little easier to generate by modifying the end slightly

Comment: [Back at you](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160761/76162) ;). I'm pretty sure 77 or 76 bYTES is possible though, but I've only got that down to 80 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

```
n)" bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/P09TSSGpsiS1WOn/fwA)

`n` is a variable that represents `\n`, `)` separates the last char from `n` and parses it to an integer. The ascii value of `\n` is 10.

Answer (score 3):

## [Templates Considered Harmful](https://github.com/feresum/tmp-lang), 30 bytes

```
St<51,48,' ','B',89,84,69,'S'>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nNLchJLEkt/v8/uMTG1FDHxEJHXUFdR91JXcfCUsfCRMfMUkc9WN3u/38A)

This should be the best possible score. Every character here can be represented by a 2 byte ascii (ex. 66) value, or a 3 byte char literal (ex. 'B'). 28 is the theoretical minimum representing every character as ascii, but it is blocked by space being value 32. 29 is also blocked by Y and E. 30 works.

Answer (score 3):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 32 bytes

```
*+}*!*1!**/*1*1++*{*1*1!}*}*1+1+*+1**+1!***+{*{+***+1*1!***+!*/
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIqK30qISoxISoqLyoxKjErKyp7KjEqMSF9Kn0qMSsxKyorMSoqKzEhKioqK3sqeysqKiorMSoxISoqKishKi8iLCJbMzNdIiwxXQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ṡ`, <s>7</s> 6 bytes

<sup>-1 bytes thanks to Bubbler</sup>

```
kṄt`¨ƈ
```

### Explanation

```
kṄ                - Push "4096"
  t               - Get the final item (6)
   `¨ƈ            - Push "bytes"
<flag>            - Join by spaces ("6 bytes")
<implicit>        - Print it.
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%A1&code=k%E1%B9%84t%60%C2%A8%C6%88&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: Can't test at the moment, but would it work if you use a numeric constant ending with 6 (e.g. `kṄ` = 4096) and omit the trailing backtick? (...or just use a different number from the length and increment to get the byte count?)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
+T" bytes"
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BT%22%20bytes%22&debug=0)

If you don't mind separating with a newline instead of a space, you can get it down to 8 bytes with

```
y4"bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
“¢>¶ŒD»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDi@wObTs6yeXQ7v//AQ)

Compressed strings.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>10</s> 10 bytes

```
Ao" bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/3zFfSSGpsiS1WOn/fwA)

Comment: +1 for the no-op space used just to pad the byte count. Too bad CJam doesn't have a predefined variable with the initial value 9.

Comment: ...although I just realized that the challenge forbids "[u]nnecessary spaces and newlines". But you could still do e.g. ``" bytes"A\`` or `A" bytes"+` to comply with the rules as specified.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen `Ao" bytes"` works.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
6EV' bytes'h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38w1TF0hqbIktVg94/9/AA)

Pushes `6`, doubles with `E`, converts that to a string with `V`, and `h`orzcats it with the string `' bytes'` to get the proper spacing. Implicit output takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
echo' bytes',~":_bj
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19dIamyJLVYXadOySo@Kev/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 65 bytes

```cs
class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write(0x41+" bytes");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/PzknsbhYIaC6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0XBNzEzT0OzOriyuCQ1V885P684PydVL7wosyRVw6DCxFBbSSGpsiS1WEnTurb2/38A)

Comment: I'm afraid your code contains a `5`.. Easily fixed by using `72-7`, though.

Comment: Fixed! With a little bit of hex to make it look clever! =D

Comment: A bit silly and crooked: class Q{static void Main(){new System.Exception("sixty four");}} => 64 and the word bytes is in the exception when you drill down through it!

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 27 bytes

```
	OUTPUT =3 * 9 ' bytes'
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NCQgNETB1lhBS8FSQV0hqbIktVidy9XP5f9/AA)

prints with a trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
#+` ßs
```

char-code 8 concatenated with " bytes" compressed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/X5lDO0Hh8Hyp4v//AQ)

Comment: Identical to what I had, again. `2³` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

### Excel (Immediate Window), 12 bytes

```
?3*4&"bytes"
```

This solution assumes that leading space is allowed.
Below the one without leading space in output (14 bytes):

```
?2*7&&" bytes"
```

It's the result of suspicious behaviour of the concatenate operator `&`. When only one, it surrounds the number with spaces; however two consecutive ones strip the spaces. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 14 bytes

```powershell
"$(2*7) bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lFw0jLXFMhqbIktVjp/38A)

Ho-hum. Uses an inline code block `$(...)` to put `14` into the string before leaving it on the pipeline. Output is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
puts"#{6*3} bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhJudpMy7hWIamyJLVY6f9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 95 bytes

```
+[--------->+<]>.----.--[--->++<]>--.[->+++<]>++.[--->+<]>+++.-----.+++[->+++<]>.[--->+<]>----.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1oXBuy0bWLt9EAsIBENFgCJALnRICaIra2tFw1TCRQBK9bVA7LgKhDyYKn//wE)

97 bytes:

```
>-[++>+[+<]>]>+.--.>++++[->++++++++<]>.[->+++<]>++.[--->+<]>+++.-----.+++[->+++<]>.[--->+<]>----.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 11 bytes

```
bn"setyb "H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/PylPqTi1pDJJQcnj/38A)

#### How it works

```
bn"setyb "H
b            push number 11
 n           pop and print as integer
  "setyb "   push " bytes" in reverse order
          H  print the stack content as chars, then halt
```

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 12 bytes

An anonymous worksheet function that takes no input and outputs to the calling cell

```
=3*4&" bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

## MSSQL, <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
print str(8*3) +' bytes'
```

Answer (score 2):

## F#, <del>24</del> 23 bytes

I hope this counts. Never code golfed before

```
printfn "%i bytes" 0x17
```

Just switched <del>24 to octal</del> 23 to hex

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/v6AoM68kLU9BSTVTIamyJLVYScGgwtD8/38A)

Comment: Welcome to the site! It looks like you have some extraneous whitespace. Could that be removed? Also, I don't know a whole lot about F#, but are you sure this is a full program? The original rules stated `write a full program to output it's own score`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem whoops, dropped that extra space. Also I do believe this is a full program. It compiles and runs just fine in Visual Studio without anything else, though I may misunderstand what that means.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I assumed that F# was like C# where you need class declarations in a full program. Looks valid to me!

Comment: You can remove tre space before and after the string literal and replace `0x17` with `0x15` to get 21 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/v6AoM68kLU9JNVMhqbIktVjJoMLQ9P9/AA "F# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
+sD4¨₆Ẏ¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X7vYxeTQikdNbQ939R3a//8/AA)

#### Explanation

```
+sD4¨₆Ẏ¿
    ¨₆Ẏ¿  Compressed string of " bytes"
  D4        Multiply 4 by 2
 s          Convert to string
+         Concatenate the strings
```

Answer (score 2):

### Windows Command Line, 20 bytes

```
set/a4*5&echo  bytes
```

Run Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe), type the command and hit Enter.

[image: img]

Answer (score 2):

## SQL, 18 bytes

```
SELECT 2*9,'bytes'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

<sup>*Saved 1 byte thanks to Jo King.*</sup>

```swift
print(9*2,"bytes")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f@/oCgzr0TDUstIRympsiS1WEnz/38A)

Comment: Why not `9*2`?-

Comment: @JoKing What an oversight... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### ArnoldC, 216 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5NCsIwEIX3PcXDTS@gB0jtsxk0SUmmlS5FN4IoeH@ISUE3zmZ4P/Mxl/fz9bhdcxZtE5INZxXHBrBcsLdRkjqToJHEvdhLmJComBKmEdviDEVpgFqWfhhHxrVYxzISkuAWiJ9FjUrwv7Sg2pIfJLLHrqLowzRYqDkdi6rrS7bG9@vhn7npFmXaNPUxa2aiIz2U0Yk3yj7nDw)

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
    HEY CHRISTMAS TREE i
    YOU SET US UP 4
    GET TO THE CHOPPER i
        HERE IS MY INVITATION i
        YOU'RE FIRED 54
    ENOUGH TALK
    TALK TO THE HAND i
    TALK TO THE HAND "BYTES"
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

**Output**

```
216
BYTES
```

Well, i took too long with my **php** answer, i had to try this.

As far as i read, i can't write without a line break or concatenate an integer with a string :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 11 bytes

```
"" sbbeOytH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/19JSaE4KSnVv7LE4/9/AA)

Non-linear pointer progression makes for weird looking programs. Outputs `11 bytes`.

The orde: of commands is such:

```
"  s  e  t      Start string literal to push letters
                Bounce and go left
     b  y       Finish pushing " bytes"
                Bounce and go right
 "  b  O  H   Push 11 to print and then halt and output the stack
```

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <s>68</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write(8*8+" bytes");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/PzknsbhYIaC6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0XBNzEzT0OzOriyuCQ1V885P684PydVL7wosyRVw0LLQltJIamyJLVYSdO6tvb/fwA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Your program contains the digits `5` and `6` which you are printing, that's not allowed.

Comment: Fixed the program and thanks for the review @ØrjanJohansen

Answer (score 2):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 14 bytes

<strike>Technically non-competing, as I made the language after this challenge was posted.</strike>

```
2c7xo" bytes"p
```

Pretty simple. Multiplies 2 and 7.

Comment: You're good as [that rule has fallen to the wayside](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges)

Comment: Ah. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 10 bytes

```
` ā`XESa@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z9B4UhjQoRrcKLD//8A)

Huh, I thumbed this one up and never answered it.

`ā` encodes the value 257 (still shorter than any other method) which gets multiplied by 10 and converted to a word via a dictionary. `2570` happens to be `bytes`. `a` encodes `10` (`b`-`f` encode `11` through `15`) and gets around the "no digits" restriction. And conveniently enough, the rest of the program is 9 bytes.

Doesn't end up being shorter than `" bytes"a@` (also 10 bytes), but oh well.

Answer (score 2):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `d`, 7 bytes

```
♣êæ█☺₧K
```

### Explanation

Unpacked:

```
7 bytes"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 10 bytes

```
°' Bytes'.
```

## Explination

```
°           # Push 10 to the stack
 ' Bytes'   # Push the literal string " Bytes" to the stack
         .  # Concatenate. Implicit print.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///QBnUFp8qS1GJ1vf//AQ)

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, 15 bytes

`j=>0xf+' bytes'`

Seems like the obvious answer.

Alternative:

`j=>9+6+' bytes'`

Answer (score 2):

## [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 12 bytes

```
6 6+" bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/30zBTFtJIamyJLVY6f9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [RAMDISP, <s>133</s> 26 bytes](https://github.com/Oderjunkie/RAMDISP)

<s>There's room for improvement.</s>

```
[P[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]][*[[[[]]]]][+[[[]]]][S[; bytes]]]]
```

i honestly don't even remember how i did this, i attached a debugger, and found it it calculates 3 * 37 + 2.

```
[P[5[*5][+1][S[; bytes]]]]
```

26 = 5*5+1

Answer (score 2):

## PICO-8, 25 bytes

```
print(ord("」").." bytes")
```

`ord()` gets the index of a character, and `」` is character 25 in [P8SCII](https://pico-8.fandom.com/wiki/P8SCII).

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
main=putStr$show(0x1D+5)++" bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIpTgjv1zDoMLQRdtUU1tbSSGpsiS1WOn/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 13 bytes

```
dn'setyb '>o<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PyVPvTi1pDJJQd0u3@b/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ṡ`, 5 bytes

```
4›`¨∞
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaEiLCIiLCI04oC6YMKo4oieIiwiIiwiIl0=)

### Explanation :

```
4     # push 4
 ›    # increment
  `¨∞ # push "Bytes"
      # flag `ṡ` => join with space
      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## dc, 14 bytes

```
7d+n[ bytes]p
```

Double it

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```python
print 8+9,'bytes'
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Wondercricket*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwULbUkc9qbIktVj9/38A)

Comment: That trailing space is not in the *output*, I think it's still precisely what the rule is intended to forbid. However, you can use parentheses around `2*9` instead.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I changed it to `8+9` instead to save a byte. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
┌`m39Σ³‘
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyNTBDJTYwbTM5JXUwM0EzJUIzJXUyMDE4,v=0.12)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 18 bytes

```
print(2*9" bytes")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/v6AoM69Ew0jLUkkhqbIktVhJ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 12 bytes

```
?3*4;" bytes
```

(Probably works in a bunch of other BASIC dialects, too)

Alternatives:

```
?&HC;" bytes
?9+3;" bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jamal](http://verhas.com/peter/progs/perl/jamal/), 14 characters

```
{@* 2 7} bytes
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ perl jamal.pl ownsize.jam 
14 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 24 bytes

```
PRINT*,11+13,'BYTES'
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8PCPL0C9HSMTTUNjTWUXeKDHENVudy9XP5/x8A)

Outputs "24 BYTES" with some leading spaces, because, you know, it's Fortran... you can't tell him to do something and expect that he will do exactly as you said, specially if it involves strings :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 12 bytes

```
"c.4k,@setyb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/XylZzyRbx6E4taQy6f9/AA)

Thank you Jo King and Mistah Figgins for -3 bytes.

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X6k4taQySSlFzyRbx@H/fwA "Befunge-98 (FBBI) – Try It Online")

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/XylZzyRbx6E4taQy6f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## TeX, 16 bytes

```tex
^^q^^v bytes\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 15 bytes

```ruby
p"#{0xf} bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BJudqgIq1WIamyJLVY6f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 13 bytes

```
&9+4$i" bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fzVLbRCVTSSGpsiS1@P9/AA)

### Explanation

```
&9+4$i" bytes
&9              push 9
  +4            add 4 (13)
    $i          output as integer
      " bytes   print out " bytes"
```

### 14 bytes

```
@20&$h" bytes"
```

Same general idea, but (ab)uses hexadecimal printing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
+hT" bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XzsjREkhqbIktVjp/38A)

Comment: Why do you have `h`?  Doesn't that just add the eleventh byte that it's there to account for, and it can thus be removed safely?

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```
fn main(){print!("{} bytes",17*2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDqbpWIamyJLVYScfQXMtIs/b/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 20 bytes

```cs
Write(11+9+" bytes")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/vCizJFXD0FDbUltJIamyJLVYSfP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 13 bytes

```
=6+7&" bytes"
```

Output: `13 bytes`

Nothing fancy. It's different from the other Excel answers as those are both based in VBA. This formula version is longer.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>50</strike> <strike>49</strike> <strike>46</strike> 28 bytes

```
m(){printf("%i bytes",' ');}
```

we need to tell the linker about our custom entry point and make sure stdio.h is included:

```
cc -o x x.c -e _m -include stdio.h
```

Notice, that the character in the printf statement is should not be a space but the ascii character for 28 (FS) in decimal.
I am not able to edit the answer and add this.

Answer (score 1):

## [T-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference), 32 bytes

```
print char(51)+char(50)+' bytes'
```

Best I could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript,26 bytes

```
console.log(78/3+" bytes")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP13D3ELfWFtJIamyJLVYSfP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 42 bytes

I figured I'd try a more interesting approach that's Octave-specific (and only works on some platforms).

```matlab
printf('%i bytes',printf('%c',8+~(10:51)))
```

Note: This doesn't work on TIO or Octave-online.net, but it does work on Octave 4.2.0 on my laptop.

#### Explanation:

`printf('%i bytes',... )` specifies that we will print a string starting with an integer `%i` followed by the characters `' bytes'`. The second part of the first `printf`-function call is another call to `printf('%c',...)`. When `printf` is called with an output argument, it returns the number of characters in the output string, as well as the string. The second part of the second `printf` call is `8+~(10:51)`. This is a shorter way to write `[8, 8, 8 ...]` 42 times. **8** is the ASCII-value of the backspace. The string to be printed is therefore 42 backspaces. This doesn't show when typing it in the terminal, so we'll get `42 bytes` without a trailing newline:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## MySQL, 28 bytes

```
SELECT CONCAT(7*4,' bytes');
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 23 bytes

```
puts [scan  %c]\ bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCG6ODkxT0FcQTU5NkYhqbIktfj/fwA)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 23 bytes

```
puts [expr 19+4]\ bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6taKgSMHQUtskNkYhqbIktfj/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```ruby
p "#{9+7} bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBSbnaUtu8ViGpsiS1WOn/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 19 bytes

```
Print&$bytes!STN!$t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM69ETSWpsiS1WDE4xE9RpeT/fwA)

### Explanation

```
Print&$bytes!STN!$t
Print       !          print
     &$bytes           (with "bytes" as a right argument)
             STN!      convert string to number...
                 $t    "t" (corresponds to 19)
```

In sane syntax, this is: `Print[STN["t"], "bytes"]`, which joins the arguments by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 74 bytes

```
rEeEeeEeEereEEreeeEeeeeereeEEeeeEereeEEEEeeEreeEEEeEeereeEEeeEeEreeEEEeeEE
```

[Try it online!](//soaku.github.io/Pepe/#!asMU8XwZ6YwY2Yu)

It's a boring answer, `rEeEeeEeEereEE` pushes 74 into stack r and outputs the number, and the rest of the code prints `bytes`

Answer (score 1):

## Python (REPL), 16 bytes

```python
'%d bytes'%(8*2)
```

#### Output :

```
16 bytes
```

Comment: You could use f-strings like `f'{7*2} bytes'`

Comment: Or, if you insist on using an older version of Python, you could use raw string `r'%d bytes'%14`

Answer (score 1):

## vim, 12 bytes

```
a9 bytes<ESC>03<C-A>
```

`<ESC>` is 0x1b. `<C-A>` is 0x01

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9FSIamyJLVY2sCY8f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 17 bytes

```
6 PRINT 8+9"bytes
```

MBASIC requires line numbers; "6" doesn't appear in the output either.
Turns out that the trailing quote is optional.

Output:

```
RUN
 17 bytes
Ok
```

Comment: Byte count is calculated from the source code, not the RAM it takes up. So this should be 18 bytes.  But +1 for using an uncommon language; we need more variety around here.

Comment: Even with a tokenizing interpreter?

Comment: Yes.  If the size of the target language/object code/internal representation mattered, the score would change every time improvements were made to the implementation's optimizer.  And there would be a lot of situations where making the source code larger would make the target code smaller, and vice versa, since optimizers work better when they have a lot of explicit information about what assumptions are safe to make.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 23 bytes

```
@"!w"SETYB"uUo<S;O'$.;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/99BSbFcKdg1JNJJqTQ03ybY2l9cXUXP@v9/AA)

Cubified:

```
    @ "
    ! w
" S E T Y B " u
U o < S ; O  '
    $ .
    ; .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIEAgIgogICAgISB3CiIgUyBFIFQgWSBCICIgdQpVIG8gPCBTIDsgTyAXICcKICAgICQgLgogICAgOyAuCg==&input=&speed=20)

Failrly simple pushes SETYB onto the stack, pushes character 23 (ETB) and outputs as an integer.  Push 32 (space) onto the stack then start outputting chars and popping  until stack is empty.

Answer (score 1):

## LOLCODE, 66 bytes

Just because it's funny

```
HAI 1.2,VISIBLE SMOOSH PRODUKT OF 2 AN 33 AN " bytes" MKAY,KTHXBYE
```

### Output

`66 bytes`

Comment: +1 because it's funny

Answer (score 1):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 29 bytes

```pascal
begin write($1D,' bytes')end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/Pyk1PTNPobwosyRVQ8XQRUddIamyJLVYXTM1L0Xv/38A)

`$1D` is a hexadecimal constant. I'm glad Pascal has something shorter than other languages!

Answer (score 1):

## [k (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 16 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0PFykTLRFNHSSGpsiS1WOn/fwA)

```
($:4*4)," bytes"
```

String result of 4*4 and concatenate

Answer (score 1):

## Chevron, 12 bytes

```
^n<<3*4
>^n
```

This is a fairly new language of my own creation - prototype interpreter, documentation, and example programs can be found at https://github.com/superloach/chevron.

### Explanation:

- `^n<<3*4` - calculate 3*4, store as n
- `>^n` - output n
- nothing else - implicit exit

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 59 bytes

```
iisioiiiioii{ii}icii{iii}iic{ii}iiicdddddc{d}dddddc{i}iiiic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYgxDgAgCANf5KMMaLzJgZH4dkRih961OrpObLUIMDaZLIeDFFOQ2kl9EdfzpV4k4gI)

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 52 bytes

```
[]{std::string a="41 bytes";a[0]++;a[1]++;return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#cpp-clang)

*facepalm* is it even competable? it just barely wins against BF! but still, no 5s and 2s in the code.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 31 bytes

```c
main(){printf("%d bytes",'');}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0k1RSGpsiS1WElHXV5d07r2/38A)

The unprintable character is the *unit separator* which value is 31.

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), <s>48</s> 44 bytes

```
2a2a2o2s2m8m1o2m2a1o9a9a5a1o5s1o9s6s1o9a5a1o
```

**Explanation**

```
2a2a2o   # Output "4" twice
2s2m8m1o # Output a space
2m2a1o   # Output "B"
9a9a5a1o # Output "Y"
5s1o     # Output "T"
9s6s1o   # Output "E"
9a5a1o   # Output "S"
```

Original 48-byte solution: `2a2a1o2a2a1o2m2m1o3m2a1o9a9a5a1o5s1o9s6s1o9a5a1o`

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 16 bytes

```sh
<<<$[8*2]\ bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGJdpCyyg2RiGpsiS1@P9/AA)

[Heavily inspired by the Bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160654/86147). `<<<` usually saves two bytes, but we lose one to escape a space.

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 ASM, IBM PC DOS, <del>36</del> 29 bytes

**Listing:**

```
        START: 
B0 1D       MOV  AL, SZ         ; get program size 
D4 0A       AAM                 ; BCD convert byte (AH=ones, AL=tens) 
86 E0       XCHG AH, AL         ; endian convert (AH=tens, AL=ones) 
50          PUSH AX             ; save AH = 9 
3030        ADD  AX, '00'       ; ASCII convert 
BF 0114     MOV  DI, OFFSET S   ; output string in DI 
8B D7       MOV  DX, DI         ; and output string in DX 
AB          STOSW               ; write digits to beginning of string 
58          POP  AX             ; restore AH = 9 (DOS write string function) 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; write to console 
C3          RET                 ; return to DOS
        S   DB '   bytes$'      ; output string buffer
        SZ  EQU LOW $-START     ; subtract starting address from ending address
```

Calculates the difference between the `START` memory address and the ending memory address.  Then writes that value as decimal ASCII followed by the string ' bytes'.

There are no `0x02`, `0x09`, ASCII `'2'` (`0x32`) or ASCII `'9'` (`0x39`) in the code.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), 13 bytes

```
" bytes"94suo
```

Explanation:

```
" bytes"      (push the string)
        94s   (push 13 by adding)
           uo (print twice)
```

Alternative (also 13 bytes):

```
" bytes"{D}uo (D == 13 base 36)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 11 bytes.

- Filename: `.n bytes.p`

  - Escaped: `\013.n bytes.p`
- Content: empty.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhrW9pI93t/xTALZIYkJEGsyDC6irbLrlJX3a4VqE8koURDAiQoFOhf756ZhIu2z/O@ux8kM3POnPttdOyo//0XZJb3d8u9nW7FdiqVvbeOae/v71XKzn7Zvnf29irO24pt7u87b35Bw6k78Iql4sALisMw8qZeNHgTuTHS3QmbDOzoEZlmqcTc6TAcx@isfnd0dsbrjMSzoYu@uHE3DHr5vNx1w8HADhx6YDjukxFMfB@VDvJWPp9evji6/o3jLEnxkD5cEZAgmp2Lj1pdJgt9iVds/2o2bu6urk94yTR3VocXH64aN2ef7uofLi9P69fcYi2kBwhn58dHV7/dfTy9vGp8aFaBDOrk83MktQqR1JKJjXrMlus7tz@74g4mvh27KOqLC@EwhtVzOHaioe/FzPY9O0L6F6Rk55aKs7/ipcIV8VVY86@zs/r5Ca9KFqC0YOiwqO/1YsncQQIxPXC7/RBlf6EYcWShzmJBMsh9sn2EM6hn@5GLaT5PJFbUd8GucRii0HfQQb7EMqhKEx4SYbqIXAcpkTE1ZgaL4OeroUjKXyXlhAqgpDTWJEA9/4nv7zPwz9DzXUJJj5usa0cuELcw8gJEegWKemBq5kZ2l9lR5A7u/ZnwaggOPQqQ/hRPrEU8Rno9QqZV2invvt2r7COl1Q4KHWXxZewOUXFhPz8i5fj0faM5B4uR4dgL4h5Shhfhh6DpNe669ejq6WPvnXs6vnz@e3oz@/T11j6KrwfnzomqZ7K5nLL4DxyzJsf1FkZZE@EOb2MMVvDDZ3dMokQEgnNdrGVNShFuY4YZmE6R7iYYa1carmLKfDCLw8tv2XJ@1fJVtcOzJvN6xD/gpXwejvRSh3Mnnwc2YLQ6nfs6L7EzQpnkguqtrNlhy@Vp82QuTpe9SdCNvTBAsJsLSnSeyIN9zJ77whs@TU8QRlctXfc7KbEbIKRI9fQnFIIrpCPxyrzJbUg03wvcA5POA5Ubrefp7GvH0A3bEIIHNTNliIs2Oi6jYoKAF7hrx8iCGBG56MGSLSUeaEYSKnbHOMToV5AqUIFcFYOBgGQo9TAcI5/PBFTelTaCEzqf8EC3Ur2Cg4lETSWs8Y0oiRDo2QhR0f6pLK91SYTDdioPYCyXQr9/QTIVdQmOZ2lY5qJ2WxSJVbjjBWmhxMxI92NUEtUCKC1WXrC5KT4ROAP8Bas@HChRAUw2DINu9DSOO0aB2DWLqkZLhXDWk32Jgn/cacyWxtCYAxkWQbIto5rF4C8F9WHVB8Vjo5DJ2BCEEc8YrZ6beoPZwijeXcdQDR@oNt/pwIbY4HsQoAuGaoVBBALAYV8cGgNDB7AFq5UsbGlB5L9Sc@eFmsr8ouWppoz9IRdrVbcgqIeZbxC0Ky18Q6CJfBiid1comtxH8ZhkTW2HsguIYq/DIX6tGmnyJMuGmq29u6JQ70DUOeATnMVwguxWs6MltChzXN@FupxQYMtmbQfwI8ErJblepHJEKS3U@ow6KlC8WdPaiNE8gPQlwghgAiiVRiub60AAC9YF@AH9wD9TLvZsxpMTEdTT2oxOVT7TyYxPIcm5SNteOCYPkPYPNUBjdJhYwG49QMFg20aBGCNGWzUOp@qsCu45nOrwzcC3AN8cfHOzKlTzH9QW5SPhYgIXjyUVAsCSBUTwqhVAOhQLWcNYF0N5bnz2EZjFMESbEHYpGBckT5nxBfbIgM89dC8Zst4dBG3PHceDDpjSyEPNMljMVrkHR0kyA4DOJcQWh0u5dMRSVHnRpHppj4OpQDQiRaQbMamyWCR7B0iP3XgyDkTlTbiogoDtOCuuuthH9/FqnxF7aNWrfTsrDhzvaXWQkwjhikBkFAvG39fvCM5DsQKrvJJs3Y6SCnrVeuQQ55CLqz7QT/qAAs0xXhUJRdh7sb66ruguOabzR1VlQKbD4UfEjPDaMVA8rolTdqyqFBbacYoAi1fEhejAgMo@5yCoR5RBFkbdsTeMeSooRGLkus43XMQ0GsOIJbfb7eWCnFChj/YHoR1@ImUC0TYIp9B/EvNn/njRmH5fAxAADqwt0B8bkNRmA7l@ARFMZYlYw2/IJZ1fckCTkuh66np0uYU0IfW0fBPdqtXz@XqttPuWHtah1WyhvRe0wAKT4JtRNATZScAmAQekDdF0te6Gh1mzqm/r8pdgBrfqW2dH5HzVP46qWDvf7hrJcWbTPta3hqB7khQZMCqdkBv43YKHSaf/OTAgDW2knWj@Bmc@4oAEs4fvBl/iPhlRGUUN6A@NGvdZA2JoQsgJT2vsSGtoFqXfcMvU9zv48EQtV6rlXeCyYeOBDBfk/Uved@Rcq2u32ic6P@e4eFdFzTAWRcr94o4xq3PAZ7fAVrBnTEpY3kscs1uh92PXfhRFsf4Nfy63dnY7WUznt7xc1uvp5QRFNGZSSe5ZZWhGdc53RANMkOBdEHvBxGVLYf8Eu14rVwTiwe4epfJYyrDhnjCgn/gnROo6IDPhUHZBbguftnXsbhn/gly/NEC0Bbx5kQRP4JYH7SOVVRdMb0LGP3AZ1uCEB7DFR5HAWqPD5EeMhmLxkOwfdL3DP247YLzFSizG8DoJA3@Wz4NMYhQ6Irg4riJYYqGGSAKZ2LQgIuaFM583yQbkoBQBRgZIbMk/JX9qo4Qj5DNNsS32pwytJMDSwz9ro62Ls39x8WD74te1UCS5upIrFX@NGG9Zoi8q5UvLDxLwo5in@@AygbINd4RntlHSVinw2CMUlhcek2WqIWqvCvWIiNQpkAf5m1REShO3cYki/LlhJRuR4PS7DB6QU32VvaI1NdYokGHAGFB0gVYzD/VGtfHCc7J1vaBYeEVR9LJRWg1@T2OFSLODyL788jRaslV0647DzDpeRgf@4cjwq74xonSbK/TD/5Nm7qc0c0AzJ2mK5v79XfPo/JQrbdPaKQbofha7UXGovKl/aF6fNq@5onxPmxnOSlS8SB@aqPdmDUmxN7Dum9e3nrtI70Lx/cmlH0HyTjtYo2wD15bogfXXb9Atcv/tgdm8ROKNBmOxsojEPyr0R2QFY81aTWOfZUUuoDYpFto0C0NX2xJjCF1ieHOIls3lsKR3kfxPykRkfDgQkwkcjn843IjplJHeLL9AECNJBPAQDT1Hc2Nv4GrD7nCiPUVfmWPHLt1Ws/y/1Yxtz0d6UC6t1AElSLE9r7SXQpm2ZSibZ5Bessp75crO23IFHgzwMAGryLE1mVTt5Jn17@0sHleJncQHi7fZahjCK4QRbyvi@@HyCoJvNcyJOuDB5OWJIYLBo4V2WzD9r5//7XYuxJoHyQdjpZyo0ql6hHA7APfA3aTpJx0/6fzwdrjM7ZqcW6lmEcKreEIjuJTeXqbgbvIPAGGJH1nAaz7qIz36/g8)

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, 13 bytes

```
Ln`setyb `[o]
```

[Try it!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=Ln%60setyb%20%60%5Bo%5D&stdin=)

### Explanation

```
Ln              - Output 13 as number
  `setyb `      - Push "bytes "
          [o]   - Output the rest of the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```
echo 8+9," bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/NTkjX8FC21JHSSGpsiS1WOn/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PEP8 Assembly](https://computersystemsbook.com/4th-edition/pep8/), 50 bytes

```
STRO 4,d
STOP
.WORD 13616
.ASCII " BYTES"
.END
```

13616 is "50" in ASCII

A programming language made as an introduction to assembly and low-level concepts. Not sure I've seen it used here before, so might be a first?

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
print(f'{chr(51)}{chr(52)} bytes')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI029OjmjSMPUULMWwjDSrFVIqixJLVbX/P8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 27 BYTES

```
Text(0,0,3*3²," BYTES
```

outputs on the graph. `Text(` allows to chain things to output, which `Output(` or `Disp` don't allow

there is probably room for improvement with one of those

- 27 in 2 or 3 bytes is possible but useless (`3^3`, `3³`)
- 26 in 3 bytes
- 25 in 2 bytes (`5²` not valid)
- 24 in 1 byte ??

This solution should work on all TI-83 and 84. See also the [14 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160907/98541) solution for the TI-84+ CE.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 19 bytes

```
82*3+."setyb">:#,_@
```

Outputs `19 bytes`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/39JIy1BbT6k4taQyScnOSlkn3uH/fwA)

Version with no numbers:

```
"D""/"-."setyb">:#,_@
```

Outputs `21 bytes`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X8lFSUlfSVdPqTi1pDJJyc5KWSfe4f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)), <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```python
print(22-3,'bytes')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69Ew8hI11hHPamyJLVYXfP/fwA)

Thanks to @twentysix for -3 bytes

Comment: 0b10110 to 22-3 gives 19 bytes: `print(22-3,'bytes')`

Answer (score 1):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org/calculator), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*Thanks [Lince Assassino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29679/lince-assassino) for -1 bytes*

```
6+6+" bytes"
```

Pasting that into the GeoGebra calculator and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives the string `12 bytes`.

Comment: `6+6+" bytes"` would also work (exactly like my answer in another language)

Comment: @LinceAssassino Lol thanks, can't believe I missed something as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Behaviour](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Behaviour), 12 bytes

```
6+6+" bytes"
```

The output is implicit, but if we need explicit print, here's one for 13 bytes:

```
@6+7+" bytes"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Aussie++](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus), 35 bytes

```
G'DAY MATE!
GIMME ""+70/2+" bytes";
```

Tested in commit 9522366.

---

This was more annoying to golf than I thought it would be. At first I tried this (33 bytes):

```
G'DAY MATE!
GIMME 11+22+" bytes";
```

But for some bizarre reason, this prints out `bytes33`, not `33 bytes` (see [this github issue](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus/issues/40)). So then I tried this (36 bytes):

```
G'DAY MATE!
GIMME ""+12+24+" bytes";
```

But that printed out `1224 bytes`. I thought I could be clever and tried this (35 bytes):

```
G'DAY MATE!
GIMME ""+41-6+" bytes";
```

Only to be given the error `THOSE AREN'T FUCKIN NUMBERS MATE!`. It became apparent that I had to use parens if I wanted to use addition or subtraction.

However, parens aren't necessary for multiplication. I tried multiplication, but I reached an impasse: using `17*2` made it be 35 bytes but print 34, using `4*9` made it be 34 bytes but print 36, etc. I could use `(4*9)` to be 36 and print 36, but then I'd be breaking the rule on unnecessary characters (I think).

Only after considering using `(9+28)` for 37 bytes did the idea of division come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 15 bytes

```
a:
*=>15\ bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

## Minecraft Command Blocks, 198 bytes

A series of five command blocks with these commands:

```
scoreboard objectives add s dummy
scoreboard players set s s 33
scoreboard players set b s 6
scoreboard players operation s s *= b s
tellraw @a [{"score":{"name":"s","objective":"s"}},{"text":" bytes"}]
```

[image: 198 bytes]

Pretty simple, it calculates 6 * 33 and prints the answer +  `bytes`. I got lucky and didn't have to adjust the length of anything.

Answer (score 1):

## Microscript II, 13 bytes

`7s6+p" bytes"`

Pretty trivial, just adds 7 and 6 to get 13, and uses implicit output for the trailing  `bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang/), 17 bytes

```knight
O++''-8~9' bytes'
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyJPKysnJy04fjknIGJ5dGVzJyIsIiJd)

My second attempt at a second entry for the August 2022 language of the month event.

The original solution is left here for posterity

```knight
OUTPUT++''%60 36' bytes'
```

Comment: You mean August 2022

Comment: @steffan indeed I do. I'll fix that

Comment: The reason the `~3` isn't working is because the C implementation is out of date. You can use my interpreter here: https://knight-lang.netlify.app/ However, it's not quite correct as it outputs `22 bytes` although it's 23 bytes. Should be easily fixable.

Comment: Also, as you can find out by reading the spec, each function can be shortened to just its first letter. So `OUTPUT` is just `O`, but it would work the same if you did `OSADKJKA` or whatever.

Comment: So here's 17 bytes: `O++''+9 8' bytes'`. [Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyJPKysnJys5IDgnIGJ5dGVzJyIsIiJd)

Comment: Thank's all; I've reduced it to 17 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Headascii](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass#Headascii), 55 BYTES

```
++++[]]]][]^^]]+++++PPDP++]]P^]+++++++P-----P(D+++P<-P!
```

[Try it here](https://replit.com/@thejonymyster/HA23#index.js), code will have to be pasted in  and executed as shown below:

```js
erun("++++[]]]][]^^]]+++++PPDP++]]P^]+++++++P-----P(D+++P<-P!")
```

Outputs `55 BYTES`

Code breakdown:

```
++++[]]]][]^^]]+++++PPDP++]]P^]+++++++P-----P(D+++P<-P! full program
++++[]]]][                                              save 16 to R2
          ]^^                                           save 32 to R1
             ]]+++++PP                                  append "55" to string register
                      DP                                append " " to string register
                        ++]]P                           append "B" to string register
                             ^                          save 66 to R1
                              ]+++++++P                 append "Y" to string register
                                       -----P           append "T" to string register
                                             (          store 84 in R3
                                              D+++P     append "E" to string register
                                                   <-P  append "S" to string register
                                                      ! print string register
```

This breakdown isn't great but the basic idea is that `[^(` store to registers and `]D<` return values from registers, and treat the rest like brainfuck basically :P

Comment: Oh wait this is 54 bytes in Headass, i'll add it later

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 12 bytes

```
34*" bytes"+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/9/YREtJIamyJLVYSfv/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 20 bytes

```
alert(5*4+" bytes");
```

Comment: Unnecessary characters, spaces, and newlines are forbidden in the source code

Comment: @l4m2 Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jotlin](https://github.com/jrtapsell/jotlin), 17 bytes

```
P("${8+9} bytes")
```

Uses the println builtin

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 18 bytes

```
Print[!4-6,$bytes]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM68kWtFE10xHJamyJLU49v9/AA)

This is simply printing `!4-6` (which is `factorial(4) - 6`) followed by `bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```
{print"${0x16} bytes"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/K/xv7qgKDOvREml2qDC0KxWIamyJLVYqfa/pobmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>19</s> 14 bytes

```
$0=2*7" bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcDWSMtcSSGpsiS1WOn/fy4A)

Comment: I don't get the point in using the x variable. Why not `$0=2*7" bytes"` for 14 bytes?

Comment: Well obviously it's because I didn't think of it.  :p

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 35 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
2⁵1⁺ᴇ⁻⁻1ᴇ⁺²2ᴇ4²+9⁺²⁺1ᴇ⁺²6-áƇǰ8Ḟ1+⇹ǰ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f6FHjVsNHjbsebml/1LgbiAzBrF2HNhkBGSaHNmlbgnlAAi5jpnt44bH24xssHu6YZ6j9qH3n8Q3//wMA)

Explanation:

```
2⁵         Push 32
1⁺ᴇ⁻⁻      Push 98
1ᴇ⁺²       Push 121
2ᴇ4²+      Push 116
9⁺²⁺       Push 101
1ᴇ⁺²6-     Push 115
á          Convert stack to array, and push the array onto the stack
Ƈ          Cast to characters ([" ","b","y","t","e","s"])
ǰ          Join the elements of the array (" bytes")
8Ḟ1+       Push 35
⇹          Swap the top two elements on the stack
ǰ          Concatenate the stack as a string ("35 bytes")
           Implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 31 bytes

```
@set /a r=29+2 
@echo %r% bytes
```

Comment: The source code is not allowed to include any of the digits of the byte count. `20*2` contains a zero.

Comment: For only two lines, no `@echo off` to optimize

Comment: Thanks l4m2, I have shortened the answer and corrected my mistake.

Comment: Save two bytes: `@set/ar=33-4`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), 22 bytes

```
print("\(18+4) bytes")
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/HQI84159)

Answer (score 0):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), <s>18</s> 15 bytes

**Solution:**

```
($6+9)," bytes"
```

**Example:**

```
q)k)($6+9)," bytes"
"15 bytes"
```

**Explanation:**

Evaluated right-to-left, don't think I can get lower than 15 this way:

```
($6+9)," bytes" / the solution
      ," bytes" / join " bytes" with...
(    )          / do together
  6+9           / 6+9 = 15
 $              / cast to string
```

**Alternative:**

Another **15 byte** solution, has potential to be golfed if anyone can make `"41"` in 4 chars or `"31"` in 3 chars:

```
|"setyb ",$49+2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```
t." bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@/RE9JIamyJLVY6f9/AA)

Conveniently, there's a preset variable for the number 10.

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 15 bytes

An anonymous [yabasic](/questions/tagged/yabasic) answer that takes no input and outputs to STDOUT.

```vb
?7+8;
?" bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/395c28Kay15JIamyJLVY6f9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 14 bytes

An anonymous [ubasic](/questions/tagged/ubasic) answer.

```
0?2*7;" bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwN5Iy9xaSSGpsiS1WOn/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 18 bytes

An anonymous MY-BASIC answer that outputs to STDOUT.

```vb
Print 9+9," bytes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/z@gKDOvRMFS21JHSSGpsiS1WOn/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Visual Basic .NET (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/), 66 bytes

A declared `Sub`routine that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Console.Write(3*22 &" bytes")
End Sub
End Module
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ssLk3M0U1KLM5M1s1LLdHNzc/L///fNz@lNCdVwZcruDRJwTcxM4/LOT@vOD8nVS@8KLMkVcNYy8hIQU1JIamyJLVYSZPLNS9FAagUTEP0/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 19 bytes

```
prin[22 - 3 'bytes]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmqIQHfu/oCgzL9rISEFXwVhBPamyJLU49v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [jshell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JShell), 12 bytes

```
9+3+" bytes"
```

I don't think it's on TIO.run despite having an article on Wikipedia.

Comment: For whatever reason, JShell requires TCP sockets to start up. For security reasons, those aren't available in TIO's sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 10 bytes

```
μ( bytes)B
```

`μ` represents `10`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//9weDYWkypLUYk2n//8B)

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 17 Bytes

```
echo $[8+9] bytes
```

output:

```
17 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 13 Bytes

```
i<Ctrl-r>=7+6<Enter> bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

## FALSE, 11 bytes

```
'\u000B." bytes"
```

`\u000B` should be replaced by the corresponding character.

Answer (score 0):

## Go, <strike>66</strike> 64 bytes

```
package main;import"fmt";func main(){fmt.Printf("%d bytes",'@')}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haxe, 20 bytes

```
trace(4*5+' bytes');
```

[Try it online!](https://try.haxe.org/#Dc9cB)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 16 bytes

```cs
n=>8*2+" bytes";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcu9CsIwEADguXmKo1PqTxEnoT@L4KQgODiIQ4xpOGgvkDuFIn32WBDcv8/y2oboku0NM5xj8NEM8FEZixG08A74hJNB0iwRyd/uYKLnYibqMrK4oTy8yNZIsoIfaaGDJlHT7hbbZQ6PURznVar@YR@IQ@/Ka0RxRySnO70pihlkk5rSFw)

---

## 39 bytes

```cs
n=>System.Console.Write(~-40+" bytes");
```

Not sure whether returning the output from a function is valid, if not, here's a 39 byte solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcqxCsIwEIDhuXmKo1OCtHRwqy2IsyA4OIhDjGk5aC9wdwhF6qvHDk7/8P1BqpA45jB5EbhwGtnP8DGFqFcM8E74grNHsqKMNN4f4HkUty3muojGuT4GxUQHJO1hgC5T1//llEjSFOsbo0b7rfbNroTnolFK1@bWmME2bkuxmjX/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 23 bytes

```
(runt 1^0vcpi " bytes")
```

`(runt [p q] "tape")` prepends a byte sequence `q` to a string `p` number of times. `p^q` is sugar for `[p q]`, and `0vXXX` is base32 (`@uv`) encoding for the byte string `'23'`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 9 bytes

```
75 02 94 0A 09 58 EF 64 4A
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=75+02+94+0A+09+58+Ef+64+4a&input=&warnings=0&hex=1)

```
u 02 94 0A 09      - integer list, length 2 ([2570, 9])
             X     - splat(^)
              .o   - lookup 2570 in dictionary (bytes)
                dJ - join by " "
```

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 13 bytes

```
a20 bytes<esc>^7<C-x>
```

`<esc>` is `\x1B` and `<C-x>` is `\x18`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9HIQCGpsiS12Ca1ONkuztzGWbfC7v///7plAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 14 bytes

```
72*u" bytes"&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/cSKtUSSGpsiS1WEkt//9/AA)

I tried a solution based on Ly's quine, but it quickly turned out to cost more bytes than it saved.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 24 bytes

```clj
(println(+ 17 7)"bytes")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/X6OgKDOvJCdPQ1vB0FzBXFMpqbIktVhJ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 46 bytes

```
38 8 bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f//w/z@xg/ze9s/zJ/RAKRXfZg/ZaGxhYIFkF6ikFRZkloMYkFkejv//wcA)

I wanted to add my own answer to this question, but seeing as y’all took all the GOOD languages, I had to pick one of the weird ones

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 21 bytes

```
print(3*7 ..' bytes')
```

The space before .. (string concatenation operator) is required or the parser sees 7.. as a malformed number.

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
es7+
t"8p
ybp
"
```

We first push `" bytes"`, then `78+` (15) and then print both.

*edit: Fixed counting final newline character*
*edit2: Saved 1 byte thanks to Jo King*

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//z@12Fybq0TJooCrMqmAS@n/fwA "Aceto – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 13 bytes

```
=4+9&" bytes"
```

Using `CONCATENATE` for 28 bytes:

```
=CONCATENATE(4*6+4," bytes")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Go, 46 Bytes

```
package main;func main(){print(38+8," bytes")}
```

Comment: Yeah, but now you have no space between the number and the `bytes`

Answer (score 0):

## [LOWER](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/LOWER), 93 bytes

```
ₔ₉₃ₔₓ₃₂ₔₓ₉₈ₔₓ₁₂₁ₔₓ₁₁₆ₔₓ₁₀₁ₔₓ₁₁₅
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvTy36//9R05RHTZ2PmprBjMlgRhOMDRTvgLEbweKNSFwgakPiNmDItv7/DwA)

This is all Unicode characters, so no `9`s or `3`s here.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
alert(`${8+14} bytes`)
```

Comment: ok. will do that.

Comment: @Cowsquack : There done. Thanks for the info

Comment: OK? I see what the point is. It must outputting that on its own. Ok will update that.

Comment: Nice, this works fine now :)

Comment: @Cowsquack: Thanks you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

## [Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), 96 bytes

```
d=$1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1
all:
	@echo $(words $(call d,x x x x x x x) $(call d,x x x x x)) bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MTv3/P8VWxVABG@JKzMmx4uJ0SE3OyFdQ0SjPL0opBtLJQGGFFJ0KBSSoiUVcU1MhqbIktfj/fwA)

Comment: See [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/73111) and [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9260/73111) standard loophole. I do not think that your answer is valid.

Comment: @JonathanFrech fixed

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 32 bytes

```
main(){printf("%d bytes",8*4);}
```

Nothing crazy here.

Answer (score 0):

## Commodore 64 - 74 tokenized and BASIC bytes

Assuming by score in bytes, you mean tokens and bytes used by the BASIC interpreter, this works:

```
0 def fn b(x) = 38911-(fre(x)-2^16*(fre(x)<x)): print fnb(.);"bytes
```

There is a bug in the FRE() function on the Commodore 64 as it assumes maximum size of BASIC is 32K, or 32768 bytes.

#### Commodore VIC-20 (unexpanded) - 29 tonkenized and BASIC bytes

```
0?(60*60-17)-fre(.)"bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 16 bytes

```
<<<$[##␐]\ bytes
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhYbbGxsVKKVlQViYxSSKktSiyHCUFmYKgA)

`␐` should be a literal `0x10` byte, but that doesn't show up in SE markdown.

---

### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-BCDEFGHIJ`, 13 bytes

```
<<<$#-\ bytes
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjXbSSrpOzi6ubu4enl1LsgqWlJWm6FmttbGxUlHVjFJIqS1KLIWJQqQVQGgA)

Cheating.

Comment: What is that flag lol

Comment: @thejonymyster It doesn't matter what the contents of the flag is, but the code itself is counting the length of the flags (I think).

Comment: @Steffan That's correct. Note that Zsh already has the options `569X` enabled by default, so by adding `BCDEFGHIJ` the length of the options reaches 13.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), 14 bytes

```
7 2*J" bytes"+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbrzBWMtLyUFJIqS1KLlbQhglA5mBoA)

##### Explanation

```python
7 2*             # Push 7 * 2 (14)
    J            # Convert to string
     " bytes"    # Push the string " bytes"
             +   # Concatenate
                 # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 106 bytes

```
D'`_ML"n<YkFEVwwe@PsON;:ml[kG4ECe#z@x,_^)\[Zvotm3qSi/gfed*hgfH%]baZ_^W{UZSRWVUNrR4PINGLEiIBG@dDCB$@?>=<5YF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/99FPSHe10cpzyYy2801rLw81SGg2N/P2io3Jzrb3cTVOVW5yqFCJz5OMyY6qiy/JNe4MDhTPz0tNUUrIz3NQzU2KTEqPi68OjQqOCg8LNSvKMgkwNPP3cc109PJ3SHFxdlJxcHeztbGNNLt/38A)

Created with [zb3 malbolge tools](http://zb3.me/malbolge-tools/#generator)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
30 2/ò" bytes"J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f2EDBSP/wJiWFpMqS1GIlr///AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org)'s type system, 24 bytes

```typescript
type F=`${0o30} bytes`;;
```

[Try it at  the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgvAAwCQG8AMB7AzGgvlAIxGAgGcEBuCgKAHpapGA9AfmqA)

TIL TypeScript has octal literal types. Two dead bytes because `0o26` has a `2` in it.

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org)'s type system, <s>65</s> 55 bytes

```typescript
type Z=[1,1,1,1,1]["length"]
type F=`${Z}${Z} bytes`;;;
```

[Try it at the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAWgvAbQIwBpXrQXQQIgDYQB2A5sABY6YBQokUAYnAAYAkA3jAL7tdQBGIYBADOTANwSqAeilQ5APQD8VIA)

3 dead bytes there, in order to get both digits the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 48 Bytes

Pascal according to ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” allows you to specify `integer` literals up to a base of 36.

```pascal
program p(output);begin write(7#66,' Bytes')end.
```

```pascal
program p(output);begin write(9#53,' Bytes')end.
```

See also the [FreePascal submission](/a/172991).

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang/), 16 bytes

```
=a$**^~>" bytes"
```

## ibe, 28 bytes

```
dheoslresluuslopslotslupslor
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 28 bytes

I know more succinct solutions are possible but this one amused me.

```ruby
:join&:succ*[?1,?7," byter"]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWe6yy8jPz1KyKS5OTtaLtDXXszXWUFJIqS1KLlGIhSlYUlJYUK7hFQ7kLFkBoAA)