# Quine in Bytes, not Characters

Tags: code-golf, integer, quine

## Introduction

A quine is a program that takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as output. Writing a quine is a standard test of a programming language. Most quines operate using strings of characters: that is what the source code is made of, after all! However, this quine is slightly different.

## Challenge

Your challenge is to write a program that takes no input and produces the number of bytes in the program as output.

- By "takes no input", I mean does not change based on input. Your program can still take command line arguments, or even arguments from stdin, but it cannot do anything with them. It must either discard or ignore them. Basically, your program should produce the same output no matter what input is given.
- Your program must output the number of bytes in it. If it is a function, it can output through its return value. If, and only if your language has no stdout, you may store output in a variable. The input can be printed as a string or an integer; the user cannot tell the difference between the output of `print('5')` or `print(5)`! Note that I said byte count, not character count. If your program uses Unicode characters that take up more than 1 byte (like some Jelly or APL programs), the output must reflect that.

## Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer in bytes wins! Edit: Actually, since there is a 1 byte answer, let's do top 3 shortest.

Edit: this question is not the same as [Output your Score](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160646/output-your-score). For one, this one does not disallow cheating quines. Also, I do not require a trailing " bytes" in output.

Comment: Does this have to meet standard Quine rules? For instance, `1` in Jelly is 1 byte long, and would output 1, is that acceptable?

Comment: @caird coinheringaahing - you do not have to follow standard rules. In this challenge, if it doesn't say you can't, assume you can.

Comment: When you say "byte count", do you mean UTF-8 byte count, or can we use our own encodings? For instance, if `¬` outputs 1, and is encoded as a single byte in our code page, would that be an acceptable answer?

Comment: No. A said in the answer, Unicode/UTF-8 byte counts are used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output your score](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/160646/76162)

Comment: Characters in languages with SBCS *do* take up only one byte, so I don't see the point of penalising them for what character they use (which seems to be the opposite of what you want)

Comment: @JoKing pppery I would say this challenge is sufficiently different, given that the other is restricted-source.

Comment: My biggest problem with calling this a duplicate is that my answer here meets this challenge. No way it meets the other challenge. It's not even possible. The same might be true for many, if not most, of the other answers here. That doesn't feel right somehow....

Answer (score 12):

## Most languages, 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7DwQA)

Outputs via exit code, which is `0` for almost any language where an empty program is valid.

Comment: Just realised that my Jelly answer could be golfed to this :/ I'll leave it to avoid duplicate answers though

Comment: Not necessarily. In C it will be unable to find an entry symbol and the compile or link operation will fail.

Comment: @rsonx Well yes, the empty program isn't valid in C...

Comment: "If it is a function, it can output through its return value". This is not a function

Comment: @JBernardo Yes? I never claimed it was a function. As stated, this is a full program that outputs via exit code.

Answer (score 5):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html), <s>87</s> 86 bytes

*-1 byte due to a slightly better representation of the character "8".*

```
hey-o
i guess i got a number i can write
an apple a day keeps doctors away, we suppose
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?DYnBDYAwDMT@THEDwFCBngABTdS0qjp9ycu2fHFsutw4G90R1ApBbt/OEnlIRi935RIiZi/jJhl4SHMkPaoWh3QZKzrhzUydc@6Sfg)

Poetic is an esolang I made in 2018 for a class project. It's basically brainfuck with word-lengths instead of symbols.

I couldn't resist making the word-lengths spell out a popular phrase, hehe.  ‍⚕️

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w/38A)

This probably works in a lot of other languages as well. Note that the output does *not* have a trailing newline

Comment: Polyglot with Keg and Carrot obviously.

Comment: @A_ And probably 05AB1E, Gaia, Deorst, or almost other golfing languages :P

Comment: It even works in PHP

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 7 bytes

```python
print 7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69Ewfz/fwA)

Comment: For Python 3, both `print(8)` and `lambda:8` come out at 8 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 2 bytes

```
2#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fSPn/fwA)

Not a duplicate, and this should hopefully clinch me 3rd place :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 4 bytes

```perl
$_=4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbk//@s7Bwg@pdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0OC/bgEA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 3 bytes

Probably one of the only times Ruby can beat Perl in bytes.

```ruby
p 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DB@P9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 4 bytes

Boring!

```javascript
_=>4
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1s7kf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 20 bytes

```
-[>+<-----]>-.--.kek
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO20YXBGLtdPV0dfWyU4GiAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 1 byte

```
╧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1OX//wMA)

### Explanation

```
╧  On the empty stack, pop a,b, push a.contains(b)
   0 definitely contains 0, pushing a 1.

Implicit output
```

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 1 byte

```
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1OWa//8DAA)

### Explanation

```
) Increment this 0 value on the stack, returning a 1.
```

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 1 byte

```
=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/2/38A)

### Explanation

```
= Check equality of 0 and 0, returns 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 1 byte

```
^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/7v9/AA) In Retina, the empty program outputs 1 more than the length of its input, which is bad here, since we don't want the output to depend on the input. Fortunately, either `^` or `$` help here, as they force the output to be `1`, which is conveniently also their length.

Answer (score 2):

## [HQ9+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9+), 1 byte

```
+
```

This language does not allow you to write a program that prints only one number. Therefore, I save the number of bytes in a special counter.

[HQ9+ online interpreter](https://almnet.de/esolang/hq9plus.php)

Answer (score 2):

## [Metatape](https://github.com/HactarCE/Metatape), 22 bytes

```
@a{ooxooeooxoeo} !a !a
```

The space characters are not syntactically necessary, but they take up less space than it would to output `21` or `20`.

`@a{...}` defines a subroutine named `a`, and `!a` executes that subroutine.

Output is bitwise (highest bit first). While the actual language is more complicated, for the sake of this program:

- `x` makes subsequent `o`s output `1`.
- `e` makes subsequent `o`s output `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 5 bytes

```hs
f a=5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h0db0f25iZp5tQWlJcEmRT55KcUZ@uUqagpnlfwA)

Comment: Err... That's neither a function nor an action. Is this allowed?

Comment: Not sure, changed it to be safe.

Comment: You could maybe argue that `f=3` was a function that takes no arguments

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 6 bytes

```r
cat(6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRMNM8/9/AA)

(Note that Jo King's [0 byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195189/86301) is also valid in R.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 6 bytes

```bash
echo 6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/B7P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-F0`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 0 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LUYw&input=NA)

This can be my first 0 bytes answer!

Using -F"0" flag => outputs 0 if the programme returns a falsey  value

Comment: You can golf that flag to `-F0`! But note, as it says in the docs, many will consider the `-Ex` & `-Fx` flags to be "cheating". This, though, I'd say is a more borderline case.

Comment: @Shaggy yes.. I was just tempted to give my first 0bytes answer when I saw Jo King hint that most languages can do it

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 3 bytes

```rust
||3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6GpUM2lAAQ5qSUKaQq2/2tqjP9bg0UKijLzSnLyFDWUqmuVdBTSNDQ1rblq/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PMD 85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMD_85) BASIC, 0 bytes

Without any lines of code, `RUN` will respond with

> OK

i.e. zero kilobytes.

(yes, it's cheating)

Comment: I chuckled at this.

Answer (score 0):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 9 bytes

```
0 _ 9 * 1
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?e05158677198c61249c8038480d3ead6)