# Codegolf the permanent

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix, complex-numbers

The challenge is to write codegolf for the [permanent of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent).

The permanent of an \$n\times n\$ matrix \$A = a_{i,j}\$) is defined as

$$\text{perm}(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod^n_{i=1} a_{i,\sigma(i)}$$

Here \$S_n\$ represents the set of all permutations of \$[1, n]\$.

As an example (from the wiki):

$$\text{perm} \left( \begin{matrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
\end{matrix} \right) = aei + bfg + cdh + ceg + bdi + afh$$

Your code can take input however it wishes and give output in any sensible format but please include in your answer a full worked example including clear instructions for how to supply input to your code. To make the challenge a little more interesting, the matrix may include complex numbers.

The input matrix is always square and will be at most 6 by 6.  <strike>You will also need to be able to handle the empty matrix which has permanent 1.</strike> There is no need to be able to handle the empty matrix (it was causing too many problems).

**Examples**

Input:

```
[[ 0.36697048+0.02459455j,  0.81148991+0.75269667j,  0.62568185+0.95950937j],
 [ 0.67985923+0.11419187j,  0.50131790+0.13067928j,  0.10330161+0.83532727j],
 [ 0.71085747+0.86199765j,  0.68902048+0.50886302j,  0.52729463+0.5974208j ]]
```

Output:

```
-1.7421952844303492+2.2476833142265793j
```

Input:

```
[[ 0.83702504+0.05801749j,  0.03912260+0.25027115j,  0.95507961+0.59109069j],
 [ 0.07330546+0.8569899j ,  0.47845015+0.45077079j,  0.80317410+0.5820795j ],
 [ 0.38306447+0.76444045j,  0.54067092+0.90206306j,  0.40001631+0.43832931j]]
```

Output:

```
-1.972117936608412+1.6081325306004794j
```

Input:

```
 [[ 0.61164611+0.42958732j,  0.69306292+0.94856925j,
     0.43860930+0.04104116j,  0.92232338+0.32857505j,
     0.40964318+0.59225476j,  0.69109847+0.32620144j],
   [ 0.57851263+0.69458731j,  0.21746623+0.38778693j,
     0.83334638+0.25805241j,  0.64855830+0.36137045j,
     0.65890840+0.06557287j,  0.25411493+0.37812483j],
   [ 0.11114704+0.44631335j,  0.32068031+0.52023283j,
     0.43360984+0.87037973j,  0.42752697+0.75343656j,
     0.23848512+0.96334466j,  0.28165516+0.13257001j],
   [ 0.66386467+0.21002292j,  0.11781236+0.00967473j,
     0.75491373+0.44880959j,  0.66749636+0.90076845j,
     0.00939420+0.06484633j,  0.21316223+0.4538433j ],
   [ 0.40175631+0.89340763j,  0.26849809+0.82500173j,
     0.84124107+0.23030393j,  0.62689175+0.61870543j,
     0.92430209+0.11914288j,  0.90655023+0.63096257j],
   [ 0.85830178+0.16441943j,  0.91144755+0.49943801j,
     0.51010550+0.60590678j,  0.51439995+0.37354955j,
     0.79986742+0.87723514j,  0.43231194+0.54571625j]]
```

Output:

```
-22.92354821347135-90.74278997288275j
```

You may not use any pre-existing functions to compute the permanent.

Comment: Is the matrix always a 3x3? Or are the dimensions arbitrary?

Comment: @L.Steer Updated question. Thank you.

Comment: Do we need to handle an empty matrix?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes. Great question.

Comment: Could you please remove the complex requirement? I think it ruins an otherwise nice challenge. Every language that doesn't have built-in complex arithmetic now has to do a totally separate task.

Comment: If we need to handle the empty matrix, you should add it as a test case. The fact that you cannot really represent the 0x0 matrix with lists makes this a bit difficult. Personally, I'd just remove that requirement.

Comment: It would also be nice to explain what S_n is for the benefit of those who don't know.

Comment: The empty matrix has permanent 1, not 0, though I agree with Dennis about just not including it.

Comment: @xnor Argh.. I knew I would get that wrong. Thank you.

Comment: There's no point putting something in the sandbox for 3 hours. Give it 3 days and people have a chance to give feedback.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I hear you.  There is also the issue that I just have some preferences for codegolf questions which not everyone agrees with.  For example, I don't feel the need to make every question as easy for restricted esolangs as for higher level languages.

Comment: **1.** It's not just esolangs. Bash, e.g., can't even natively deal with *floats*. Excluding a language from the competition just because it lacks a certain numeric type, even if can effortlessly implement the desired algorithm, is just being picky for no good reason. **2.** I'm still not sure about the empty matrix. Would it be `[[]]` (has one row, the empty matrix doesn't) or `[]` (doesn't have depth 2, matrices do) in list form?

Comment: @Dennis 2. I think a 1d empty array is `[]` and a 2d one is `[[]]`.  I suppose equivalently we could define it to have one empty column. This is just an oddity of how 2d arrays are represented I think.  1. I love bash more than most people but surely almost all challenges have a set of languages that are suited to it and a set that aren't.  I also don't think we should compare solutions in different languages in codegolf.  I am interested in the best one in each language for which there is a submitted answer.

Comment: @Dennis http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787 has various fun ways of handling floating point numbers.

Comment: **1.** I'm not daying that it's *impossible* to solve this challenge in Bash, but if the lion share of the code is used to deal with complex number arithmetic, it stops being a challenge about permanents. **2.** Most if not all current answers is languages without a matrix type break for input `[[]]`.

Comment: `[[]]` is clearly a 1x0 matrix. My recursive function needs the empty matrix as base case, and it comes naturally down to `[]`. - BTW, I think an example that is easy to type (low dimension, simple numbers) would have been very helpful.

Comment: @ChristianSievers you are right on both counts.

Comment: It's a shame this otherwise-great question is burdened by these difficulties. Like Peter said - leave challenges in the sandbox longer if you want good feedback. 3 hours is way too short.

Comment: @Mego I removed the empty matrix requirement. I hope that helps.

Comment: My objection wasn't related to the empty matrix requirement (I made it after the requirement was removed). I am objecting to requiring complex number support (which doesn't really add anything to the challenge other than incredible complication for languages without native complex number support), the lack of simple test cases, and the lack of explanation for your equations (not everyone knows that `S_n` represents the set of all permutations of `[1, n]`).

Comment: @Mego I have now added an explanation for S_n (thank you. I used yours).  Can we just disagree about the complex number requirement? I think it's interesting and it's an extra interesting challenge (in my view) to golf code in a language that doesn't have complex number support. No one should be comparing the length of such code with something in a language that does.  In general, my preference is for challenges that are closer to real life problems and I feel there is room on codegolf for a wide variety of question types.

Comment: @Lembik The issue is, as Dennis mentioned, by requiring complex number support, this challenge is more about complex number arithmetic than it is about the permanent of a matrix in languages without native complex number support. It's essentially two different challenges, depending on the choice of language.

Comment: @Mego the same argument is valid for the tons of challenges on this site based on operation on prime numbers.  *Every* esolang has a 1 byte builtin for the primality test, while using general purpose languages you have to add a bunch of code just to do the test

Comment: @edc65 Those challenges include operations on prime numbers because they actually add something to the challenge (or are the core of the challenge). Requiring complex support in this challenge is [adding unnecessary fluff](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9384/45941) by [requiring the use of unnecessarily complicated number types](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8437/45941), which causes it to be a [chameleon challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8214/45941). Three hits on the "don't do these things" list is not good.

Comment: @Mego example: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89726/golf-a-brain-flak-integer/90608#90608

Comment: @edc65 Trying to say "well why didn't you complain about X challenge" isn't constructive - I don't read every challenge that gets posted.

Comment: @Mego Don't you? You said "those challenges...". I did not complain about them (trust me, they are a lot) even if I don't like them, and I don't complain about this one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## J, 5 bytes

```
+/ .*
```

J does not offer builtins for the permanent or determinant but instead offers a conjunction `u . v y` which recursively expands `y` along the minors and calculates dyadic `u . v` between the cofactors and the output of the recursive call on the minors. The choices of `u` and `v` can vary. For example, using `u =: -/` and `v =: *` is `-/ .*` which is the determinant. Choices can even by `%/ .!` where `u=: %/`, reduce by division, and `v =: !` which is binomial coefficient. I'm not sure what that output signifies but you're free to choose your verbs.

An alternative implementation for **47 bytes** using the same method in my Mathematica [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96860/6710).

```
_1{[:($@]$[:+//.*/)/0,.;@(<@(,0#~<:)"+2^i.@#)"{
```

This simulates a polynomial with *n* variables by creating a polynomial with one variable raised to powers of 2. This is held as a coefficient list and polynomial multiplication is performed using convolution, and the index at 2<sup>*n*</sup> will contain the result.

Another implementation for **31 bytes** is

```
+/@({.*1$:\.|:@}.)`(0{,)@.(1=#)
```

which is a slightly golfed version based on Laplace expansion taken from the J essay on [determinants](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Essays/Determinant).

### Usage

```
   f =: +/ .*
   f 0 0 $ 0 NB. the empty matrix, create a shape with dimensions 0 x 0
1
   f 0.36697048j0.02459455 0.81148991j0.75269667 0.62568185j0.95950937 , 0.67985923j0.11419187  0.50131790j0.13067928 0.10330161j0.83532727 ,: 0.71085747j0.86199765 0.68902048j0.50886302 0.52729463j0.5974208
_1.7422j2.24768
   f 0.83702504j0.05801749 0.03912260j0.25027115 0.95507961j0.59109069 , 0.07330546j0.8569899 0.47845015j0.45077079 0.80317410j0.5820795 ,: 0.38306447j0.76444045 0.54067092j0.90206306 0.40001631j0.43832931
_1.97212j1.60813
   f 0.61164611j0.42958732 0.69306292j0.94856925 0.4386093j0.04104116 0.92232338j0.32857505 0.40964318j0.59225476 0.69109847j0.32620144 , 0.57851263j0.69458731 0.21746623j0.38778693 0.83334638j0.25805241 0.6485583j0.36137045 0.6589084j0.06557287 0.25411493j0.37812483 , 0.11114704j0.44631335 0.32068031j0.52023283 0.43360984j0.87037973 0.42752697j0.75343656 0.23848512j0.96334466 0.28165516j0.13257001 , 0.66386467j0.21002292 0.11781236j0.00967473 0.75491373j0.44880959 0.66749636j0.90076845 0.0093942j0.06484633 0.21316223j0.4538433 , 0.40175631j0.89340763 0.26849809j0.82500173 0.84124107j0.23030393 0.62689175j0.61870543 0.92430209j0.11914288 0.90655023j0.63096257 ,: 0.85830178j0.16441943 0.91144755j0.49943801 0.5101055j0.60590678 0.51439995j0.37354955 0.79986742j0.87723514 0.43231194j0.54571625
_22.9235j_90.7428
```

Comment: Wow is all I can say.

Answer (score 13):

### Haskell, 59 bytes

```
a#((b:c):r)=b*p(a++map tail r)+(c:a)#r
_#_=0
p[]=1
p l=[]#l
```

This does a Laplace-like development along the first column, and uses that the order of the rows doesn't matter. It works for any numeric type.

Input is as list of lists:

```
Prelude> p [[1,2],[3,4]]
10
```

Comment: Always welcome a Haskell solution!

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œ!ŒDḢ€P€S
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZIhxZJE4bii4oKsUOKCrFM&input=&args=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)

#### How it works

```
Œ!ŒDḢ€P€S  Main link. Argument: M (matrix / 2D array)

Œ!         Generate all permutations of M's rows.
  ŒD       Compute the permutations' diagonals, starting with the main diagonal.
    Ḣ€     Head each; extract the main diagonal of each permutation.
      P€   Product each; compute the products of the main diagonals.
        S  Compute the sum of the products.
```

Comment: It's just too good!

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 75 bytes

Seems clunky... should be beatable.

```py
P=lambda m,i=0:sum([r[i]*P(m[:j]+m[j+1:],i+1)for j,r in enumerate(m)]or[1])
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
œvyvyNè}Pˆ}¯O
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xZN2eXZ5TsOofVDLhn3Cr08&input=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)

**Explanation**

```
œ              # get all permutations of rows
 v        }    # for each permutation
  yv   }       # for each row in the permutation
    yNè        # get the element at index row-index
        P      # product of elements
         ˆ     # add product to global array
           ¯O  # sum the products from the global array
```

Comment: A slightly shockingly sized answer! Could you provide some explanation?

Comment: @Lembik: Feels like it could be shorter still. I have a second solution of the same size so far.

Comment: Handling empty matrices is no longer required.

Comment: [8 bytes by using maps](https://tinyurl.com/yx3cmfdk). Too bad the new 05AB1E doesn't support imaginary numbers (or I simply don't know how), since we now have a main diagonal builtin and this could have been 6 bytes: `œ€Å\PO`.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 139 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
def p(a):c=complex;r=range(len(a));return sum(reduce(c.__mul__,[a[j][p[j]]for j in r],c(1))for p in permutations(r))
```

**[repl.it](https://repl.it/EBh8/3)**

Implements the naïve algorithm which blindly follows the definition.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <del>74</del> 63 bytes

```
->a{p=0;a.permutation{|b|n=1;i=-1;a.map{n*=b[i+=1][i]};p+=n};p}
```

A straightforward translation of the formula. Several bytes saved thanks to ezrast.

### Explanation

```
->a{
    # Initialize the permanent to 0
    p=0
    # For each permutation of a's rows...
    a.permutation{|b|
        # ... initialize the product to 1,
        n=1
        # initialize the index to -1; we'll use this to go down the main diagonal
        # (i starts at -1 because at each step, the first thing we do is increment i),
        i=-1
        # iteratively calculate the product,
        a.map{
            n*=b[i+=1][i]
        }
        # increase p by the main diagonal's product.
        p+=n
    }
    p
}
```

Comment: `reduce` actually hurts your byte count compared to aggregating manually: `->a{m=0;a.permutation{|b|n=1;a.size.times{|i|n*=b[i][i]};m+=n};m}`

Comment: @ezrast Thanks! Managed to golf down that `times` loop as well.

Answer (score 4):

## MATL, <s>17</s>14 bytes

```
tZyt:tY@X])!ps
```

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFp5dDp0WUBYXSkhcHM&input=WzAuMzY2OTcwNDgrMC4wMjQ1OTQ1NWosIDAuODExNDg5OTErMC43NTI2OTY2N2osIDAuNjI1NjgxODUrMC45NTk1MDkzN2o7IDAuNjc5ODU5MjMrMC4xMTQxOTE4N2osIDAuNTAxMzE3OTArMC4xMzA2NzkyOGosIDAuMTAzMzAxNjErMC44MzUzMjcyN2o7IDAuNzEwODU3NDcrMC44NjE5OTc2NWosIDAuNjg5MDIwNDgrMC41MDg4NjMwMmosIDAuNTI3Mjk0NjMrMC41OTc0MjA4aiBd)

**Explanation**

```
t       % Implicitly grab input and duplicate
Zy      % Compute the size of the input. Yields [rows, columns]
t:      % Compute an array from [1...rows]
tY@     % Duplicate this array and compute all permutations (these are the columns)
X]      % Convert row/column to linear indices into the input matrix
)       % Index into the input matrix where each combination is a row
!p      % Take the product of each row
s       % Sum the result and implicitly display
```

Comment: Very impressive.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby 2.4.0, <s>59</s> 61 bytes

Recursive Laplace expansion:

```ruby
f=->a{a.pop&.map{|n|n*f[a.map{|r|r.rotate![0..-2]}]}&.sum||1}
```

Less golfed:

```ruby
f=->a{
  # Pop a row off of a
  a.pop&.map{ |n|
    # For each element of that row, multiply by the permanent of the minor
    n * f[a.map{ |r| r.rotate![0..-2]}]
  # Add all the results together
  }&.sum ||
  # Short circuit to 1 if we got passed an empty matrix
  1
}
```

Ruby 2.4 is not officially released. On earlier versions, `.sum` will need to be replaced with `.reduce(:+)`, adding 7 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), 73 bytes

```julia
f(a,r=1:size(a,1))=sum([prod([a[i,p[i]] for i=r]) for p=permutations(r)])
```

In newer versions of julia you can drop the `[]` around the comprehensions, but need `using Combinatorics` for the `permutations` function. Works with all Number types in Julia, including `Complex`. `r` is a `UnitRange` object defined as a default function argument, which can depend on previous function arguments.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBasMwDIbvfQof7S0UybZsaZCx9wg5BJZQj7YJTstg7N0zp6WBHqaT0Pfz/5K@rsfULcuguyrX@Dann760aEw9X0@6mfL4qZuuSdXUpLZVw5hVqnNrbt1UT30@XS/dJY3nWWfTmuVjPozfatDjuZ@1q5wxu6eRrew2yv186KZeNwr2LgSJ4PkV9mA9iSd6SadKFcSInkWwoEg2SAjxgYKlwMhUkJAQiLuhnXquIozCJNYVYXFDQd48CNBhFFiRgyK0/EAIzgGGNZkdORvtP/YRgSn6uAoDisSwbR9YwN4PI2AODuyWXAzFh3UpkugtrMGqre5/@30flj8)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 82 bytes

```
f=a=>a[0]?a.reduce((t,b,i)=>t+b[0]*f(a.filter((_,j)=>i-j).map(c=>c.slice(1))),0):1
```

Works with the empty matrix too, of course.

Comment: @ETHproductions I never learn...

Comment: Exactly my code, just published 14 hours before, I'll try to add complex numbers

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 54 bytes

```
Coefficient[Times@@(#.(v=x~Array~Length@#)),Times@@v]&
```

Now that the empty matrices are no longer considered, this solution is valid. It originates from the [MathWorld page on permanents](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permanent.html).

Comment: @alephalpha That's a neat idea to use the rows to identify coefficients but wouldn't it break if the rows were not unique?

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 44 bytes

```
p(m)=if(#m,sum(n=1,#m,m[1,n]*p(m[^1,^n])),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVTbjhNHEP2V0ebFJsOq7l2FRd55iPIBi5EWCGQlbFlkecjXb0739IAteWxXV9W5VPXt8fvT66@3l5fb4XJ8@/Tl8Ntl/ffH5XB9yyu@Xh54vZ5fIfjwgdcP1/PxuPLx5fF2@/bf4bK8/mO5fX@6Ph/u3l3f3B1P269e6rQH/vrx/Cty6KFfsffXu@O6PDw8rsvHdfl0Wj6vy9/r8uW0fF2Xf9bl6bwufz4@H/ohuteIamT5O92TmJe5v3q3LnSfzJZVjEBziYpoWyDEIzkdgfJyKkXg1AOt0ksUAeRycc4MJ1ZuRT2ghGOSW4BJlTh6j1RXaTJLNab0Zq0HgqtaTFSRRbLBdcoMJZk9kFwWvblXMyG0OA@GqY3EyTpDT@JmtaWQFotEh4W4NObZpNyp1YDlxVQUtcGiBrxu0WF5FOTZEqylgWSXBM/WkD1FJBA37i08BX/7VkgTOtjg1/A0stnaDfpQSRcXRMEvZgsiKKUdkyFbSnknGMxh@OghKc@mU5MopMtWzDpgmV1QIeBbh0VAZygwmYuoqHZ5VeCA055BFaY8dMchtxZ7DwiUg4lKCLHZRtFbOsswJDBVQMVbhkCRiDEmmq0lUE6xVBUO5vAjycVmRgC854CrwbBzVysc45A2eIR7k33iABAjWKNHSxZL3VAxXtbGMBh6seospRC7u9UJCkGF1F0rjc6we95IW7U9IGMvhoeupuFTEtG0zr3LHqAEtjOQDJQcYw/EGxydmwPWsLCXEiYSeDYXhDt67RkEB7ARs3lzKyihg0cmYROnJDiErjEGiFrkrhXytbAXQytLkNfdD@WQ4Yc5oOuUyrAqvk1clhpq7QkoWmjZA1gcHNsNNCjNNGgo4b07G0gpVOuzgFsBK6T7vBk2eJRiXBgmOW@G6n7SAIUdKNw582bIPghQpWdgc7h@loKx1nzsYOHfpDk9zsSEYr0UOQq33AOmVeVjSBSC7ldfq0rIKMPyJoqD@yyIAmefBTdvkA0Z5/Px5X8)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 50 bytes

```
m->polcoef(vecprod([x^2^i|i<-[0..#m-1]]*m),2^#m-1)
```

Based on [@miles's Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96860/9288).

According to [Wolfram MatheWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permanent.html), the permanent of a matrix \$A = (a_{ij})\$ is the coefficient of \$x_1 \cdots x_n\$ in the polynomial \$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j\$. This is exactly what miles's answer does.

But in PARI/GP there isn't an easy way to generate an arbitrary number of new variables. So instead of a list variables \$[x_1, \dots, x_n]\$, I use the \$2^i\$'th powers of a single variable \$x\$, i.e., \$[x^1, \dots, x^{2^{n-1}}]\$, and take the coefficient of \$x^1 \cdots x^{2^{n-1}} = x^{2^n-1}\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVTbbhtHDP2Vhfsip5LB@5B1mvc8FP0AVwYcx0kNRLZgOEUL9N/dM7OzjQRoJXFIngs557uXx8PX89v54eW0/Pp2Onw4P3@7f374svvr4f788vx5d/P3rdw@/vv4/nBDV1c/nQ58PL47Xe7ltn@/fLs7n7/9szsthw/L@eXx6XV38fHpl4vL6/XXeXfavu4ufv/@@iOy6y0R/RH@4@nicr/c3Nztl0/75f56@bxfHvbLl@vl6375c788HvfLb3evu36IrjSiGln@TFck5mXu7z7uF7pKZssqRqC5REW0NRDikZyOQHk5lSJw3QOt0ksUAeRycc4MJ1ZuRT2ghGOSa4BJlTh6j1RXaTJLNab0Zq0HgqtaTFSRRbLCdcoMJZk9kFwWvblXMyG0OA6GqY3EyTpDT@JmtaaQFotEh4W4NObZpNyp1YDlxVQUtcKiBrxu0WF5FORZE6ylgWSXBM/WkD1FJBA37i08BX/7WkgTOtjg1/A0stnaDfpQSRcXRMEvZgsiKKUdkyFbSnkjGMxh@OghKc@mU5MopMtazDpgmV1QIeBbh0VAZygwmYuoqHZ5VeCA05ZBFaY8dMchtxZbDwiUg4lKCLHZStFbOsswJDBVQMVrhkCRiDEmmq0lUE6xVBUO5vAjycVmRgC854CrwbBzUysc45A2eIR7k23iABAjWKNHSxZLXVExXtbGMBh6seospRC7u9UJCkGF1E0rjc6we95IW7UtIGMvhoeupuFTEtG0zr3LHqAEtjOQDJQcYw/EGxydmwPWsLCXEiYSeDYXhDt67RkEB7ARs3lzKyihg0cmYROnJDiErjEGiFrkphXytbAXQytLkNfND@WQ4Yc5oOuUyrAqvk5clhpqbQkoWmjZA1gcHNsMNCjNNGgo4b05G0gpVOuzgFsBK6TbvBk2eJRiXBgmOW@G6n7SAIUdKNw582bIPghQpWdgc7j@LwVjrfnYwcK/SXN6nIkJxXopchRuuQVMq8rHkCgE3a6@VpWQUYblTRQHt1kQBc4@C27eIBsyjsfLt/8A)