# Print the Greek alphabet!

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

Fairly obviously, you have to print the Greek alphabet. But I thought I'd make it slightly more interesting, so there's a twist: when your program is ran with an argument (anything), it should output the Greek alphabet in lowercase.

**Information**

1. Greek alphabet (Capitals):  `ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ`
2. Greek alphabet (Lowercase): `αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω`

---

### Rules/Requirements

- Each submission must be a full program.
- Builtins to print the Greek alphabet are not permitted
- Standard loopholes apply
- You must print exactly what is shown.

### Scoring

Programs are scored according to bytes. If you are using a character set different to UTF-8 please specify. Try to get the least bytes out of everyone, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)!

### Test cases

```
./program
==> ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ

./program 1
==> αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω

./program 'lower'
==> αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω

./program 123897883421
==> αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω

./program ""
==> αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω

greek();
==> ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ

greek("blah");
==> αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω

greek(123);
==> αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω
```

### Submissions

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 97049; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 53406; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does an empty string count as having an argument or having no argument? Please use the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback before posting a challenge on the main site.

Comment: @Mego That counts as an argument.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/96950/41024).

Comment: Will the argument be always one argument, or can there be two or more arguments?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer In the test cases it's just one, so I guess there will only ever be one.

Comment: @GeorgeGibson Well, that would be convenient for my Python submission.

Comment: Can `nil`, `null`, `undefined`, etc. be passed as an argument?

Comment: [Hebrew alphabet](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/output-the-hebrew-alphabet), Greek alphabet. Next stop: Chinese alphabet?

Comment: Kritixi approves the challenge.

Comment: @Glorfindel [It's not an alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Written_Chinese). Though technically, [Hebrew isn't either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjad#Impure_abjads). ;)

Comment: If there is no argument passed at all, do I output the uppercase alphabet?

Comment: @TheBitByte Yes

Comment: Edit this into your question, and let everybody who's already answered know this

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your last three test cases; they look like function calls, yet the rules specifically ask for a full program.

Comment: So much for all the languages I grew up with.  That's going to be a lot of PSETs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

Uses [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.

```
24Ý17K913+çJDl¹s
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MjTDnTE3SzkxMyvDp0pEbMK5cw&input=)

**Explanation**

```
24Ý               # push range [0 ... 24]
   17K            # remove 17
      913+        # add 913 to each
          ç       # convert from code point
           J      # join to string
            Dl    # push a lowercase copy
              ¹   # push the input
               s  # swap the top 2 elements of the stack
                  # implicitly display the top of the stack
```

Comment: Did you mean `[0 ... 23]` or `[0, 24)` instead of `[0 ... 24]` or `[0, 24]`?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer There is one other character between the range of greek alphabet code points.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Oh right, I was really confused. I am working it in another language, which I won't tell here. I'm commited to that right now.

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, 56 bytes

Full program. I don't think a function/lambda answer will be shorter than this for this language.

Dangit, sigma `ς`. This is why we can't have nice things. And you too, (unrenderable character that serves as a placeholder for "uppercase" `ς`)

```
print *($*[0]?([*?α..?ω]-[?ς]):[*?Α..?Ρ,*?Σ..?Ω])
```

Comment: I think this prints an extra lowercase sigma, ς

Comment: This now prints an extra U+03A2.

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 16 bytes

```
25,H-ea'α'Α?f+
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=MjUsSC1lYSfOsSfOkT9mKw&input=)

```
25,H-         e# 0 to 24 excluding 17.
ea'α'Α?       e# If the argument list is truthy (non-empty), alpha, otherwise Alpha.
f+            e# Return characters with each number added to the character code.
```

Comment: Can you add a explanation please?

Comment: @XiKuuKy I don't think so :/

Comment: @RGS Edited. :/

Comment: @jimmy23013 nice one :-P I simply scrolled through this answer and thought I'd comment if for posterity. Didn't think you would come and edit your answer! +1

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>89</s> <s>83</s> 81 bytes

```
(...a)=>String.fromCharCode(...[...Array(24)].map((_,i)=>i*1.06+913+32*a.length))
```

If a character array is acceptable, then for <s>82</s> <s>80</s> 78 bytes:

```
(...a)=>[...Array(24)].map((_,i)=>String.fromCharCode(i*1.06+913+32*a.length))
```

Edit: Saved a bunch of bytes thanks to @ETHproductions.

Comment: Using `String.fromCharCode(...array)` is again shorter: `(...a)=>String.fromCharCode(...[...Array(24)].map((_,i)=>i+(i>16)+913+32*!!a.length))`

Comment: And since `String.fromCharCode` floors, you can save another two bytes like so: `(...a)=>String.fromCharCode(...[...Array(24)].map((_,i)=>i*1.06+913+32*!!a.length))`

Comment: @ETHproductions I can't believe I forgot to use `String.fromCharCode(...)` but I like that `i*1.06` trick! Sadly comprehensions are a byte longer this time as far as I can tell.

Comment: I managed to get it down to `(...a)=>String.fromCharCode(...[for(_ of Array(i=24))i++*42/41+889+32*!!a.length])` (82).

Comment: You can remove the `!!`, as there will only be zero or one args.

Comment: Using a single argument `a`, the expression `1/a+a` should give truthy for every value of a except `undefined`. So `a=>String.fromCharCode(...[...Array(24)].map((_,i)=>i*1.06+(1/a+a?945:913)))`

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, <s>114</s> 108 bytes

```
import System.Environment
q[a,b]=[a..b]
f[]=q"ΑΡ"++q"ΣΩ"
f _=q"αρ"++q"σω"
main=f<$>getArgs>>=putStr
```

Thanks to @xnor for saving 6 bytes

This might win in the category of longest imports if nothing else…

Comment: It looks like it's worth defining `q[a,b]=[a..b]` to use 4 times.

Comment: `getArgs>>=putStr.f` is shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>104</s> <s>99</s> 92 bytes

```
g=function(x)for(i in sprintf("'\\u%04X'",913:937+32*!missing(x))[-18])cat(eval(parse(t=i)))
```

Golfing down on the second version I had previously. Work the same way as  previous version.

Thanks to @JDL for shaving off 7 bytes!

**Old versions at 104 bytes:**

I have two different solutions with the same byte count:

```
f=function(x){a="ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ";cat(if(missing(x))a else tolower(a))}
```

Or:

```
g=function(x)for(i in sprintf("'\\u%04X'",if(missing(x))913:937 else 945:969)[-18])cat(eval(parse(t=i)))
```

Explanations:

```r
#First one is trivial
f=function(x){
     a="ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ" #String to print
     #If argument missing, print uppercase else lowercase 
     cat(if(missing(x))a else tolower(a)) 
     }
#Second one more interesting:
g=function(x)
     #Create escaped unicode strings (i. e. "'\\u03B1'" etc.), loop over them...
     for(i in sprintf("'\\u%04X'",if(missing(x))913:937 else 945:969)[-18])
          #...eval the strings
          cat(eval(parse(t=i)))
```

Usage:

```
> f()
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ
> g()
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ
> f(1)
αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω
> g(1)
αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω
> f("a")
αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω
> g("a")
αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω
```

For some reasons, it doesn't work on R-Fiddle (it changes `"` to `'` by default which makes the code throw an error) but you can try it out on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/sbQqNV).

Comment: Replace `+'if'(missing(x),0,32)` with `+32*!missing(x)`?

Comment: @JDL Thanks! Don't know why I didn't think of that one.

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, <s>55</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
24Fi16>913s.C)sz!hAl
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=24Fi16%3E913s.C%29sz%21hAl&input=h)

```
24F          )       -   for i in range(24):
   i16>              -       i > 16
       913s          -      sum(i, ^, 913)
           .C        -     chr(^)
              s      -  sum(^) - created uppercase alphabet
                  Al - [len, lower, upper][V](^)
                 h   -  V + 1
               z!    -   not input()
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes

```python
import sys
x=25
while x:print(end=chr(906-x+32*len(sys.argv))[:x^8]);x-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKG4spirwtbIlKs8IzMnVaHCqqAoM69EIzUvxTY5o0jD0sBMt0Lb2EgrJzVPA6hWL7EovUxTM9qqIs4iVtO6QtfW8P9/AA)

This still may not be as low as it can go!

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 62 bytes

```
 "$ù"E"ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ"@ƒ.X
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=ICIkw7kiRSLOkc6SzpPOlM6VzpbOl86YzpnOms6bzpzOnc6ezp_OoM6hzqPOpM6lzqbOp86ozqkiQMaSLlg&input=)

Because some of the uppercase Greek alphabet is not present in CP437, this solution is encoded in UTF-8 and scored accordingly. Here is a hexdump (reversible with `xxd -r`):

```
00000000: 2022 24c3 b922 4522 ce91 ce92 ce93 ce94   "$.."E"........
00000010: ce95 ce96 ce97 ce98 ce99 ce9a ce9b ce9c  ................
00000020: ce9d ce9e ce9f cea0 cea1 cea3 cea4 cea5  ................
00000030: cea6 cea7 cea8 cea9 2240 c692 2e58 0a    ........"@...X.
```

Explanation:

```
 "$ù"E"ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ"@ƒ.X
<space>                               push the number of items present on the stack
 `$ù`E                                select `ù` (lowercase) if the number of items is not 0, else `$` (stringify - does nothing to a string)
      "ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ"      push the uppercase Greek alphabet
                                @ƒ    call the selected function
                                  .   print
                                   X  discard
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>80</s> <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```
import sys;a='ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ';print([a,a.lower()][-len(sys.argv)])
```

Old version:

```
import sys;a='ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ';print([a,a.lower()][len(sys.argv)-1])
```

Older version:

```
import sys;a='ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ';print(a.lower()if len(sys.argv)>1else a)
```

Comment: `[a,a.lower()][len(sys.argv)-1]` because the comments state that there will only ever be one argument.

Comment: You can shave one more byte with `[a.lower(),a][-len(sys.argv)]`.

Comment: What encoding are you using that this is 76 bytes?

Comment: [I count 100 bytes.](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#import%20sys%3Ba%3D%27%CE%91%CE%92%CE%93%CE%94%CE%95%CE%96%CE%97%CE%98%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%9B%CE%9C%CE%9D%CE%9E%CE%9F%CE%A0%CE%A1%CE%A3%CE%A4%CE%A5%CE%A6%CE%A7%CE%A8%CE%A9%27%3Bprint%28%5Ba%2Ca.lower%28%29%5D%5B-len%28sys.argv%29%5D%29)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>21</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
;Ckzir)c+816+32*NÊ
```

[Test it (no input)](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O0NremlyKWMrODE2KzMyKk7K)
[Test it (empty string input)](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O0NremlyKWMrODE2KzMyKk7K&input=IiI)

```
;Ckzir)c+816+32*NÊ     :Implicit input (or not)
;C                     :Lowercase alphabet.
  k                    :Remove
   zir                 :  "z" prepended with "r"
      )                :End remove
       c+              :Map charcodes and add
         816+32*       :  816 plus 32 multiplied by
                N      :   Array of all inputs
                 Ê     :   Length (0 if no input, 1 if a single input)
```

Comment: [17 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=MjVvZDkxMytIKk7KIGbPyTc). Took me a bit to get under 18

Comment: Nicely done, @Jacob :) I think that's sufficiently different from mine to warrant posting it yourself.

Comment: Ok will do. BTW you forgot to update the explanation

Comment: You can change 32 to H

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 81 bytes

```powershell
'ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ'|%('*wer','*per')[!$args.Count]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLZSsNAFIbv8xRjmTpJaYW0glEQBB9DRKROVBiTtGlQaAuK@6X7vuF@6b7rG/zzSHEaNYrghWQuZuCc///OcM7x3FFe9oe4ECG1SSephgwLWMQSlrGCVaxhHRvYxBa2sYNd7GEfBzjEEY5xglOc4ZzV0jrLKAzLsoynHqOnifaXB/2WbjdwKr1hXdO6dI2ok9X/T88S5rhE8YIR7lR8ZsSkC1ziCte4wS3ucI8HPOIJz3jBK97kuJyQk3JKTssZOSvn5LwimUnMTDR6lag@M/MFq73NsgqteTMZKZGbOoEQhmaQGkmTagSifMzjxQofUNmvZqt9oH1alB629Tic46VfI/lARJgy9wPRcDZTO4rWo5sLn/@h@q73Q5@i@qcoV@Sl@HNGR@yNXSmtHr4D)

Comment: 78 bytes using [`'ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ'|% "*$('pw'[$args.Count])er"`](https://tio.run/##pZLZSsNAFIbv5ymGMHUSaYW0glEQBB9DRKROVRiTNmmo0BYU90uXuq@4X7rv@gb/PFJMo0YRvJDMxbk45/@/czhnik5FuN6IkDJgBdpNqwHHIpawjBU0sIo1rGMDm9jCNnawiz3s4wCHOMIxTnCKM5zzWopqrUznxQrvY4PusNfW6/h2ud8QrhbUCenRCQ1fWv8/Ok257dCQ6Y8Ju@xxIyZd4BJXuMYNbnGHezzgEU94xgte8aYm1KSaUtNqRs2qOTWvFkKSmcTMZXNRifpzM5uzOjssK9eeNZORErmZ7UtpEIPWaIpWIxAT40WRL4uhsPq17PAzsAESlUcLepzOiNKvk3wgIowrPF82nS2sEGXrURTSE3@ovvv90GtM/xRl8qIUD2d0xd7YpZF68A4 "PowerShell – Try It Online") This assumes there will ever be one or no arguments passed

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 68 bytes

```c
j=24;main(i){for(setlocale(6,"");j--;)putwchar(968-1/i*32-j+(j<7));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/L1sjEOjcxM08jU7M6Lb9Iozi1JCc/OTEnVcNMR0lJ0zpLV9das6C0pDw5I7FIw9LMQtdQP1PL2Eg3S1sjy8ZcU9O69v///4YA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s><sup><sup>96</sup> 53 <sub>51</sub></sup></s> 58 bytes

```r
cat(intToUtf8((913:937)[-18]+32*!!length(commandArgs(T))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUJDw9LQ2MrS2FwzWtfQIlbb2EhLUTEnNS@9JEMjOT83NzEvxbEovVgjRBMI/v//DwA)

I tried to make an R answer with command line args, but it's a bit longer(now a lot, lot shorter) than the loop based approach by plannapus. I used some of the tricks in their answer.

A crazy -43 bytes from Dominic Van Essen.

-2 more bytes from Dominic Van Essen.

+7 bytes after removing `ς`

Comment: Cool to see command-line args in action in R: we don't use them often (so I'm not very good with them...)!  There are still a couple of golfing tricks you can use: 1. you can skip the ```{}``` in the function definition if there's only 1 command (like here)...

Comment: 2. you could actually use the function argument, instead of leaving it out & wasting bytes by calling ```missing``` ([like this](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9U2rTQvuSQzP0@jQjMzryQkP7QkzULD0tDYytLYXNvYSEuxQpMrObFEI1UjJzUvvSRDIzk/NzcxL8WxKL1YI0RT09bWQFPz/38A))...

Comment: and 3. once you've done that, you'll probably want to remove the function altogether & incorporate it into the main expression ([like this](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzULD0tDYytLYXNvYSEsjJzUvvSRDIzk/NzcxL8WxKL1YI0RT085AU1Pz/38A))...

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzULD0tDYytLYXNvYSEtRMSc1L70kQyM5Pzc3MS/FsSi9WCNEEwj@//@fCAA) with ```!!``` instead of ```(>0)```

Comment: I'm afraid I've just noticed (from a comment in the answer above) that the Greek alphabet doesn't seem to be contiguous in Utf8-encoding!  You need to remove the 'ς' character.  This unfortunately brings it back up to [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUJDw9LQ2MrS2FwzWtfQIlbb2EhLUTEnNS@9JEMjOT83NzEvxbEovVgjRBMI/v//DwA)...

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 42 bytes

```julia
print.(['Α':'Ρ';'Σ':'Ω'].+32(ARGS>[]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69ETyNa/dxEdSv1cwvVrdXPLQaxVqrH6mkbG2k4BrkH20XHamr@V1YIKapUSExJycxLV0jMU0gsSi/NTc0rUUhKzckvV/wPAA)

-1 byte thanks to MarcMush: use `ARGS>[]` instead of `ARGS==[]`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 84 Bytes

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4170b41daca83e8496a985157cd8952062004dc7)

```php
<?=($argc<2?trim:mb_strtolower)("ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ");
```

## PHP, 87 Bytes

```php
$s="ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ";echo$argc>1?mb_strtolower($s):$s;
```

Comment: [gotcha](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108196#108196). You seem somehow absent. `$argc>1` is 8 bytes shorter than `isset($argv[1])` and doesn´t need a blank.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 82 bytes

```
print((('Α'to'Ρ')++('Σ'to'Ω')).mkString.map(& =>if(args.size<1)&else&toLower))
```

Ungolfed:

```
print((('Α'to'Ρ')++('Σ'to'Ω')).mkString.map(s=>if(args.size==0)s else s.toLower))
```

Sadly, `(('Α'to'Ρ')++('Σ'to'Ω'))` is a `Vector[Char]`, which would be printed as `Vector('Α', 'Β', ...`, so it has to be converted to a string with `mkString`.The argument to `map` is called `&` to save spaces between `&else`, `else&` and `& toLower`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
,⁸Ea32µ24R%18T+912+µỌ
```

A full program

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=LOKBuEVhMzLCtTI1UiUxOFQrOTEyK8K14buM&input=)** - note once run with an argument a refresh will be required to run with no argument.

#### How?

```
,⁸Ea32µ24R%18T+912+µỌ - Main link
,⁸                    - pair (,) with left argument (defaults: left=0, ⁸=[])
                            no argument: [0,[]]
                               argument: [argument,argument]
  E                   - all items equal? -> no argument: 0; argument: 1
   a32                - and 32           -> no argument: 0; argument: 32
      µ               - monadic chain separation
       24R            - range(25)        -> [  1,  2,  3,..., 17, 18, 19,..., 25]
          %18         - mod 18           -> [  1,  1,  1,...,  1,  0,  1,...,  1]
             T        - truthy indices   -> [  1,  2,  3,..., 17,     19,..., 25]
              +912    - add 912          -> [913,914,915,...,929,    931,...,937]
                  +   - add the 0 or 32 (lowercase letters are 32 code points higher)
                   µ  - monadic chain separation
                    Ọ - cast to ordinals
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 68 bytes

```
(($a=-join([char[]](913..929+931..937))).toLower(),$a)[!$args.count]
```

ASCII-only, but outputs in UTF-16. Constructs a `char`-array of the appropriate characters, `-join`s it together into a string, stores it into `$a`. Then, uses `!$args.count` as an index into the tuple, to output either `$a` if no arguments are present, or `$a.ToLower()` if there is at least one argument.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\print-the-greek-alphabet.ps1
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\print-the-greek-alphabet.ps1 ''
αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 80 bytes

```python
import sys;print(''.join(chr(x+881+len(sys.argv)*32)for x in range(25)if x!=17))
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 174 bytes

Lazy implementation, can probably golf it a lot

```
class P{static void main(string[] a){System.Console.Write(a.Length>0?"αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω":"ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ");}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 73

```
 puts [expr $argc>0?"αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω":"ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ"]
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMT2N4TEkxRGpZb1E)

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 24 bytes

```
l?#α:#Α|# 9->[.!@ 1+];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/x1753EYr5XMTa5QVLHXtovUUHRQMtWOt////bwgA)

#### Explanation:

```
l?#α:#Α|# 9->[.!@ 1+];  Implicit input of args to stack
l                       Push length of stack
 ?                      If last item (length) is != 0..
  #α                    ..Push lowercase alpha
    :                   else
     #Α                 ..Push uppercase alpha
       |                endif
        #<space>        Push 32 (ordinal of a space)
          9-            Subtract 9 (23)
            >           Move last item to start of stack
             [......]   Do-While loop, will run 24 times
              .         Duplicate last item
               !@       Print without popping
                  1     Push 1
                   +    Pop last 2 items (1 and duplicate) and push sum
                     ;  Suppress implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 55 bytes

```
.+
αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω
^$
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##BcE5EsFgAIbh/j9HOjOOlBmFQqMwDsAQpLTEmljGEkpZxO4G73ek3/M0qs1avWJtuWS4kpCSkXOj4M6DJy/efPjyU0ttddSVp576Gsg3rmMYMmLMhIApM@YsWLIiJGLNhi079hw4ciLmzMXaPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 26 bytes

The normal way to pass multiple arguments to APL programs is through a lists. So this program prompts for such a list, which may have 0 or 1 arguments.

```apl
'ς΢'~⍨⍳'Ω'×~≢⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L/6@aZzi9TrHvWueNS7Wf3cSvXD0@sedS561DcVJP9fAQwKuIB8r2B/P/XoWHUuDDGlpJzEDCVsMoZGxrHqAA)

`⎕` prompt for argument list

`≢` tally the number of arguments (0 or 1)

`~` negate that (1 or 0)

`'Ω'×` "multiply" Omega by that (1 keeps uppercase, 0 folds to lowercase)

`⍳` All characters from `Α`–`Ω` or `α`–`ω` respectively

`'ς΢'~⍨` remove lowercase and "uppercase" final sigmas

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 78 bytes

```
import sys;a=(len(sys.argv)-1)<<5;print(''.join(map(chr,range(a+913,a+938))))
```

### Explanation

`a` is an offset, 32 when an argument is given to use the lowercase range. 913 to 937 is the range of unicode values for the uppercase greek alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoMwEAXQfU7xdyZUCql1oeBJigtpow60kzATBE8/0rd75ax75s6MfiVLhZ7qdBqePWj9577IdrziOCN9NWGInVuzgEAMWXhLXlu9PfowOqAIcfXvXTyFNvFnappgZvEC), 88 bytes

```
import sys
s=945 if sys.argv[1:] else 913
for i in range(s,s+25):
  print(chr(i),end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 74 bytes

This an improvement to @HackerBoss es' answer (I don't have enough reputation to comment).

```python
import sys;a=len(sys.argv)-1<<5;print(*map(chr,range(a+913,a+938)),sep='')
```

Subtraction has higher precedence than bit shift, so no need for parentheses, we save 2 bytes. Also instead of using `''.join()` we unpack the `map()` and set `print()`'s default seperator to an empty string to omit the spaces, that saves 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 45 bytes

```sh
A=({Α..Ω})
((#))&&A=${(L)A}
tr -d \ -z<<<$A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/f0Vaj@txEPb1zK2s1uTQ0lDU11dQcbVWqNXw0HWu5SooUdFMUYhR0q2xsbFQc//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 134 bytes

```rust
fn main(){let mut s:String=('α'..'ϊ').collect();s.remove(34);print!("{}",if std::env::args().nth(1)==None{s.to_uppercase()}else{s})}
```

[Try it on the Rust Playground!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=fn%20main()%7Blet%20mut%20s%3AString%3D(%27%CE%B1%27..%27%CF%8A%27).collect()%3Bs.remove(34)%3Bprint!(%22%7B%7D%22%2Cif%20std%3A%3Aenv%3A%3Aargs().nth(1)%3D%3DNone%7Bs.to_uppercase()%7Delse%7Bs%7D)%7D)

ungolfed:

```rust
fn main() {                                    //full program
    let mut s: String = ('α'..'ϊ').collect();  //create a range of chars from 'α'(inclusive) to 'ϊ' (exclusive) and collect into string
    s.remove(34);                              //remove 'ς'
    print!(                                    //print
        "{}",                                  //with default formatting
        if std::env::args().nth(1) == None {   //if the 2nd arg doesn't exist (first is filename)
            s.to_uppercase()                   // uppercase string then return
        } else {                               // else
            s                                  // return unmodified string
        }
    )
}
```

This doesn't work on tio for some reason so this is on the playground, where you can't add input- turn the `==` to a `!=` to test lowercase version.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 81 Bytes

```python
lambda*x,b="αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω":(b.upper(),b)[x>()]
```

-6 from TheThonnu for using `*`.
-2 from TheThonnu for telling me that the brackets are unneeded.
-28 from mousetail for using an uppercasing function.
-7 from TheThonnu for assigning the greek letters to a variable.

Comment: [Fails for falsy arguments, like `""` and `0`](https://tio.run/##Nce5rgFhGIDh3lXIX83fnUQnmVtwBZoRhIQZEQUdsZf2nSP2EsdyrHfwfpc0Kk/3pHKZmGP73KgZdBNWMhS2vFkz4NgRv5H1WnZYsefAkT9OnLlw5Z8bdx48efGWvBSkKCUpS0WqUpO60k5a0aBJizYduvToM2DIiDETpsz4Zc6CJSvWbNiyU24qHbczRtRQSmvPNz9aux8)

Comment: You can fix it and save a few bytes: [118 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tcc5DkFRGIDR3irkVu@qJDqJnWieiJDwiCjoiLk0z1PMpXlmB9@/pKeS6M5JZFLhuOWxQz6/HTVjgaDpSnuNtNO0goodew4cOXHmwpUbdx48efHmI1nJSV4KUpSSlKUiVaXjSUWNOg2atGjToUuPPgOGjBgzYcqMOQuWrFizYavsRDJipYyQoZTWjl/cf9ba/gI)

Comment: @TheThonnu what does the asterik do?

Comment: It allows the function to take any number of arguments (including no arguments), and then wraps it all into a tuple, `x`.

Comment: Also, the parentheses are unnecessary, since `and` has a higher precedence than `or`: [116 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tcc3CsJgGIDh3VPIPxknwU3wJi4REQVNQnDQTbGP9t6wj/auN3i/I8VJcHseK5OKmYbfiQZDTkJPhiO6Nx1Iu3Ujotix58CRE2cuXLlx58GTF28@kpWc5KUgRSlJWSpSVaatqFGnQZMWbTp06dFnwJARYyZMmTFnwZIVazZslWPZcSPliXqU0jTXL74/a5rzBQ)

Comment: [88 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwdI0BVuFmKWlJWm6FjcjchJzk1IStSqsNJKsbJXObTy36dzmc1vObT237dz2czvO7Ty369zuc3vO7T2379z-8w3nG883n28533q-7Xz7-Y7znUo6FQqJeSkKSQr5RQpJeqUFBalFGpqa0YaxEPO3FRRl5pVopAHFuGBMQ01NiOSCBRAaAA) Note that high Unicode values cost multiple bytes

Comment: @mousetail an error occurs.

Comment: The link gives the output though, there is no error in python 3.10

Comment: @mousetail maybe because I’m using my phone?

Comment: Try using TIO or ATO, it's much easier

Comment: [81 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwdI0BVuFmKWlJWm6FjcDcxJzk1IStSp0kmyVzm08t-nc5nNbzm09t-3c9nM7zu08t-vc7nN7zu09t-_c_vMN5xvPN59vOd96vu18-_mO851KVhpJeqUFBalFGpo6SZrRFXYamrEQg7cVFGXmlWikaWhqcsGYhpqaEMkFCyA0AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, <s>17 16 15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
24Ė17Ɗ913+C¤?L
```

-1 thanks to @TheThonnu :), saved 1 extra by using different method.

Explanation:

```
24Ė              # range [0, 24]
   17Ɗ           # remove index 17
      913+       # add 913 to each
          C      # convert to character array
           ¤?    # if there is input:
             L   #   convert to lowercase (vectorizes)
                 # J flag joins character array
```

Thunno 2 isn't on ATO yet, but I have confirmed that this works on my machine for both the input and no input versions.

Comment: Not at my computer right now, but would `¤?kj+` work in place of `kj¤l×+`? Also, doesn't the `B` flag give a string not a character array, so the `J` flag isn't necessary?

Comment: @TheThonnu Thanks, it does work! Not sure why it wasn't working for me earlier

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 53 bytes

```
{say @*ARGS??.lc!!$_}([~] flat 'Α'..'Ρ','Σ'..'Ω')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@6OLFSwUHLMcg92N5eLydZUVElvlYjui5WIS0nsURB/dxEdT099XML1XXUzy0GM1eqa/7/DwA)

- `[~] flat 'Α'..'Ρ','Σ'..'Ω'` constructs the uppercase Greek alphabet.
- `{ say @*ARGS ?? .lc !! $_ }` is an anonymous function which receives the uppercase alphabet as an argument.  If there are any command-line arguments, the alphabet is lowercased and printed, otherwise it is printed as-is.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
25od913+H*NÊ fÏÉ7
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=MjVvZDkxMytIKk7KIGbPyTc)

#### Explanation

```
25o                 map each n in range [0, 25):
   d                  convert the following codepoint to a character:
    913                 n + 913
       +H*NÊ            + (number of inputs * 32)
             fÏ     keep elements where the following is truthy:
               É7     subtract 17 from the index 
                      (if index is 17, this will be 0 = falsy)
-P                  P flag joins the array to a string
```

The cool part of this is `fÏÉ7`: `É7` transforms to `-17` by using the shortcut for `-1` (i.e. decrement). The regular way of doing this would be something like `fÏ¶17` which is one byte longer.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 108 [bytes](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7)

```
#coding=iso-8859-7
import sys;print'αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω'if~-len(sys.argv)else'ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ'
```

Terribly golfed, maybe :(

And no, I can't use `A.lower()`.

Thanks to 13285 (alexwlchan) for -11 bytes.

Comment: This is the most golfed version I can do.

Comment: You can save 8 bytes by skipping the assignment to `A,a`, and just using those strings directly in the `print`.

Comment: @alexwlchan Right, I just didn't think of it... still terribly golfed, though.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 91 bytes

```
Print@{#&,ToLowerCase}[[Length@$ScriptCommandLine]][""<>"Α"~CharacterRange~"Ω"~Drop~{18}]
```

Script. Just takes the character range from `Α` to `Ω`, removes U+03A2/`ς`, either converts to lowercase or doesn't, and prints.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 39 + 3 (`-C2` flag) = <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
 perl -C2 -E 'say map{chr$_+954-!@ARGV*32}-9..7,9..15'
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 95 bytes

95 bytes, but only 71 characters. [Byte counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%28...a%29%3D%3E%27%CE%91%CE%92%CE%93%CE%94%CE%95%CE%96%CE%97%CE%98%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%9B%CE%9C%CE%9D%CE%9E%CE%9F%CE%A0%CE%A1%CE%A3%CE%A4%CE%A5%CE%A6%CE%A7%CE%A8%CE%A9%27%5B%60to%24%7Ba.length%3F%27Low%27%3A%27Upp%27%7DerCase%60%5D%28%29). Using @Neil s way to determine if arguments are passed.

```
(...a)=>'ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ'[`to${a.length?'Low':'Upp'}erCase`]()
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
C:913+32*#g+Y,24RM17
```

This is a memorable day. Pip has <s>tied</s> beaten Jelly!<sup>1</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup> And lost to two other golflangs, but whatever.</sub>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@@9sZWlorG1spKWcrh2pY2Qa5Gto/v///@L83NT4xKL00tzUvJL4jNSiVAA)

#### Explanation

```
             ,25      Numbers 0 through 24
                RM17  Remove 17 (ς)
            Y         Yank (to get correct order of operations)
  913                 Char code of capital alpha
      32*#g           32 times number of cmdline args (must be 0 or 1)
     +     +          Add everything up
C:                    Convert to characters (using the compute-and-assign metaoperator to
                        lower the precedence of C)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 176 bytes

```
class M{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(a.length>0?"αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω":"ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ");}}
```

## Java 8, 173 bytes

```
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(a.length>0?"αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω":"ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ");}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy Script, <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```
((913..937)-930).each{print((char)(args?it+32:it))}
```

### Edit

Switched from `913..937` and `it==930?:` to `(913..937)-930`

Comment: Can someone explain me, why my answer was downvoted? Did it broke any rules?

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 79 bytes

```php
for($i=944-32*!--$argc;$i++-9&31;$i+=$i%32==1)echo html_entity_decode("&#$i;");
```

generates unicode html entities and decodes them. Run with `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 35 bytes

```matlab
@(x)disp(char((913:937)+32*nargin))
```

Pretty self-explainatory, I think.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 94 bytes

```powershell
param($n)$k=((0..16)+(18..24)|%{[char]($_+913)})-join'';if($n){$k.tolower()}else{$k.toupper()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPUyXbVkPDQE/P0ExTW8PQQk/PyESzRrU6OjkjsShWQyVe29LQWLNWUzcrPzNPXd06Mw2kqVolW68kPwdknoZmbWpOcSpEpLSgACzy////lDQA)

Comment: It looks like omega is missing.  I think the 23 should be 24.

Comment: @Axuary thank you!

Comment: Down to 69 bytes: [`((0..16)+18..24|%{[char]($_+913)})-join''|% "*$('pw'[$args.Count])er"`](https://tio.run/##pZLZTsJQEIbv@xQn5OBpBRoLRIuJiYmPQQgheBBMLdBCMAESjful@77F/dJ91zf4zyPVUrUaE696LuZi5v@/mcycSrnBLbvIDcOhBTJAmo4s96iq1qtENF1V48lWuJnOF3NWRqbZSEpLKG0lNloumYy1wiTUTWVWabA0zVkjtjpUrpu1jMKtkNOWpEFZIu6LygyLWMIyVrCKNaxjA5vYwjZ2sIs97OMAhzjCMU5wijOc44JFCTPLxGXWx7hZs5niky5xhWvc4BZ3uMcDHvGEZ7zgFW94FxNiUkyJaTEjZsWcmBcLLkkLYmZGZz@B@jMtntBTfbqeSMa1YKRAbmrWDUORFNIiYdL0QJSPV3i@xofd6vey3T9As5JXLhVkPx3j1T8n@UR4GIvbdaPj7KIFL9v2Ijds/o/qp98vfYjKX6JYnlf94ZR@3@u7QlLbcbT4Bw "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 48 bytes

```
=CONCAT(UNICHAR(ROW(1:24)*19/18+944-(A1="")*32))
```

Alternatively, you could put the upper case alphabet in B2 and use the formula below for a combined 47 bytes (or more depending on how you account for multiple cells)

```
=IF(A1="",B2,LOWER(B2))
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 27 bytes

```
{⎕UCS(912+32×0∊⍴⍵)+18~⍨⍳25}
```

The program switched to uppercase, when empty array or empty string is received. Unfortunately, it is technically impossible to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 171 bytes

Modified from [@Value Ink's Ruby solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97051/110802).

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8/z8/KSs1uUTBNzEzrzolNU0hF8jQSCxKL7ZyLCpKrIwOLinKzEuP1bQtANIlOXkaGplpYHm9vPw819yCkkpNDfVzG9VL8tXPd6pr6pXkB6eW6KVkpqVpABka6ueb1DVBoj6ZxSUKqTnFqUDVE0Gqzy1Uh4lrawMFFwMFFdTPrYSLaurlZkNs11BSUNLUrP3/HwA)

```scala
object Main{def main(args:Array[String])=println((if(args.nonEmpty)('α'to'ω').toSet.diff(Set('ς')).toList else('Α'to'Ρ').toList++('Σ'to 'Ω').toList).mkString(" "))}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY47DsIwEET7nGKUxrYi5QBIFBR0UEVUiMIQBxkcG9kLEkI0dJQcAVFRchE4UsgHimy1OzP7NGEljawqt9yoFWEqtcUpAnJVoKwPLv06DDDyXh7nGXlt1wsxwMxqwrBNAgdp4FXYm0bSBdqf1Do7Lnd0FODs/WIgB/a5MpGSyxSluS4KXi@cfS5MNOpEB2p5vVEmqIZw6wjvO/tnkSSN8fgZT9aD7OqqZCzviqXltivPY8RC1IlzdK6qLw)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val result = if (args.nonEmpty) ('α' to 'ω').toSet.diff(Set('ς')).toList
                 else ('Α' to 'Ρ').toList ++ ('Σ' to 'Ω').toList
    println(result.mkString(" "))
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### Perl under Windows -- console has no Unicode support -- (42 bytes, including spaces)

This is not my solution, *I am just merely adapting* the Perl solution of **Denis Ibaev** above, to Windows console Perl.

```
perl -E"say map{chr$_+151-!@ARGV*24}1..24"
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ
$ perl -E"say map{chr$_+151-!@ARGV*24}1..24" with one or many arguments
αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρσςτυφχψ
```

The console page code must be Greek of course:

```
chcp 737
```

<sup>NOTE: Just a small idea. On this page I can see that some of the answers use CHARACTERS that seem to been Unicode above 255. Therefore those characters take at least 2 bytes to code (perhaps 4 if one is using a console using 32bits Unicode chars?). Would not it be better if the contest measure was the CHARACTER unit (being Unicode or ASCII or EBCDIC ou whatever) rather than just BYTES? Would not it be simpler and more *unifying* (wonder if this adjectif exists in English, "unificateur" in French)?</sup>

---

Previous code in error:
Does not print lowercase omega.

Corrected code (70 chars) :

```
perl -E"$i=!@ARGV+0;@a=73;pop@a if$i;say map{chr$_+151-$i*24}1..24,@a"
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ
perl -E"$i=!@ARGV+0;@a=73;pop@a if$i;say map{chr$_+151-$i*24}1..24,@a" foo
αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρσςτυφχψω
```

<sup>I know we are not supposed to print the 'end-of-word' sigma form ('ς') but as it is a mispelling error in ancient Greek to use regular sigma ('σ') at the end of a lowercase word, I choose to print it, as the tittle of this puzzle is "Print the Greek alphabet" and that this character is part of it...</sup>