# Print the Greek alphabet in words

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

<sup>This is different from [Print the Greek alphabet!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97049/print-the-greek-alphabet) because it is in words.

This is different from ["Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world) because the output is different and much longer, leading to different techniques.

This is different from [We're no strangers to code golf, you know the rules, and so do I](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/were-no-strangers-to-code-golf-you-know-the-rules-and-so-do-i) because the output is different and much shorter, leading to different techniques.</sup>

Your task is to print this exact text: (the Greek alphabet in words)

```
alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta theta iota kappa lambda mu nu xi omicron pi rho sigma tau upsilon phi chi psi omega
```

<sup>Capitalization does not matter.</sup>

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk How is this a duplicate of that? It's completely different.

Comment: How? It's just printing a static string.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97049/print-the-greek-alphabet)

Comment: You know, had you posted this in the Sandbox, you could've avoid the downvotes by getting told it's a dupe of HW *before* posting it on main...

Comment: Specifically, it could be considered either a dupe of HW or a dupe of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6043/45941

Comment: @mego I don't think it's a great challenge, but I don't think either of those are great dupe targets. Mostly because of length. HW is really short and strangers to code-golf is *really* long (and fairly compressible)

Comment: I agree that this should have been vetted in the Sandbox, I also agree that this ISN'T a dupe. The length of the required output plays a definite role here.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>99</s> 81 bytes

```
from unicodedata import*
i=913
exec"print name(unichr(i+(i>929)))[21:],;i+=1;"*24
```

Thanks to [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for saving 15 bytes!

This uses the `unicodedata.name()` method 
 to get the name of every character. Unfortunately, the code point 930 gives an error for some reason, so that cost a few extra bytes.

This also prints the output in uppercase, which is allowed.

Comment: Nice find with the unicode data. I golfed it to 81: `from unicodedata import*;i=913;exec"print name(unichr(i+(i>929)))[21:],;i+=1;"*24`.

Answer (score 4):

## Scala, 76 bytes

```
print((913 to 937)filter(930!=)map(Character getName _ drop 21)mkString " ")
```

Explanation:

```
print(                  //print...
  (913 to 937)            //build a range of the codepoints for aplha to omega
  filter(930!=)           //filter out that sigma in the middle
  map(                    //map each char...
    Character getName _     //to its full unicode name, e.g. "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA"
    drop 21                 //and drop the first 21 chars, aka "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER "
  )
  mkString " "            //join them with a space
)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Jolf, 7 bytes

```
RΜpΧ΅z♣
```

Replace `♣` with `0x05`, or [try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Us6ccM6nzoV6BQ) Or, use [this link](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=4oKvU-KCr0NSfm1HIjgyIDkyNCAxMTIgOTM1IDkwMSAxMjIgNScgImRwQUhFRQ) to generate the code. (Just click run, the code will be written into the code box.)

### Explanation

```
RΜpΧ΅z♣
 ΜpΧ     map Greek character alphabet
    ΅z    with the toGreek function (converts greek characters to names)
R     ♣  and join that with spaces.
```

Comment: +1 for the `toGreeek` function

Answer (score 3):

## ///, <s>119</s> 117 bytes

```
/1/eta //2/psilon //3/a /alph3b1gamm3delt3e2z11th1iot3kapp3lambd3mu nu xi omicron pi rho sigm3tau u2phi chi psi omega
```

*-2 bytes thanks to steenbergh*

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=LzEvZXRhIC8vMi9wc2lsb24gLy8zL2EgL2FscGgzYjFnYW1tM2RlbHQzZTJ6MTF0aDFpb3Qza2FwcDNsYW1iZDNtdSBudSB4aSBvbWljcm9uIHBpIHJobyBzaWdtM3RhdSB1MnBoaSBjaGkgcHNpIG9tZWdh&input=)

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by doing this `/2/psilon /`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 68 characters, 92 bytes

```php
<?=strtr(htmlentities(αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω),["&"=>"",";"=>" "]);
```

uses UTF-8; prints a trailing space. Run with `-nr`.

- turn the lowercase greek alphabet into html entities
- remove ampersands and replace semicolons with spaces
- print

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/76688bad145b3a049444f626069b81134a35055b)

Answer (score 2):

## BF, 1265 bytes

```
++++++++++.--[--->++++<]>+.+++++++++++.++++.--------.-------.-[->+++<]>.[->+++<]>++.+++.[--->+<]>---.+[->+++<]>++.-[->+++<]>.++[->+++<]>+.------.++++++++++++..------------.-[->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>+.+.+++++++.++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.-[->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>++.+++++++++++.+++.----------.+++.+++.-.-[->+++++<]>-.-[->++++<]>--.---[->+++<]>.[--->+<]>---.+[->+++<]>++.-[->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>++.[--->+<]>---.+[->+++<]>++.-[->+++<]>.---[->++++<]>.------------.---.[--->+<]>---.+[->+++<]>++.-[->+++<]>.-[--->++<]>-.++++++.+++++.+[->+++<]>++.-[->+++<]>.-[--->++<]>+.----------.-[++>-----<]>..[----->++<]>+.-[->+++<]>.++[--->++<]>.-----------.++++++++++++.-----------.++.---.-[->+++<]>.+[----->+<]>.++++++++.-[---->+<]>+++.+[----->+<]>+.+++++++.-[---->+<]>+++.--[->++++<]>.[->+++<]>+.[--->+<]>---.+++++[->+++<]>.--.----.------.-[--->+<]>----.---.-.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++++++<]>.-------.[--->+<]>---.---[----->++<]>.----------.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.---[->++++<]>-.----------.--.++++++.------------.-[->+++<]>.---[->++++<]>.+[->+++<]>++.--[--->+<]>.-[---->+<]>+++.---[->++++<]>+.-----.+++.----------.+++.+++.-.-[->+++++<]>-.[-->+++++++<]>.--------.+.[--->+<]>---.+[->+++<]>.+++++.+.[--->+<]>---.[-->+++++++<]>.+++.----------.[--->+<]>---.+++++[->+++<]>.--.--------.++.------.>++++++++++.
```

Comment: How and WHY...?

Comment: Why not? Sometimes longer can be better :) @carusocomputing

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>85</s> 66 bytes

*Thanks to ngenisis for pointing the way to a 19-byte savings!*

```
CharacterName@Alphabet@"Greek"~Riffle~" "~StringDelete~"Curly"<>""
```

Returns the string with every Greek letter capitalized. Just thought it would be fun to coerce Mathematica into doing all the work!

`Alphabet@"Greek"` returns a nicely formatted list of the Greek alphabet characters; `CharacterName@` converts each of those characters into a string naming that character, and `~Riffle~" "` inserts a space between each such string. Unfortunately, two of the letters are called `"CurlyEpsilon"` and `"CurlyPhi"`, and so we need `~StringDelete~"Curly"` to fix that. Finally, `<>""` concatenates all these strings together.

Previous submission:

```
StringDelete[ToString@FullForm@Alphabet@"Greek","List"|"Curly"|"["|"]"|"\""|"\\"|","]
```

`Alphabet@"Greek"` returns a nicely formatted list of the Greek alphabet characters as before, but `FullForm` forces it to show the internal structure rather than the nice formatting; `ToString` converts that internal structure into a string that can be manipulated:

```
"List[\"\\[Alpha]\", \"\\[Beta]\", \"\\[Gamma]\", \"\\[Delta]\", \"\\[CurlyEpsilon]\", \"\\[Zeta]\", \"\\[Eta]\", \"\\[Theta]\", \"\\[Iota]\", \"\\[Kappa]\", \"\\[Lambda]\", \"\\[Mu]\", \"\\[Nu]\", \"\\[Xi]\", \"\\[Omicron]\", \"\\[Pi]\", \"\\[Rho]\", \"\\[Sigma]\", \"\\[Tau]\", \"\\[Upsilon]\", \"\\[CurlyPhi]\", \"\\[Chi]\", \"\\[Psi]\", \"\\[Omega]\"]"
```

From here, `StringDelete[..."List"|"Curly"|"["|"]"|"\""|"\\"|","]` gets rid of all the stuff we don't want.

Comment: `StringDelete[Riffle[CharacterName@Alphabet@"Greek"," "]<>"","Curly"]`

Comment: oooo, `CharacterName`!

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <s>104</s> 83 bytes

Base conversion with separator `f`. Unfortunately, it starts with smallest code point `a`.

```
tX."azT¢ç§ªVôòé!þm<EÞ6ä¿û2_w}MªÍ]·¥ünBPæúòRÜÔYcWed¼(É?«/~{"\fd
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tX.%22az%16T%C2%A2%C3%A7%C2%A7%C2%AAV%17%C3%B4%C2%83%C3%B2%02%15%C3%A9%21%C3%BE%1Cm%3C%07E%03%C3%9E%066%C3%A4%1A%C2%BF%C3%BB%7F2_w%C2%8F%05%7DM%C2%AA%C3%8D%11%5D%C2%B7%C2%A5%C3%BCnB%C2%86P%C3%A6%C3%BA%C3%B2R%C3%9C%C3%94YcWed%C2%BC%28%C3%89%06%3F%C2%AB%2F%C2%97%C2%90%C2%89%7E%7B%C2%84%0C%22%5Cfd&debug=0).

Comment: Python 2 is beating you. :D

Comment: @mbomb007 :/ that doesn't count...

Comment: Pyth is just short Python, right?

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 58 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“ßẓ⁸!ȧøḌçỊ¤¢Q=4QẠė⁷¤yż>S⁺ẓṬḄṂċK~⁼Ṛ7&⁼s<ụɦ³ḳMŻyVẉƑƭ6Ẋ⁵ỌQ⁸ẹ»
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcw5_hupPigbghyKfDuOG4jMOn4buKwqTColE9NFHhuqDEl-KBt8KkecW8PlPigbrhupPhuazhuIThuYLEi0t-4oG84bmaNybigbxzPOG7pcmmwrPhuLNNxbt5VuG6icaRxq024bqK4oG14buMUeKBuOG6ucK7&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 47 bytes (44 characters)

```perl6
put squish ~«map {.uniname~~/\w+$/},"α".."ω"
```

Prints `LAMDA` instead of `LAMBDA`, bus so do the other [Unicode database based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda#Character_encodings) solutions.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#@19QWqJQXFiaWZyhUHdodW5igUK1XmleZl5ibmpdnX5MubaKfq2O0rmNSnp6Suc7lf7/BwA)

Comment: A 70-byte solution that prints the exact output: `put (lc squish ~«map {.uniname~~/\w+$/},"α".."ω").subst("md","mbd")`

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 86 bytes

```
“¤±¢ªœÏ¤œ epsilon zeta etaìÛ iota kappaÊ¯ mu nu xi omicron¾î rho¿Ã tau upsilonÐ¢Â¶á‚Åµ
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcwqTCscKiwqrFk8OPwqTFkyBlcHNpbG9uIHpldGEgZXRhw6zDmyBpb3RhIGthcHBhw4rCryBtdSBudSB4aSBvbWljcm9uwr7DriByaG_Cv8ODIHRhdSB1cHNpbG9uw5DCosOCwrbDoeKAmsOFwrU&input=)

Answer (score 0):

### Perl6 (71)

```
(913..937).grep(*!= 930)>>.chr>>.uniname>>.substr(21).join(" ").lc.say
```